# Is Stack Overflow going to create its own jsFiddle-style sandbox environment?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jsfiddle

At least with everything HTML, CSS, and JavaScript related, it seems like everyone is either providing a jsFiddle, or requesting a fiddle in the comments.

Does anyone know if Stack Overflow has any plans to develop or integrate something similar to jsFiddle and other scripting sandboxes right on the page in question and answer posts?

I think it would be spectacular if you could play with the code in a question the same way you can in jsFiddle **without having to leave the page** or provide links in your comments/answers. It would be beyond spectacular if they could create similar test environments for PHP, ASP.NET, and whatever other languages you could play with online.

They could base the use of such things off of reputation if they wanted to.

Does anyone else think this would be an awesome feature? Is it possible that we could see something like this in the near future?

Comment: See the related [Custom jsFiddle for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: @ShemSeger not sure, but I fixed up your question for you anyways.

Comment: Bad idea: That would promote putting half the question somewhere else. Anyway, why not for [insert language of choice] too?

Comment: I'm not suggesting putting parts of the question elsewhere, just adding functionality, and I would like to see sandbox environments for as many languages as possible, right on the same page as the question.

Comment: I'm actually surprised people don't think this would be a good idea, could you please comment why you don't like it if you're going to down vote the question?

Answer (score 4):

This is done - blame Haney: [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1):

### Story of HTML - CSS - JS section on Stackoverflow

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**So**

*Does anyone else think this would be an awesome feature?* - **NO**

I'm already seeing many users asking for jsFiddle even if OP is sharing the code.

The core rule for Stackoverflow is to share the codes, not the demos, so I would say, *jsFiddle is kind of Convenience rather than necessity*.

jsFiddle indeed makes it easy for a user to understand as he can see a visual of what he asked for but again, it is not required. According to me, when we share jsFiddle demos, hardly any user cares to read the code, its like copy-pasta and done.

Also, users will start posting links to custom sandbox, which is again, not recommended. So, code is sufficient to answer a question, you can always use services like jsFiddle, jsBin etc as an addon to your answer.