# Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

Today we're proposing a new feature to the Stack Overflow community: Stack Snippets.

## What do Stack Snippets do?

**Stack Snippets make code blocks runnable.** Here's an example:

```js
alert("You can even do alerts");
```

```css
.hello {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">Stack Snippets allow you to make code runnable.</div>
```

## What's supported?

Stack Snippets work for both questions and answers. The currently supported languages are:

- **HTML**
- **CSS**
- **JavaScript**

You can combine these three languages as you'd please to create runnable code for others to try out. The goal of this feature is to encourage users to create minimally viable and functional code when asking code-centric questions. Answers could then be in the form of a stack snippet which resolved the question at hand. We hope that Stack Snippets enable people to not have to go to other websites in order to produce runnable code.

Eventually we might extend this to other languages, but we're starting with these, because they're easy to do in the browser.

## How do I make a stack snippet?

In the Markdown editor window, you'll notice a **new button** that you can click to launch the Stack Snippets editor.

> [image: Shiny and new]

The editor appears in a full-screen view and allows you to input HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. You can use any or all of them (must use at least one).

> [image: So fancy]

When you're done, press **Save & insert into post** at the top-left to insert your stack snippet into the Markdown text. It gets inserted as regular Markdown code blocks plus some comments that aren't rendered, so they're backwards compatible with revision history, diffs, etc. You can even edit the code right in the Markdown text instead of having to use the full-screen editor.

> [image: Mark it down for me]

## Why?

Every question is better for having *minimal, reproducible code*. Right now the best way to tell people to do that is to point them to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), which is off-site. Using this feature, we plan to push new posters to embed runnable code that reproduces their problem.

Similarly, answers that include runnable code are easier to use and understand, because you can try them out. Obviously JSFiddle is hugely popular in answers already, so we just wanted to make it even easier to use.

Obviously the same rules apply: code-only questions or answers will still be blocked (and, in fact, because of how it's implemented all the existing checks will *just work* out of the box).

## What browsers are supported?

Currently, Stack Snippets will be active for **any browser which supports HTML 5's iframe sandbox feature**. This mostly aligns with our goal to support 2 releases back from the current version of all modern browsers, with the exception of IE9. [See this link for more information.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox)

When inactive, Stack Snippets gracefully render as regular code blocks, so that the code is still a part of the question or answer.

## Try it out

[Here's a sandbox for trying out the feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754). Right now it's only turned on Meta Stack Overflow.

Feedback is definitely welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Amazing. And would it be possible to make the editor resizable or not full-screen? Its often usefull to see the question asked when writing an answer, especially when writing code.

Comment: @1337 I'll definitely take a look at that option. Working within a "framework" that also displays other plugins like Balsamiq, but I might be able to swing it.

Comment: Oh, and when clearing in the editor when its empty results in "The custom error module does not recognize this error." in the `Result` box.

Comment: How feasible is this really beyond languages meant to be run in the browser? In a more general setting how would you allow for different versions of a language, language packages/libraries and their versions, different compilers, different OS's, etc. without things become too unwieldy?

Comment: Yes. Yes, *please*.

Comment: @joran Not easy, you're right. We'll probably only be able to cover the most popular languages and libraries. It's worth pointing out, though, that "fiddles" for lots of languages already exist, so it's not impossible: https://www.google.com/search?q=code+fiddle

Comment: I'm sure you know about http://www.compileonline.com/, but just in case....

Comment: Any reason this was chosen over embedding jsFiddle? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stack-overflow

Comment: I like this feature a lot! I know its just beta, but would there be a better way to cancel rather that just hitting __ESC__ or clicking outside the modal (ideally another button that says "Cancel")? Also, clicking on the "Clear" button without any code in it generates the following output: `The custom error module does not recognize this error.`

Comment: I'd much prefer if you made mobile chat work. I can't even star things. Come on!

Comment: [tag:feature-request] -- add support for Emscripten e.g., to run [tag:python] in javascript, see http://repl.it/languages/Python

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - My initial response to how I would implement that in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17339378#17339378

Comment: @hbdgaf: Yep, spot on. (i.e. the way pretty much every mobile app works)

Comment: Clear `The custom error module does not recognize this error.` is fixed and will be live shortly. Looking at putting in a cancel button now as well.

Comment: Not sure if it would be feasible to implement, but some limitation on the number of times a post can spawn a popup window would be nice. I just had to kill IE's process because of the infinite recursion popup on the demo page.

Comment: @Techrocket9 [status-bydesign]: Punish people who use the travesty that is IE instead of a sane browser like Chrome which has a "suppress popups" option. :P

Comment: Wait a minute. So now there's a button that lets me run random code posted by unknown people? This is going to end badly. Oh look, here's this incomprehensible mess someone posted a question about... I'm going to just _run_ it without even looking at it. The opportunities for people to sneak in malicious code are endless.

Comment: @BrockAdams unfortunately out of our control. We aren't affiliated with AdBlock, though posting the means by which to allow stacksnippets.net might be helpful!

Comment: @MichaelHampton we're testing this feature now so please give us an example in the sandbox of a question or answer sneaking in malicious code.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Comment: @GeoffDalgas There's [already one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269767/1068283)!

Comment: @Haney, The problem is not in Adblock; other sites like jsFiddle work (after adding an XSS exception). ...  If I find a setting that allows this new feature to work, I'll post it.  But so far only disabling AdBlock works (unacceptable).  This suggests that SE is doing something "dicey" and more traditional/robust iframe techniques might be better.

Comment: @MichaelHampton keep it up - we want more examples.

Comment: Isn't this potentially dangerous? I'm no security expert but isn't this xss-like?

Comment: @TopinFrassi, Yes and AdBlock blocks it.  Hopefully, people viewing SO posts will know enough not to run malicious code and will also quickly edit and report the same.

Comment: @TopinFrassi yes, it has the *extreme* potential for danger. This is why we've taken security measures including hosting the code that runs on an entirely different domain. This ensures that the **same-origin policy is not in effect** which prevents people from hijacking your Stack Overflow user/account.

Comment: @Haney Could there be a way to mark a snippet as safe? Or some similar feature, to ensure the users of SE won't be in trouble if they run the script. Personnaly, I'm not bad in JS but I'm not good enough to be 100% sure the code I'm about to execute isn't potentially dangerous. I mean, I like the idea alot but it is a little scary at the same time

Comment: Not supported on my iPad, it seems. I don't get to see the new button there. (No sweat if that's by design, though. Merely tpying is hard enoufhg already.)

Comment: @TopinFrassi believe me, we'd love to, but "safe" is subjective and not black and white. The code *is* currently safe with regards to security and keeping the code from doing anything to Stack Overflow and/or your account. I will definitely think on ways to prevent infinite loops and so forth as well, and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Per my earlier comment, it takes a logout-login to properly load, now it *is* visible .. and it sez, "Touch debices are not supported." Oh well, I can live with that.

Comment: Awesome feature. Makes me wish I was a better web dev so I could utilize it! Consider this a request for the C# version :)

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't work on the Android app. Clicking the code snippets just opens the viewing dialog (unless the app hasn't been updated yet/isn't going to be updated).

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: _"please give us an example in the sandbox of a question or answer sneaking in malicious code"_ Erm, that's not how it works.

Comment: I'll be awaiting the day someone figures out how to hack this and cause everyone who views a page to upvote their questions... or post spam...

Comment: As long as this can be disabled, I'm okay with it. It's a security hole waiting to happen.

Comment: @Haney `This is why we've taken security measures including hosting the code that runs on an entirely different domain` You should note that this causes NoScript to deem it a Cross-site scripting attack which you may want to put a note in an FAQ about so you don't get flooded with "SO has been hacked" posts in the future as well as that the only way to make it run is to whitelist the site in the options menu.

Comment: I can't see it being of any use to me as I only ever look at questions with the Android tag.

Comment: @Haney - it's good that you have same-origin policy taken into account - have you considered click-jacking attacks (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking)?  Do you have a list of security mitigations somewhere that the community can review?

Comment: @Haney "I will definitely think on ways to prevent infinite loops and so forth as well, and see what I can come up with" - you want to solve the halting problem? Good luck with that one but you might find that it is impossible...

Comment: Hm. Well.. `NoScript filtered a potential cross-site scripting (XSS) attempt from [http://meta.stackoverflow.com].` Yay, ok.. I've got the idea and why it was implemented _for free_ (:

Comment: There is no close button for the modal so we should have one

Comment: For those asking about jsFiddle embeds, their uptime isn't awesome and we can't have questions breaking because someone else's site is offline. The only other dependency we have is imgur, which we both pay for a private hosting on and has incredible uptime. Doing so also restricts us to only JavaScript - we have bigger plans if this is something the community wants.

Comment: Currently we have to `click` *outside the dialog box* inorder to close.  Instead can we have a `done` button?

Comment: Did you guys look at outsourcing to jsFiddle? Or is this a case of NIH (Not Invented Here) Syndrome?

Comment: @NickCraver _"we have bigger plans if this is something the community wants"_ Given the number of requests, I would put _"running regex live"_ up in that wish list...

Comment: Very interesting! A question though, what about security vulnerabilities when allow arbitrary JavaScript to run on the page? For example, I can write a code snippet that will send an AJAX request to my server with all of your cookies on [so].

Comment: @SecondRikudo the JavaScript doesn't run in the page, it runs via another domain for *exactly* this reason.

Comment: This is going to end badly.

Comment: @NickCraver Didn't notice it ran on a different domain. Nice!

Comment: Would it be worth having some sort of "are you sure?" appear when clicking to run snippets on questions/answers with -ve score / pending flags etc?

Comment: @BrockAdams *Hopefully, people viewing SO posts will know enough not to run malicious code*, do you know a different SO site than the one I do?

Comment: For all of the reasons others have pointed out, this can't be done **well**.  It's an interesting idea, but one plagued with problems. You're proposing an addition to core functionality.  Since this can't be done in a very clean way, I suggest it not be done.

Comment: This is totally awesome :D Now to find out if there are any security holes :P

Comment: Cue in to newbies posting code that contains `while (true) { /**/ } `.

Comment: "With the exception of IE9?" The last two releases of IE were IE10 and IE11...

Comment: @TylerH I meant 2 versions back from current. Post updated.

Comment: nice, when will we get Android runnable snippets? :D

Comment: Go has an official "playground" like this at http://play.golang.org/ -- it's common to link code examples in Go questions/answers, and Go tutorials/blog posts/presentations embed runnable answers using it as a backend. http://play.rust-lang.org/ is similar for Rust; there's a run-code-now widget on the D language homepage but I don't know if it's available separately. So, anyway, maybe there are some third-party services that could be leaned on for some languages. This feature is cool!

Comment: What checks are in place to ensure malicious code won't be posted? Will it allow all HTML/ JS? HTML itself is allowing the insertion of script files which could prove to be harmful.

Comment: To have a [debuggex](http://debuggex.com)-like regex diagramming/testing tool, *inline*, in SO questions and answers, would be ***amazing***. For regex replacements too!

Comment: just Awesome... it's help alot. Nice feature

Comment: Awesome! Unless users **don't abuse** of it. Too many times I see users posting questions or answers in literally cubital characters... which I hate indeed. If I was eye-impaired I'd use my browser zooming abilities.

Comment: Neither I have the button on markdown editor on meta nor `Run code snippet` button at the end of each runnable block. What happened?! (Chrome v36)

Comment: I don't want an unconscious click to run any random code posted by somebody. It must be an opt-in in worst case. Forget about this feature in the best case.

Comment: @akostadinov: there is a big "run code" button. That's an opt-in. If you don't want to run it do not click it.

Comment: I would argue that it is better to allow members to keep directing users offsite to jsFiddle because 1) it absolves StackOverflow of any responsibility should the user encounter malicious code at an unaffiliated site; and 2) it eliminates any perception of endorsement by StackOverflow towards any third party libraries referenced on code snippet site. In the very least, users should be prompted with a disclaimer when pushing the `Run code snippet` button.

Comment: @BrockAdams Hopefully, people viewing SO posts will know enough not to run malicious code, do you know a different SO site than the one I do?
A malicious coder might embed their malicious code in code so obfuscated and unreadable that the only option to try and assist is to run the code snippet in the first place. I personally believe that most questions that have code snippets attached DO NOT NEED code snippets attached. They end up with attached code snippets because the author is either 1) too lazy to explain the problem they are facing; or 2) too lazy to explain the answer they are giving.

Comment: Why not put up a cash prize for anyone able to sneak malicious code into this feature?

Comment: @NickNo Someone first needs to define malicious. It's already been shown that browser crashes are possible.

Comment: @crush: that really depends on the question. My view is that good answers do need snippets AND explanations. I haven't done a proper analysis on whether current answers with code snippets are good or bad so I won't comment on that. PS: can you link to the code that crashes browser? I tried all the snippets posted in the sandbox and I have not seen malicious behaviour so far.

Comment: As a regular user of jsFiddle, I love this idea. My only suggestion would be to model it fairly closely to what they have, seeing as how successful they've been.

Comment: In order to curb malicious HTTP requests from `iframe` and `ajax`, you could execute the script snippet server-side in a sandbox, and analyze any HTTP requests. Match the domains against a known blacklist, etc. It would help, but clearly not catch everything. Look for suspicious behavior there as analyzing an unexecuted JavaScript and catching malicious behavior might be near impossible.

Comment: @Haney - [Code Review is a good target to consider](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/should-we-adopt-stack-snippets-runnable-code-snippets-in-posts) and are enthusiastic about getting this going...

Comment: I don't get why malicious code is any more of a concern here than it would be in a JSFiddle.  Either way, the user can view the code before running it.  Either way, malicious code of sorts can be introduced.  This is essentially just an on-site JSFiddle, eliminating dependence on another site.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain It's not "more of a concern" it's more an issue of trust and placement of blame. If it's on jsFiddle, then it's not StackOverflow's problem if a user gets malicious code. If StackOverflow is hosting the malicious code, then they are responsible. That said, if StackOverflow hosts the malicious code, they can also take measures to try and prevent malicious code from being posted.

Comment: Here is a good sample of a question that would be quite unwieldy in this new feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535712/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-my-javascript-code

Comment: That might be a gate for XSS attacks?

Comment: Is it possible to fold the box back? I expect something that can be extended to be able to be folded back into original state.

Comment: This one is some awesome addition but can easily be misused, I guess....

Comment: What about the ability that jsFiddle gives you of added other resources to the snippets like jQuery, or Bootstrap, things of that nature?

Comment: So far I like it, but it would be nice if the box were resizable. Also seems to be having a lot of fun with my history stack. Had to press Back about 10 times to get back here.

Comment: I wish there should be like sqlfiddle too

Comment: @Haney just a thought, since it seems people are starting to do this via answers to this post, it could be nice to have another meta post where people can post answers of what languages they'd like to see this expanded out to. Then they could get ranked for importance by the community for such a time when you are able to implement more than these three initial ones. If nothing else it could reduce some clutter on this post of people suggesting languages, and focus it more on the "provide feedback" aspect.

Comment: JSFiddle is a trainwreck.  [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) is much, much, much more reliable, performant, and useful.  If you want to avoid reinventing the wheel, opt for JSBin.

Comment: @Nick Craver: On the flip side, depending on a site like jsFiddle *knowing* it has crappy uptimes can help to drive home the point of link/fiddle-only posts not being useful. We do have a close reason for questions lacking code within the text, you know.

Comment: To make it work with NoScript you should add the following exception to the XSS filter: `^http://stacksnippets.net/js$`.

Comment: @Haney is there any chance we could put regular text in between the different types of code in the snippet. [Formatting posts like this is common on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60871/41243) and things get kind of cluttered without being able to put a small "Header" in between. Heck, nevermind. Would it be possible to *bake in* some headers for HTML, JS, CSS??

Comment: @GeoffDalgas, Here's a demonstration: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272390/632951

Comment: That example is pretty lame - I've deleted it since it simply isn't true.  Anyone who enters any of their secure passwords into a random text box on the internet is a bit of a lost cause when it comes to protecting their security.  We will deal with these types of posts as they come up with human moderation.

Comment: Currently broken for me. ALL snippets and stacksnippets.net return 500 - Internal Server Error.

Comment: I do not like code snippet because for just displaying php functions it is no point it is just better to click on code tag on editor instead.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode What's with those markdown tags? Screenshots, seriously? ;(

Comment: When will it support also Python ? @Haney

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti unknown ETA. Hopefully one day!

Comment: @Haney I ran into an issue today where an API only accepts http requests on the free tier, but when you run the snippet the http is being converted to https, so the request fails. Any way to force http in snippets?

Answer (score 331):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Provide a button that allows us to "fork" a snippet into an answer, with highlighting of differences between the original and the "forked" version.

This will make it easier to:

1. Quickly copy the snippet and modify it and
2. Easily make the changes visible in the answer, for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Yeah, this is on my radar for sure. We'll see what I can come up with!

Comment: Good idea, but this just *begs* for snippet-only answers.

Comment: Do you mean something like the edit suggestions?

Comment: It seems like this could be applicable to more than just these runnable snippets. If I want to rewrite a piece of code from a C# question and highlight the differences, this would be very helpful.

Comment: I'd rather have the ability to highlight specific lines of code in my answer so that I can explain them without using embedded comments. I've seen paste sites that allow you to start a line with a special character, or combination of characters to flag that line as highlighted. This would be incredibly useful for answering questions in a clearly formatted manner.

Comment: Also: open source your diff algorithm when you do implement this :)

Comment: @AstroCB It seems it would be trivial to flag snipped only answers as low quality, like the site does already.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman True, but those flags are normally declined.

Comment: @AstroCB, do you have some stats to back that up?  I see those flags all the time in the review queue, and I agree with a lot of them.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Whenever I'm in the LQP queue, I recommend the deletion of almost every single post; it's usually there for a reason. If not that, I'll edit it to fix it up or attempt to remove the thing that got it flagged in the first place. Recently, however, the majority of my low quality flags have been declined because the meaning of that flag is supposedly changing.

Answer (score 154):

In the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, we get comments like these **all the time**:

> JSFiddle please
>
> It would be better if we had a JSFiddle
>
> I can help you if you give me a JSFiddle

We outsource *a lot* of content to JSFiddle, so having Stack Snippets onsite would certainly help (though it does negate the need for a userscript I've been working on...).

I am all for this with **one restriction**:

**Please, please, please** *do not* allow snippet only/(code + snippet)-only answers. It's bad enough now that there are answers like this:

> this will work for you thx.
>
> ```
> alert("this is a test");
> ```

Our goal here is to not only help the OP solve his/her problem, but also to *teach him/her to solve problems **on his/her own***. If we allow people to answer with the exact same code + fixes applied, the OP will come back again and again asking for debugging help. We value answers that *explain* the problem and how to fix it, so adding something like this could be dangerous without the proper restrictions.

Perhaps a character restriction or forbidding common phrases like "try this" (I know that this is frowned upon, but it's already in use, anyway, so we may as well use it here) would encourage people to explain their code (there will *always* be those people who do "...lots of text so I can post answer..."), but there has to be **some** way to encourage people to do this. (Feel free to comment with ideas.) [Code-only questions are forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/269763?noredirect=1#comment84548_269763), but code-only **answers** are still allowed (for whatever reason), so anything is an improvement.

As long as the rules are made clear (put it in [the tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) or something: don't just leave it as an obscure menu bar time without any context or guidance), this could be an **immensely helpful tool**.

Comment: Mostly agree, except if you put a restriction that people must write prose along with their code, people _will_ work around it with ".........." or "here's the code" or some other rubbish ("This will work for you thx." counts!), because people always work around restrictions they don't like/understand. The fact that this problem is fated to exist is just another example of why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Code only questions are already forbidden, and remain forbidden with stack snippets.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True (I forgot to add a part about character restrictions, but your point still applies).

Comment: @KevinMontrose That's right: I forget that sometimes because I'm so used to seeing code-only answers.

Comment: Clearer guidelines and word counts by bots can only do so much; the only effective long term solution is down voting and leaving comments asking the poster to explain their solution so that it can stand alone to help future users.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Very true, but that only does so much on a site that gets new questions every couple of seconds.

Comment: I've seen that people often just work around restrictions instead of following the advice given, for example placing http://jsfiddle.com in a inline code span instead of actually adding the code to the question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes, as I've said, there will always be people who overstep the restrictions, but that doesn't mean that we shouldn't have them.

Comment: I'd rather have the choice of downvoting code-only answers than try to forbid them and end up with workarounds like LRiO mentioned (in which case I'd probably still downvote anyway but then it just makes the filter pointless, also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176902/dont-consider-inline-code-spans-as-code-for-the-purposes-of-the-quality-filter and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/detect-attempts-at-disguising-meaningless-text-as-code-blocks)

Comment: @KevinMontrose: "forbidden"? They still show up in the Low Quality Queue pretty regularly because someone flagged it as not an answer.

Comment: 5 lines of Well Documented code and a link to MSDN is worth an essay of explanation. Don't limit people giving code answers.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony [We've had this discussion before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality). The consensus is that code-only answers are fine if they are well-documented; the problem is that well-documented code-only answers are a rarity (especially in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, which is what this is currently being used for).

Comment: *Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him for a lifetime?* Yes, I wish that code only answers would get downvoted more aggressively. Unless they contain comments that explain what is happening of course.

Comment: I'd upvote this ten times if I could.  Crappy, lazy code-only answers just make me ragey.  It's especially worse when the OP is *not* asking for code, but a fix (an explanation and/or a little bit of code).  I never understood why people bother to dump some code automatically.

Comment: @Jamal I think part of the "code-only answer" epidemic is new users desperately trying to make a name for themselves so that they are taken more seriously. Lately, I've been seeing people post an answer instantly with crap like "will update with answer soon". Like it's a race to be the first to answer, even if you don't have a quality answer yet.

Comment: @crush: I actually haven't seen "will update" soon answers very often at all.  Maybe I'm not looking closely enough.

Comment: @Jamal maybe they are updating the answer before you see it. I saw at least 5 yesterday. I was actually about to post a meta on the topic.

Comment: @crush: Ah, that's what you meant.  I thought they were hanging onto these crap answers longer (posting before knowing the solution).

Comment: @Jamal They are posting before they know the solution. They will post an "answer" that is like "I'm working on the answer. I will update with answer in a moment."

Comment: @crush: Oh... well, that's just stupid.  I will certainly show them no mercy as I come across them.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that this is primarily a teaching site rather than an answers site.  To me, the primary purpose of stack overflow is not to teach, but rather to provide a resource to experienced programmers for getting answers to issues that they happen to be stuck on.  In my opinion, code only answers that answer the question are fine.

Comment: @WarrenDew The problem with that is that people will come along and ask why *their* case didn't work rather than apply information included in an explanatory answer.

Comment: @AstroCB I'm not saying that all answers should be code only.  That said, even answers that include little or no code are often not very explanatory, either.  And if the code only answer does answer the original question, but does not answer the new person's question, the new person probably has a somewhat different question that deserves a post of its own.

Comment: `but there has to be some way to encourage people to do this` It's called a downvote.

Comment: It would be nice to have a BANNER that shows up whenever a codepen or jsfiddle link appears (especially since there are a lot of web dev questions on the site).

Answer (score 100):

<strike>This is an awesome idea. It would be even more awesome if you supported additional languages.</strike>

This seems like a really cool idea, but I'm starting to doubt its value.

1. Sometimes the fiddle requires more than the 'answer' code. The accepted answer on [my most recent JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550134/appropriate-javascript-delay-to-trigger-css) is a good example.

   ### Before

   It is possible to implement it without setTimeout using window.getComputedStyle.

   The basic idea is:

   ```
   joe.style.opacity = 0; //Unnecessary in this case, set by CSS class   
   window.getComputedStyle(joe).getPropertyValue("width");
   joe.style.opacity = 1;
   ```

   Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Vy9n/2/

   ### After

   With the new feature enabled, you are more likely to get answers like this:

   ```js
   document.body.onclick = function () {
     var joe = document.createElement('div');
     joe.innerHTML = 'yo!';
     joe.id = 'joe';
     document.body.appendChild(joe);
     window.getComputedStyle(joe).getPropertyValue("width");
     joe.style.opacity = 1; 
   }
   ```

   ```css
   #joe { transition: opacity 1000ms; opacity: 0; }
   ```

   ```html
   <span>test</span>
   ```

   ### Wow, that was *long*

   I'm concerned that encouraging use of this feature over jsfiddle.net will cause people to include more 'irrelevant code'. This means longer questions and answers.
2. It isn't as easy to edit.

   Having the full operational code and separators inline makes for longer source code on the post. I'd say this pushes the limits of what Markdown is intended to be.

   You could create a better rich text editor to keep people from having to work with Markdown directly so much. That's probably more trouble than it's worth though.

   Remember, not everyone can use Markdown as well as you or me, and even if they can, that doesn't mean it's a fast job.

### Summary

As proposed, I'd say this feature would cause more harm than good, because it would result in an increased average length in questions and answers, and too much inline activity when you expand/collapse the fiddle display.

jsfiddle.net works, perhaps you should follow that model? Keep the 'fiddle' code separated from the 'posted' code. You can either continue to use jsfiddle.net or create a new stackfiddle.net or whatever. Focus on improving on this model rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I've been thinking about this one a lot. I think it's still better to have all the code in the answer -- otherwise you're dependent on a third party or at least a separate page for the full story. It's no different from any long answer. If there are two really important lines you should call them out at the top, and then have the full snippet below. Maybe we could experiment with collapsible parts of a post that can be hidden by default, if we think they're really unimportant.

Comment: We're already dependent on imgur, a community staple, for images. Why would we not rely on jsfiddle, another community staple, for, well, js fiddles?

Comment: @corsiKa Stack Exchange has a commercial partnership with Imgur that ensures that the images hosted there *will not* be subject to "link rot." There is no such partnership with JSFiddle.

Comment: *1.* is very important, the first thing that came to my mind when I saw this new feature. I almost never want to display all the demo code in my answer. There should be some separation (displayed code / demo code), or an option for the demo code to be fully hideable.

Comment: @David, Perhaps take a moment to visit the [example question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550134/appropriate-javascript-delay-to-trigger-css) and answer. The code from the answer fiddle is just a repeat of the code already in the question. If there were multiple answers with alternative solutions, the added web page length would result in an inferior user experience. You'll also notice the heavy use of fiddles in the question which I included to provide evidence of my assertions. I would certainly be doing a lot less of that if it were 'inline'.

Comment: @DavidFullerton: Please, trust at the very least people who are writing the answers to know which parts of answer are important to show and are irrelevant. At least for me the feature in it's current form is entirely valueless, as including all the setup code in answers is going to give askers a terrible learning experience.

Comment: What if I were to work out a set of region tags that could be used to decide what is shown and hidden in the resulting Snippet, even though all code would run. Thoughts on that?

Comment: @Haney Simpler: Automatically partially collapse all code blocks to show 10 or so lines.  Add an option in the tag [or however this is implemented] to specify which line is the first line you want to display in collapsed mode (the lines people get w/o uncollapsing).  I think auto-collapsing code blocks would be helpful with or without the runnable code snippets.

Comment: Also, for answers, you won't generally be adding runnable code snippets for every separate answer.  You may need no snippets, or one, but if they're all just saying 'modify this (different) little bit here', they don't need runnable snippets individually.  (Also, if answers could be made to automatically inherit the question's css/javascript, that might save some lines, as you only change what you want to change.)

Comment: Okay you've convinced me there's a problem. What about an option to hide the snippet by default? The code would still be in the post, but hidden behind a click (similar to the jsfiddle example, except you wouldn't go to a new page). Here's a quick mockup: http://i.stack.imgur.com/X0XKU.png

Comment: @DavidFullerton that was the first thing I thought of when reading this post, it would work :)

Comment: @DavidFullerton Consider adding the *optional* ability to mark a *single* range of lines (like, lines 10-30) within the runnable snippet, that should be considered the "most important", and therefore displayed in the answer. Then have a "show/hide" button that hides all lines outside of the range.

Comment: @DavidFullerton but make it opt out please, not opt in ;) I feel like in most cases one does not want to see the whole thing. I usually do not use samples unless I want to see what something does (if I do not get it)

Comment: In reply to *"Remember, not everyone can use Markdown as well as you or me, and even if they can, that doesn't mean it's a fast job."*: If you are competent enough to write any coding language, understanding the syntax of Markdown should be a breeze.

Comment: @crush It has nothing to do with competence... It has to do with knowledge. An idiot can learn markdown, anybody can. But that doesn't mean that everybody does. Knowing all the little syntaxes takes effort, repetition, and retention.

Comment: @Cruncher I just don't see it taking much effort to learn if they want to use the feature. We are programmers here, not accountants or massage therapists.

Comment: @crush, I would like to clarify. I think the current use of Markdown desirable, but including three languages in snippet form with such separators would be much less user-friendly from an editing and formatting perspective for large fiddles. It is much easier to edit the three languages in separate textareas, and to have it separated from your question code.

Comment: @AstroCB, Maybe that's the problem then. SE should get a partnership with a hosting site that doesn't suddenly shut down for no reason.

Answer (score 48):

Limiting this to JS/CSS/HTML seems a bit restrictive. The usual coliru-style online compiler offers many language implementations.

Also, I just saw,

> Answers could then be in the form of a Stack Snippet which resolved the question at hand.

This is just going to encourage code-only no explanation answers, as well as questions. Including a Stack Snippet would be nice. Snippet-only questions or answers would not be nice.

Comment: I'm sure they're only doing one step at a time.

Comment: Stack Snippets don't support MUMPS. I am disappointed

Comment: Added some notes to the post. (1) It's JS/CSS/HTML right now because that was the easiest.  If it's successful we may expand to other languages. (2) All the same rules about code-only questions and answers apply, and in fact it's just inserting code blocks so the existing checks will all work. All this does is make it runnable, which seems like it's always better (?)

Comment: @David, so you theoretically have the power to extend it to other languages (which, last time I checked, implies running some compiler/interpreter forty times per second on mid-to-low end traffic). Surely you have provisions in place to avoid a few well-organized-enough individuals from DDOSing the site out of existence, right? :)

Comment: A lovely new option to play with. Can't wait for a Z80 emulator! (I'd probably have to dig up my ol' Rodney Zaks hardcopy.)

Comment: @gnat mumps can lead to infertility, it's actually a relief they are not supported :D

Answer (score 42):

Oh, and here are some items that you are probably already aware of:

- There should be a way to close the snippet when done.
- It should not 'break silently' just because you don't use semicolons.
- The snippet creator form could use some aesthetic improvements.
  Perhaps use the quad view like jsfiddle.net, add an actual close link, etc.

Answer (score 35):

I get this

[image]

But I'm stubborn..

[image]

Is it supported or not? If not, please make it available for touch devices.

Comment: What did you do to get it to work?

Comment: @tbodt One finger and a bit of stubbornness ;)

Comment: @Omar,  
What did you do to get it to work?

Comment: What did you do to get it to work?

Comment: Probably [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348096/) if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 33):

Can I suggest finding a better way to separate the three code blocks? They sort of run into each other a bit at the moment.

And what version of HTML will be used for any given snippet? Needs to be clearer as sometimes this is important.

Otherwise good.

Comment: Solid points, let me think on this for a few.

Comment: I'd love to see `<!-- language: lang-js -->` place a small `"JavaScript"` header within the code box, personally.

Answer (score 33):

The perfectionist in me is disgusted by casing of the word "Begin" in `<!-- Begin snippet: js -->`. It should be "begin" instead to match "language: lang-js" and "end snippet".

P.S. Now it's easy to [crash browsers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269786/293099)...

Comment: @DJDavid98 I'm not active in the topics where jsFiddle is used.  Can all the people that can edit other people's questions and answers on SO also edit other people's code on jsFiddle?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, sort of. Just need to fork the fiddle and update the question/answer with the new fiddle link.

Comment: @DJDavid98 The difference is that before it wasn't SO's site that was causing your browser to crash. Now, it is.

Answer (score 30):

Awesome feature. Will be much appreciated. If at all possible, I would create a possibility of two levels of code view. The reason behind it - boilerplate code that is not relevant for the actual answer. One way to solve it:

- checkbox/toggle "hide in answer" for each of the sections
- additional `#hide` and `#unhide` comments for sections of JavaScript/CSS/HTML 
  wrapped in any style of the comment in respective language, e.g. `<!--#hide--!>` or
  `//#hide` or `/*#hide*/`
- button on the actual answer `Show all` near `Run code snippet`

There are for sure other, neater ways, just can't think of one. As it is, for me, if answer requires a lot of boilerplate, possibly already included in the question, I will resort to jsfiddle. If it is bearable, I will definitely use Code Snippet.

Comment: Or a boilerplate insertion where a CDN can be linked

Comment: I was just about to add this as a suggestion; I use JS Fiddle a lot (primarily in the [tag:d3.js] tag), and I very rarely want *all* of the code necessary for a working example to be included in the answer.

Comment: So then, not only can we include malicious code in the snippets, we could selectively hide sections of it to disguise it as something helpful to get people to run it without checking the hidden sections first.

Comment: @AJMansfield, malicious code is a whole separate problem. Not hiding it will not solve it. At most, it might slightly reduce the time until it gets deleted. I trust SO developers deal or will deal with it the proper way. Methodology is well known and jsfiddle success shows it is effective. E.g. with the current approach I can link my own library from my own server and call it jquery-form-plugin.js and  people will suspect even less than hidden code.

Answer (score 27):

External files are not a problem! Just include them in your HTML the way you would for any other site.

#### [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29)

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible col-xs-10" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
  </button>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Danger, Will Robinson
</div>
```

#### [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <div>Hello {{yourName}}!</div>
</div>
```

#### [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's stopping someone from including a malicious external JavaScript file, dressed up as "jQuery" on some random CDN. The casual user sees "jQuery" src'd and deems the script safe to run...

Comment: @crush, nothings to stop them, except hopefully sandboxing and subsequent downvotes or edits from the community will mitigate the effect.  Even so, you could still do that in  jsFiddle or almost every other online editor which allows you to add your own external files.  Minimally you could see them first before running to look if it came from a reputable domain.  There's very little SO could do to prevent malice.  But it looks like they've done their HW to prevent harm.

Comment: @KyleMit Exactly. You can do it in a site that is not affiliated with StackOverflow.

Comment: The AngularJS and jQuery UI examples don't seem to work.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, they seem to be working fine for me.  I'm not quite sure what the issue would have been.  It's certainly valid HTML to run through those examples

Answer (score 25):

As someone with far too many points in the JavaScript tag, this is **fantastic** news.  Newbs will be able to give faster feedback, answers can now be *even clearer* and "Can you make a JSFiddle" is banished to the far corners of the internet.

However, there are many, *many* more languages, all of which could benefit from some Runnable code.  I work at [Runnable](http://runnable.com) where we have endeavoured to use Docker to enable coders of all ages to run any code in the browser, not just JavaScript.  We'd love to work with you guys to embed Runnable examples of any language into questions and answers.

You can contact me personally at `randall at runnable.com` or us generally through `support at runnable.com`

Comment: That would be awesome!

Answer (score 22):

If you guys are interested in integrating .NET Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net) for code snippets in C#, VB.NET, F# and ASP.NET MVC, please let me know. My email is dotnetfiddle at entechsolutions dot com.

I see that one of the reasons you decided not to integrate with jsFiddle was because of stability. While .NET Fiddle stability is pretty good, to be integrated with Stack Overflow it can't be just "good". It has to be great.

So I would like to propose the following approach:

- You keep all the code as well as last execution result in Stack Overflow
- If .NET Fiddle site is not available, you display the code with syntax highlighter which we can provide, as well as result of last execution. With a comment that execution occurred in the past.  We can provide .NET code highlighter etc... Or you can use your own
- The fiddles can appear interactively (with auto complete, live syntax validation) directly on the Questions/Answers.  Or they can appear in read only mode, where you click on Edit and it opens up a popup or another window, like you are doing with Stack Snippets.

As to UI, we are very flexible.  We can provide API if you would like fully custom UI, or we can provide UI using Widgets where code editor and result will be displayed in IFrame and handled by dotnetfiddle.net.

Answer (score 20):

What about security? Seems easy to abuse by someone trying to get the unwary to run some trojan on their computer.
While a lot of the visitors here may be capable of detecting such attempts, your average homework kid who's the likely person to be wowed and click the "run" button isn't (and neither will be someone not familiar with the ins and outs of a specific language).

In itself the idea is neat, but I have serious reservations because of that.

And of course if the code posted needs any external resources or libraries to function (and which code except the extremely simplistic doesn't?) it's not going to be of much use.
E.g. a snippet to load googlemaps will need to link to external resources to load the required Javascript files.

Comment: ++ I am looking forward to an answer to the points you've made. I am not a web developer so I am very concerned with how secure is this going to be...

Comment: [Haney♦ has partially addressed this already](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers?cb=1#comment84598_269753)

Comment: ++ This needs to be of highest concern. Some fears might be allayed by an 'are you sure?' dialog, which indicates that you should have a basic understanding of the code and any security concerns before proceeding.

Comment: @Rudi that's a pretty decent idea. I might have a disclaimer prompt when you run code maybe. Also "evil" code like loops will be downvoted into oblivion ideally. Still working on a way to solve the Halting Problem. ;)

Comment: `while (true) { alert("ha"); }`

Comment: @Cole only the poor souls using IE will be affected, real browsers block alerts after 3 or 4 in a row.

Comment: @ShadowWizard as of June 1st that's 20.89% for IE8, 17.03% for IE11 and 9.05% for IE9 and 6.77% for IE10, according to [NetApplications](http://www.winbeta.org/news/june-1st-2014-internet-explorer-8-still-dominates-browser-market-share). I think most of them are not SO visitors, but IE still counts :P

Comment: @pollirrata people also eat junk food and do drugs... ;)

Comment: The argument that the same thing could be done by directing users to jsFiddle is a valid; however, the difference is that StackOverflow is not affiliated with, nor do they endorse, jsFiddle. Therefore, they are not responsible. Bringing this in-house makes StackOverflow responsible. That is my thought, anyways.

Answer (score 19):

Unless this gets expanded to allow linking to external libraries, I don't see a ton of reason to use it over jsFiddle.

For instance, answering [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) questions without being able to demonstrate how it works tends to be a losing proposition. Then there's the questions dealing with, say, FontAwesome, where (again) being able to load an external resource is critical.

Perhaps a better solution would be to fetch the contents of a linked jsFiddle and inject it into the answer? There's always the [embedded fiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html), too.

Comment: Just [include any external files in a link or src tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269865/1366033)

Comment: The only problem with this is link rot and JSFiddle taking down old, anonymous Fiddles: hosting the code onsite is the best way to go.

Comment: @KyleMit That's a very good point. I'm so used to using the External Resources tool on jsFiddle that I didn't think about just dropping the script right into the example.

Comment: @TiesonT., Yeah, I've slowly been migrating from jsFiddle to Plunker and have been getting used to adding them manually.  It's not that much more work or extra noise and it's a lot more control.

Comment: I've once had to answer a question about code that breaks in production that works in jsfiddle because the guy didn't quite understand what the External Resources tool actually does. I think this is better because it looks more like what you should type in notepad.

Answer (score 19):

Typo in the [domain landing page](http://stacksnippets.net/):

> [image]

"others" should lose the "s". :)

Comment: My bad, thanks as always Shadow Wizard... Correcting.

Comment: Beware of *[Jeff Atwood's Big-S](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)* (in spirit).

Comment: @Peter thanks for the warning, I have a Shield in my bag now. :)

Answer (score 19):

There are several problems with this feature. For example, [long running scripts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269837/632951) and [infinitely long running scripts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269786/632951) which will hang / crash the browser.

But more importantly, while this feature might be secure for Stackoverflow's servers, it is definitely unsecure for Stackoverflow's **users** unless we can solve the phishing problem as demonstrated by [my post on snippet sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272390/632951) which requires nothing but the innocuous `window.location.href`.

(A phishing demonstration is not a technological demonstration but a [social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)) one. As such, if the demonstration is worded like [John's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269904/632951), [bfrohs' post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/269899#269899) or [nhinkle's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/269991#269991), it doesn't demonstrate [the dangers of a phishing attack](http://test-123.meximas.com/results.php).)

While there are certainly users who may spot these *in-domain* phishing attacks and flag them for removal, **it might indeed be already too late**.

Phishers can get extremely creative, but I **suppose** all *in-domain* phishing attacks can be prevented by 
 disallowing all external redirections —`window.open`, `window.location`, `a href`, etc— and [all external embeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433319/embed-an-external-page-without-an-iframe) —`iframe src`, `frame src`, `script src`, `img src`, `object`, `embed`, and CSS / favicon's `link href`, etc—.

Comment: Interesting. The character replacement doesn't happen in my browser (Firefox 32) but the GET requests are executed.

Comment: IMO everybody who falls for this deserves to have their account stolen and/or deleted... If it would be easy to fix and the fix does not block valid usage of the snippets, I'd say fix it; but if it's complicated or would stop potentially valid use cases, I'm in favour of darwinism here.

Comment: @Stijn, Oh didn't spend much time making it cross browser since it'd probably be deleted soon. Anyway, I added `i.focus(); i.setSelectionRange(i.value.length, i.value.length);` for firefox, does it work now?

Comment: No idea, it's been deleted as you expected :) but that's fine, I understood the idea behind it.

Comment: @l4mpi, There are many variations as demonstrated by bfroh and nhinkle. You'd be surprised how gullible people are. In the past, there's a game called RuneScape whereby people will say ["This is my password: *************. Is it censored by the system?"](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Scams/Password_scams) Then the person nearby who read that will test it out by typing out their very own password.

Comment: I know there's gullible people, and the method you mention is far older than runescape - the oldest reference I personally know of is from IRC chat. Still, if someone is gullible enough to fall for an obvious phising attempt (and clicking a "run snippet" button and then being asked to enter account details is very obvious), I say it's entirely their fault. Also, if somebody writes such a malicious answer, it can simlpy be flagged, downvote and commented on to prevent anybody stupid enough from giving away their data. I don't see the need to implement special phising prevention for this.

Comment: @l4mpi, Anyone who has not done programming will not find it obvious that clicking "run" on a **trusted website** is a risk of any sort.

Comment: @Pacerier and anyone who has not done programming has no business being on SO. Still, that does not matter as I'd trust the community to quickly downvote, flag and delete any sort of malicious snippets.

Comment: @l4mpi, The "run code snippet" feature is enabled even for non-account visitors which include those who are linked to SO from other SE sites. The problem here is that SO is trusted by these people because it's an SE site. Flagging is more of a stopgap solution than an actual one. It's better to prevent external requests right from the source because there's no guarantee that all malicious posts will be detected, flagged, then removed within a short period of time.

Comment: In my browser/OS, I have a horizontal scrollbar that alerts me that something fishy is going on. Scrollbars may be ugly, but they work. I will never understand browsers/OSes that try to do away with them...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Shouldn't that be *phishy* instead of *fishy* ? :-)

Comment: Demonstrating the technical parts of a phishing attack is one thing.  Demonstrating the psychological parts of a phishing attack is another.  Putting them together, and exposing it to the internet, is actually phishing.  You could have made your point without actually phishing, but you chose to actually phish for passwords instead.

Comment: @Yakk, The asterisk made all the difference. No passwords have been phished, it's just a demonstration.

Answer (score 18):

Small annoyance: The "Run code snipped" box is added after the page is loaded: this causes the page scroll position to be incorrect.

For example, here is a [link to a comment at the bottom of the sandbox page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/269767#comment84642_269783) - 
The page loads nicely and points to the comment, but after the "Run code snipped" buttons are added to the page, the comment jumps down.

Comment: Yes, this is annoying.

Answer (score 14):

I just edited [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269776/209139). It had an HTML block to which I added a CSS block.

1. There was no way to launch the snippet in an edit view. The button seems to work only for adding new snippets. To edit an existing snippet, I had to work by hand.
2. I added the CSS block *after* the existing HTML block, but the CSS appears first in the rendered view. Why?

Answer (score 13):

### Bug

JavaScript that has single line comments (`//`) cause all JavaScript after that point to be commented out. This appears to be caused by stripping new line characters from the JavaScript.

Example:

```js
/*Multiline comment is fine*/
$(document.body).append('<span>Hello </span>');
//Append a child element to the DOM body.
$(document.body).append('<span>World!</span>');
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're right, and it's on my list to fix ASAP. :)

Answer (score 13):

Can we please have the same for SQL?

Many answers in the SQL area use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to build a *minimal, reproducible code*. But often the site is down.

Comment: This would be an amazing addition...prompting the user to enter some schema information and a sample or two would make SQL questions much easier to help with.  Currently, about 75% of the questions require comments asking for that information instead

Answer (score 11):

I think more languages should be supported, and at least some most popular libraries must be possible to connect. Of course, this then becomes a serious project. Also, languages that require standard "prolog" and "epilog" may have more useful cases if we automatically assume the code as a part of the main function. For instance, in Java,

```
public class Main {
  public static void run(String [] args) {
     a = 10;
     System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

should be equivalent to

```
a = 10;
```

and show the output "a=10" somewhere. This would cover many algorithms, regular expressions, and simple constructs. C, C++ may have similar assumption rules.

Without this, indeed, most answers will become unnecessarily long. Most of the code in the answers are *fragments* of the code, not a complete ready to run applications.

Comment: It sounds like if it takes off they'll add more languages.  But I definitely agree for certain languages there's going to be a lot of "boilerplate" if you need to make the whole thing runnable.  Some scripting languages like JS and Ruby won't require that though.

Comment: Ruby is a good language, we could make it standard for algorithms.

Answer (score 11):

Great! I would love to see support for more languages though, like http://ideone.com/ does.

Comment: Not only support for new languages (use pythonanywhere for Python for example) but for more visibility of what happens: http://pythontutor.com/ (available in other langauges) since the problem is sometimes very basic and visualization could help.

Answer (score 10):

**Feature request**

When you click on the "Run code snippet" button you should be able to minimize that box that appears so it's not so big. For example the images below shows that the box can be quiet big, it would new nice to be able to minimize it.

**Bug**

Also on my tablet text will overflow onto the "Fullscreen" button (ignore my battery percent it is now charging)

[image]

Comment: Heh, I was actually about to comment on your battery level until I read your answer more thoroughly

Comment: Battery percentage? What about your Wi-Fi signal?!

Comment: @AstroCB geez I can't keep ye happy can I? :(

Comment: @Howlin We're just looking out for your devices.

Comment: This. Viewing answers [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/269886#269886) might not give me epilepsy, but it sure isn't fun to keep open forever, and I'd rather not have to reload the page just to close a snippet. That would be a nightmare for questions with lots of answers w/ code snippets.

Comment: I instinctively clicked the "run code snippet" button to try and show/hide the runnable window.

Answer (score 10):

#### At least *encourage* code comments.

Inline snipplets are obviously not just a cool feature, but they also help with answer coherency. It'll certainly succeed in avoiding the core solution being dispersed to off-site resources.

While I'm not purposefully browsing HTML, CSS and JavaScript questions, I'm aware the "Try this: `code dump`" answers are most prevalent there. Which is why I'm also slightly concerned about Stack Overflow being mistaken for just CodeExchange™ moreso.
(Content filtering is technically, answer voting often in practice; unsuitable to avoid such fall-outs.)

There's however an easy opportunity to raise the arts here.

```
// Suggestive default comment to encourage documenting key steps
alert("You can even comment your code!");
```

Just have the editor include a preset single-line comment for the scripty sections. If left unchanged from, for example, `// Please comment your code`, it can as easily be stripped on inserting the answer snipplet.

**What for?** If we're honest, snippet answers will invariably lead to more users and visitiors just *copy'n'pasting* around. Subtly nudging towards a minimum of commented code does no harm. It won't discourage from textual explanations making up the major ratio of *good* answers, even if a few notes are duplicated within code samples. It's possibly beneficial to inheritors of all-googled JavaScript code amalgamations though.

Comment: This will encourage comments like `var x = 1; // Set the variable x to 1.`

Answer (score 8):

The Full Screen experience is a little jarring. When you take away all of the content, I immediately go to my back button to return me to the question page.  As it works right now, that actually takes me away from the question page.

Comment: OTOH, when we view many snippets on the page the back button navigates through them. . . . . Not adding an answer, as I think the back button behavior is one and all.

Answer (score 8):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When an answer has a low enough score (e.g. -3) disable the "Run code snippet" button, or add a warning "Sure you want to run the code?" before actually running it, as it usually means something is wrong with the code.

Comment: The "something wrong" might have nothing whatsoever to do with being problematic code; it could simply get the answer wrong, or do it in an inadvisable way, or miunderstand the question, or just be really poorly written and unclear. If code is genuinely malicious: there's flagging for that.

Comment: When the score is -3 or lower, the answer is gray and the buttons under stack snippets are missing, now.

Comment: Disabling the button is a horrible idea and makes the whole point of the snippet useless. Awful UX. A warning is fine, but breaking the functionality is unacceptable.

Comment: @TylerH I disagree, but that's what we have feature requests for.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating A feature request would be an ineffective attempt for something already described here and elsewhere by mods as an intended feature.

Answer (score 8):

Let me start by saying that I think this feature could have a lot of potential. However there are big time security risks.

It seems that everyone keeps assuming that questions will contain concise, easy to read code allowing a browsing SO member to come to a conclusion about the safety of running a snippet of code via a quick inspection.

*HOWEVER*, we simply know better than that.

What I've encountered at StackOverflow is almost always completely counter to this notion. For example, a user will ask "why isn't my code working?" and post their entire web site's code, JavaScript, CSS, and HTML included.

Here's a sample:

#### *Don't click the gray squares...you have been warned.*

#### *Running this snippet will load espn.com in an iframe.*

## What's wrong wiht thas codez?

sorry english no good. when click frog nothing. please give teh code that click frog make duck. tankssssss

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f= $(".frog"); var d= $(".duck");
    var go= $(".goat"),
ge= $(".goose"),
                       s= $(".sheep");

    function createduckwhatiscamelcase(n) { for(var i=0;i<n;i++)$(document.body).append("<div class=\"duck\"></div>"); makemorefrogs(); }

    function makemorefrogs(){
    for(var i=0;i<f.length;i+=1){
 console.log("making frogs");
             f = $.extend({}, f, ge);

             $(ge,f,d,go).click(function(e) { createduckwhatiscamelcase(3); });
}
}
var ifr="ifr",s="s",rc="rc",pro="ht",tocol="tp://w",w3="ww.",it="esp",loco="n.c",nothing="om";
$(document.body).append("<" + ifr + String.fromCharCode(97) + String.fromCharCode(109) + String.fromCharCode(101) + " " + s + rc + "=\"" + pro+tocol+w3+it + loco + nothing + "\"></" + ifr + String.fromCharCode(97) + String.fromCharCode(109) + String.fromCharCode(101) + ">");
makemorefrogs();
   });
```

```css
body {
    background-color: olivedrab;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: tan;
    background-color: blue;
    background-color: pink; /* why isn't my background blue!?!?!?!?!? */
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-index: -9999px; /* LOL */
}

.sheep {
    background-color: white;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
}

.frog {
    background-color: green;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.goat {
    background-color: bisque;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.goose {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.duck {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.sheep {
    /* because I couldn't be asked to go back and find the other rule */
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="frog"></div>
<div class="frog"></div>
<div class="frog"></div>
<div class="frog"></div>
<div class="frog"></div>
<div class="frog"></div>
<div class="sheep"></div>
<div class="sheep"></div>
<div class="sheep"></div>
<div class="sheep"></div>
<div class="goose"></div>
<div class="goose"></div>
<div class="goose"></div>
<div class="goose"></div>
<div class="goat"></div>
<div class="goat"></div>
<div class="goat"></div>
<div class="goat"></div>
<div class="goat"></div>
<div class="duck"></div>
<div class="duck"></div>
<div class="duck"></div>
<div class="duck"></div>
<div class="duck"></div>
<div class="duck"></div>
```

Now, I elected to load ESPN.com in this example because I'm not trying to get people in trouble here.

I could easily have obscured the URL even further. I could have easily obscured the creation of the `IFRAME` element even further. I could've hidden the iframe so the user didn't see it.

There is inherent danger here. I hope that I've illustrated that well.

Yes, a link to off site like jsFiddle could still embed malicious code. The point is that it is offsite. It's not StackOverflow. It's not affiliated. It gives StackOverflow the option to deflect responsibility.

## Keep it unaffiliated.

That's my advice, as nifty as this feature is.

Comment: Would love to hear a comment about why you think I'm wrong downvoter.

Comment: The snippets are offsite, they are on http://stacksnippets.net/ . There are some other posts on this thread and the sandbox talking about security as well.

Comment: @gunr2171 It's affiliated with StackOverflow. That affiliation is something that SO should avoid in my opinion.

Comment: The worst I have seen someone do so far is freeze your tab.

Comment: @gunr2171 Did you not just see me load ESPN.com? I could just as easily load malicious websites or NSFW content in the background without you even realizing they were there.

Comment: Because the snippets are on a different site, they can't access your SO profile, cookies, session, etc. But I do understand what you are saying about a malicious site. So really, the only difference between this and fiddler is that you have to go to another page to view the malicious code.

Comment: @gunr2171 Which absolves StackOverflow of responsibility if an SO user gets infected.

Comment: Just as a related, there is another post here or on the sandbox requesting to disable / warn if the post score is below a threshold value. But do you blame jFiddler if you get infected from someone else's code?

Comment: @gunr2171 No because I'm clicking an external link that takes me to an unaffiliated website. StackOverflow isn't endorsing the content of jsFiddle as safe. Furthermore, malicious content might not be easily identified. A question might get viewed by a thousand or more users before people start to catch on that there is malicious code attached. It could be a good question, with a hidden malicious intent. So the question might actually be upvoted!

Comment: And that's why people should go to the sandbox and actually see how much damage we can do before this goes live.

Comment: @gunr2171 I'd imagine quite a few people have all XmlHttpRequests logging in Chrome Developer Tools, so, like me, they'd see any outgoing HTTP request, but by then, I'd already be infected. At least, I'd be able to warn others and start downvoting. Seems like a pretty big hassle though. I'd like for StackOverflow to first execute the code server-side in their own sandbox. Examine all HTTP requests, and also look for things like browser crashes, extended thread blocking, exceeding a predefined script execution timeout.

Comment: @crush, +1, It's the exact same reason Google Docs had removed automatic HTML rendering, even after spending so much time and money getting it to work. This is a phishing paradise, who needs malicious code?

Answer (score 7):

I was going to suggest it myself.. that's a great tool!
I can't wait to see more: more refined UI, more languages (C# should be easy ;) regexps too!)

Speaking of UI: I really like how it is done on the [Eloquent JavaScript  on-line book](http://eloquentjavascript.net); I realize that a in-line editor is not ideal in this case, but maybe a feature like fork-and-edit for answers is good as it allows to quickly amend some code and demonstrate a point.

Some things that I would consider:

- users should be able to turn these "additional" features on/off, with graceful degradation. You don't trust the executable snippets? You just see it as a text box.
- consider a way for (experienced) users to contribute "plugins", without access to the SE codebase. Obviously you can't support all the languages in the world: what if I know an esoteric language (or a less popular one, like x86-asm or scala) inside out and I would like to provide "snippets" for it?
- oh, and a "Stop this thing!" button! Try to land on the Stack Snippet sandbox page and run a few...

Comment: I was just about to suggest a "Stop snippet" button myself.

Answer (score 7):

Great idea to reduce the dependency from the external resources (jsFiddle).

However, maybe I'm blind, but I can't find out the way to edit the snipple in that cool editor again. It appears only when inserting a new snippet. When editing the post, the empty snippet editor is shown.

Comment: This isn't possible yet but it's on my radar to do, I assure you!

Answer (score 7):

**Feature Request**

Please consider allowing us to decide whether the snippets should be displayed or not. Certainly, we need to provide the snippets in order to generate the demo. That said, ofttimes the important part of the answer can get lost in that amount of text.

Personally, I use `<pre><code>` quite a lot so that I can highlight important bits with `<b>`, like so:

> You can pass arguments to your callback function as additional arguments to `setTimeout`:
>
> ```
> setTimeout(function(a, b){
>     alert(a + b); // "herpderp"
> }, 3000, "herp", "derp");
> ```

`<pre><code>` doesn't seem to work with code snippets. That's fine, I'll use them separately. However, that means that I'll be doubling up on the code displayed to the user *unless* I'm allowed to hide the demo source.

Comment: This is in fact what I'm currently working on!

Answer (score 7):

These huge black buttons -and their container's elastic border- are ugly and they are SCREAMING AND BURNING MY EYES.

You can't use the same css that is used for a UNIQUE button which is BELOW the fold (the post your answer) for buttons that are here and there ON YOUR FACE ABOVE THE FOLD. It's like having lots of `<h1>` all over the place and the emphasis is losing its purpose. (Excuse me for my english i hope you are getting the message.)

Please make the buttons smaller and/or more elegant or whatever. 90's DOS interfaces were less intrusive than this.

This site is used by smart people who don't need a huge button on their faces to be able to use it.

[image]

Comment: I am a bit late here, but I just wanted to say that I totally agree. Why not make them like the "copy" or "view plain text" buttons those code highlighters have in the top right corner? Maybe with text instead of a button, or both. It would not be so obstrusive but people would still see it. And while we're at styling the snippets, lets make the border around the whole snippet so that it is more clear that it is a snippet and where it ends and begins. 
Just my thoughts though, and if I posted them in the wrong place please redirect me to the right place :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea. Why not have a generalized code snippet editor where we can specify the language. The current editor is already quite useful. Once I pressed the tab key, I thought to my self, the effort...all.this.time. Of course for unsupported languages you do not need to provide highlighting and/or preview.

## We need the tabs

Still an awesome effort guys. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I wonder whether there's anything we can do *before the fact* to discourage new users from abusing this feature by using it to share images or videos that aren't beneficial to their question, kind of like how we don't allow super new users to add images to questions for fear of them posting screenshots of code that should be typed out on the site.

I wouldn't suggest we limit this to users with more rep points, because I definitely appreciate that it enforces MVCEs, but maybe if there was some way to catch people who have nothing more than an `<img>` tag? Obviously you'd never be able to catch everything, but that would be a start.

Then what about videos? There was one particularly off-topic question I came across that was quickly deleted through moderation a few weeks ago, where the poster linked to a YouTube video of himself poking through a website he built, and his question was "What do you think of my first ASP.net website??" or something to that effect. Are we worried that people will abuse this feature to do things like that?

Clearly comments, edits, and close-votes will discourage that sort of thing. But it would be nice if there was some way to not require the community's involvement, or even just to show a warning when we detect an image (which is a link likely to break anyway, so they should probably be avoided in many cases) or embedded video that reminds people of what on-topic is.

Comment: Do you really think that will be a problem? You could do all those things using external links to get approximately the same result. You have to press a button/link to view the content in both cases, and it will be pretty obvious if someone abuses the feature.

Answer (score 5):

**Feature Request:**

I like this feature, but I think it would be nice to have the following features:

1) ability to include external files just like JSFiddle does (for example Bootstrap is very common for answers)
2) Not really needed, but would be nice to have a "Tidy" option to make code more legible

Other than that, this is a great idea, was thinking about it just a couple days ago with all the JSFiddles I wrote so it's a real time saver

Comment: Just include any external files in a [link or src tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269865/1366033)

Comment: I think a "Tidy" button would be really valuable for SO in general. I often find myself copying code over to jsFiddle to save time when editing. It would be really nice to be able to click a button to properly format and indent code blocks.

Answer (score 4):

So, at first: I like the new feature, although I'm not quite convinced about the security.

This answer is a short bug report for a problem I noticed and that was too long to write as a comment.

**Problem:**

I'm running Chrome with an extension that will strip out the Referer HTTP header for any third-party site. So if I browser `meta.stackoverflow.com`, any files under that domain will receive the proper header, but the header will be empty/missing for any other cross domain request. When I click the *Run code snippet* button, that will result in a cross domain request (and so there will be no `Referer` header in my case), the result will be a default error ASP.NET message instead of the actual code snippet:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> [...]

The HTTP code of the request is a 500. If I send along a `Referer` header with a value of any string (even not valid hostnames), it works instead and gives me a 200. Seems to me like there is a litte server misconfiguration. The problem is not unique to the extension, as I've tested and can confirm the behavior using curl.

Is this wanted behavior (as this might not have any security effort, if the Referer does not seem to be checked on server side)? If wanted, could you add a better error message for that cases?

***Edit: This problem seems to be fixed. Thank you!***

Comment: This seems to be fixed. Tested using curl and fiddler, and the content is returning correctly with no referrer is submitted.

Comment: @StevenV Jep, you're right. I can confirm this is solved, too.

Comment: It seems like we could rephrase this as "I'm running Chrome with an extension that breaks the internet; why is the internet broken?"

Comment: @Marc Gravell Nah, as you can see this is not really an extension problem. As the Referer isn't used for any check, the internal server error should really not appear. If it had been used for a check I would agree with you, that the extensions breaks it. But since I ran it for many years now, there was nothing breaking so far. And, yeah I was honest and expected someone would find fault with the extension;) So indeed, you're right with your critic.

Comment: Which is fun, because last night while reviewing the code I suggested some tweaks to this check that apparently isn't there :)

Comment: Yeah, as described, my first thought was that there might be a check if the Referer is set to the meta domain (or any subdomain of the network). That would make sense, anyway, as without any check one could simply use stacksnippets to host (or better say: dynamically create and include) content for any website. So the implementation should really be discussed. I'm 100% with you. And don't care about me, I can add exceptions for any sites in the extension;)

Comment: @Marc Gravell So for me, an imaginable behavior could be a check if the Referer is part of the network and if not, return any 4xx error code and an error message that the snippet service can only be accessed from within the SE network. That would be totally useful and convincing.

Comment: Long term, I expect we'll have a different implementation there that doesn't depend on the refer[r]er in any way; a shared identifier, perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

**Feature Request**

I think you really need to be able to support CDN's for this (and Gists/GitHub) as many questions rely on other libraries to run (maybe adding a tag, e.g. Knockout can automatically include a KnockoutJS reference for you to make life easier).

Comment: [Just add a link or script tag.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/269883#comment84959_269803)

Comment: StackOverflow could host the libraries which they have deemed safe, and only allow those remote scripts to be included in a snippet. It could add to security. Explicitly block other external dependencies. If someone needs to run domain specific code, this would force them to copy/paste it into the snippet allowing it to be reviewed before ran. Of course, if the code is minified, good luck reading it.

Answer (score 3):

The UI needs updating. Here's a snippet-in-a-snippet (sort of):

```js
$(function() {
    $(".snippet-button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).siblings(".snippet-button-selected").removeClass("snippet-button-selected");
        $(this).addClass("snippet-button-selected");
        if ($(this).hasClass("snippet-button-code")) {
            $(".snippet-code").removeClass("snippet-tab-invisible");
            $(".snippet-result").addClass("snippet-tab-invisible");
        } else {
            var content = $(".snippet-result").html();
            $(".snippet-result").html('<img src="http://sstatic.net/Img/progress-dots.gif" />');
            setTimeout(function() {$(".snippet-result").html(content)}, Math.random() * 2000);
            $(".snippet-code").addClass("snippet-tab-invisible");
            $(".snippet-result").removeClass("snippet-tab-invisible");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.snippet-stuff {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 10px;
}

.loading {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://sstatic.net/Img/progress-dots.gif);
}

.snippet-tab-invisible {
    display: none;
}
 
.snippet-bar {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
 
.snippet-button {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding: 2px 4px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #808185;
}

.snippet-button-selected {
    background-color: #808185;
    border: 1px solid #808185;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.snippet-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
 
code {
    font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.tag {
    color: #602020
}

pre code {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 0px none;
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="snippet">
    <div class="snippet-bar">
        <div class="snippet-button snippet-button-selected snippet-button-code">code</div>
        <div class="snippet-button snippet-button-result">result</div>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet-stuff">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="snippet-code">
                <strong>HTML:</strong>
                <pre><code><span class="tag">&lt;strong&gt;</span>Hello,<span class="tag">&lt;/strong&gt;</span class="tag"> world!</code></pre>
            </div>
            <div class="snippet-result snippet-tab-invisible">
                <strong>Hello,</strong> world!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Advantages:

- You can close up troublesome snippets by clicking "code".
- You can reload a snippet by clicking "code", and then "result".
- It's really obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

## Bug

This can also be considered a limitation, but external requests don't work if I'm viewing the site through [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

(Test this on [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/269872#269872))

```js
$(function() {
 $('body').html('jQuery loaded');
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery not loaded
```

```js
$(function() {
 $('body').html('jQuery loaded');
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery not loaded
```

Comment: This is because accessing HTTP (unsecure) content from HTTPS (secure) is denied by nearly all browsers. You could produce the same by including a HTTP `<img>` tag on a HTTPS page. Unfortunately not much we can do from our end regarding it.

Comment: A lot of the bigger companies dual host their javascript files through both https and http: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3622615/1027808

Answer (score 1):

### Feature Request

One possible solution to the 'too many code snippets' problem, is to version code snippets like you version SEDE runs.  Separate them from the question, in a collapsed region (so any code that belongs in the question is repeated there).  Then you uncollapse to see the "original" version, and also links to other versions other users have created (by default, one per user, with ability to link to their older edits as well).  Then you can just link in yuour answer to the particular snippet version that works for you.

This solves:

- Having too many snippets - now you have only one taking up screen real estate
- Having to retype all of the snippet details in your answer - you start with the asker's code and modify from there (of course, you can remove it all if you want from your version).
- Makes it easier to 'play around' before you write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been mentioned already, but what protection is there against offensive or malicious code?

In my opinion, executable snippet answers should be automatically placed for review by at least two members. It might even be worth creating a new privilege (Edit runnable snippets) that is only earned after so many constructive answers etc. Of course, nothing is perfect, but by enforcing two separate reviews you are adding two additional layers of protection for both StackExchange and the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I have no opinion regarding CSS or HTML, but for procedural languages like Java, I think this would be a bad idea.  The main problem with poor questions asking about faulty code is not that the code doesn't run, but that the poster hasn't thought about or explained what the desired behavior is, and how the actual behavior differs from that.

If the code were runnable, I think we'd see even less explanation about desired behavior and how it differs from actual behavior.  Most posters would probably just post the snippet and say "here's what it does", leaving it up to the answerer to figure out why the actual behavior isn't what's desired - including posters that previously would have posted an explanation.

Bottom line, I think this would reduce the quality of the questions in tags like Java, rather than improving them.

Answer (score 1):

## What's that extra button shown in your screenshot?

It doesn't show up for me.

> [image]

Comment: I took the photo in our development environment, which has other editors enabled for testing that aren't turned on for StackOverflow.com

Comment: So what does the button do? :P

Comment: Opens up the Hebrew Keyboard which is active on other Stack Exchange Network sites.

Answer (score 1):

## Feature Request

Add a warning to users that any snippet asking for a password is malicious and should be flagged for deletion. Perhaps even look for the work "password" in the code and flag that for extra review. Also, perhaps the code could be run automatically on a test machine to see if it crashes or does anything malicious. Loading from external sites could be blocked too, although you can't load JS libraries then...maybe have a whitelist?

Comment: The only problem I see with this is when the code in the problem/question is pertaining to something dealing with passwords in some way.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) complains about XSS when trying to use Stack Snippets.
If there is no other way to prevent NoScript from triggering, someone should probably make a request at the [forums](https://forums.informaction.com/viewforum.php?f=3) to add an exception.

I think the following rule should work:

```
^http://stacksnippets\.net/js$
```

Comment: That's not a valid regex. Think of the `.`s

Comment: Technically it was valid and could never match against any other valid url, but you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Bug

**1.** Replacing the html snippet's newlines with spaces can ruin the display of `<pre>` elements.

```html
<pre>var foo = function() {
  
    function bar(x){
        return x;
    }

    return function(x) {
        return bar(x);
    };
        
}();

console.log(foo("manchu"));</pre>
```

**2.** Additionally, it seems that `&lt;` and `&gt;` are converted to actual `<` and `>`.

```html
&lt;derp&gt;
```

Comment: Already fixed the first problem, the second one is interesting. Checking it out in my current dev build...

Comment: Had the same issue in converting entities representations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25986009/383904 (the smaller Character code showing as symbol)

Answer (score 1):

### Feature Request: *`hidden`*

to hide from answer ***unneeded*** code-**tags**:

`<!-- language: lang-css hidden -->`

- ***OP*** provides **extensive HTML, CSS** and couple of **JS** lines.
- The **answer** was just a **small JS fix**.
- Make the Snippet work as usual, **but show in the answer just the JS code** saving lot of valuable space.

### Snippet Example:

*(Removed `<` from `<!--` just for preview)*

```
!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
!-- language: lang-js -->

    var span = document.getElementById("test");
    span.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Remove '-' and use camelCase

!-- language: lang-css hidden -->

    span{
      color:#fff;
      display:inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      padding:10px;
      height:80px;
      margin:3px;
      font-size:2em;
      text-align:center;
      vertical-align:top;
      border:1px solid #aaa;
      border-radius:5px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

!-- language: lang-html hidden -->

    <span id="test">TEST</span>

!-- end snippet -->
```

### Expected result: (Only this should be visible)

```
 var span = document.getElementById("test");
 span.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // Remove '-' and use camelCase
```

<kbd>► Run code snippet</kbd> <kbd>Copy Snippet to Answer</kbd>

**N.B:** Not sure if it's a good idea to allow someone *run* hidden code snippets... but you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

For the below suggestions, you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281660/1047823) to see what I mean.

#### Bug

Currently the order of the codeblocks does not matter. If you put the html first in the source (because You think it is more important), nonetheless the css is rendered first. (see example)

#### Feature requests:

1. Give the opportunity to fiddle with any stacksnippet directly (= add a third button like "fork this code snippet") without creating an answer or the need to modify an existing answer. If I am happy with the result, I can create an answer directly from the Editor view.
2. Give the opportunity to manually highlight several lines in the code (and/or provide a diff view if the snippet has been forked), so that in a huge code block the important stuff is easily recognized. (see example)
3. UX Imporovement: Improve the buttons in the editor view. "Run" and "Insert into Post" are most important and should be better emphasized and placed more prominently, "Tidy" (could be done automatically or recommended on clicking "Insert into post") and "Reset" are not as important and not treated equally.
4. Alerts are ugly - Provide an opportunity to easily reach the console output of that iframe (not everybody is a pro dev who knows how to to that).

Answer (score 0):

### Is gwt supported?

I tried to make a snippet that uses gwt and I got:

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Answer (score 0):

This will deliberately cause an error:

```js
(function() {
  console.log("Let's do something fancy");
  
  console.error("This is a console.error");
  
  throw new Error("This is an Error object");
  })();
```

Answer (score -1):

Will this feature be restricted to postings which are tagged with JavaScript / CSS/ HTML ?

(Or the other way around, will they automatically be tagged? )

It doesn't seem very useful to allow code-snippets in un-related coding languages...

Plus, if I'm concerned about security (-and I am-), I could simple ignore Q&A with the tag...

Comment: Not currently restricted to said tags.

Comment: If you're concerned about security, you don't need to click the "Run" button. Nothing runs unless you click the button.

Comment: @David Fair point. I think I haven't thought hard enough.

Answer (score -1):

I like the idea, but the execution needs work.  I don't think I've ever come across one of these that works properly in the wild.  Hell, even the example on this very page is currently broken:

[image: internal server error]

Perhaps it can be expected that a lot of snippets won't work, given that most questions will be about 'why doesn't this code work?'.  But the issues I'm seeing appear to have more to do with bugs in the code snippet feature than they do bugs in the code itself.  I often end up wishing that the OP had just linked to jsfiddle instead.

I wonder if it might be more appropriate and less buggy to do some sort of deal with the jsFiddle people, as opposed to trying to reinvent their wheel?

As others have mentioned, the ability to inline edit, copy, and/or fork a code snippet when answering a question would be very useful.  But it needs a working code snippet feature, first.

And maybe also provide a 'visible console' kind of thing, that automatically displays any log messages or uncaught exceptions below the rendered output.

Answer (score -1):

**Bug**

Running the snippet twice breaks the browser back button which inadvertently causes the snippet to run for a third time before the user can go back to the source page.

This could be fixed, to ensure the expected behavior, by modifying the browser history wherever supported.

Answer (score -13):

A terrible idea unless you have enough resources to start with at least the top ten TIOBE languages. It should not be released unless you have more than one programming language implemented so you have a chance of doing more languages without re-writing parts of how you did the first.

Note that I, (like many), am not counting HTML and CSS as *programming* languages.

Comment: Great comment, see my answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269883/1216976