# Proper use of the <kbd> tag

Tags: discussion, markdown

I've found that the `<kbd>` tag is very useful for marking up stuff other than actual keyboard keys. For example,

1. Menus: "Navigate to the <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Open</kbd> option"
2. Buttons: "Press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button."

Technically, this does match the [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/kbd).

> When the kbd element contains a samp element, it represents input based on system output, for example invoking a menu item.

I feel it makes my posts much more clear when used judiciously. Will I be going against any SO guidelines if I use it this way?

Comment: What are you actually bothering about? It's just markup and has it's use in certain contexts. Subsets of HTML are supported in markup, `<samp>` isn't AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, it's just markup. I just wanted to know if I would be going against SO guidelines if I use it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I clarified my question.. I assure you that my intentions are most honorable! :)

Comment: _"I assure you that my intentions are most honorable! :) "_ I never doubted that.

Comment: Related: [Stricter <kbd> usage rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules)

Comment: [Building castles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131634/135695).  I thought everyone knew [`<kbd>` was made for building castles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/135695).  And sometimes [keyboards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1950/135695) And [more keyboards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156177/135695)  But mostly [castles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131926/135695)

Comment: @BenVoigt yup.. definitely that! Don't know what I was thinking!!

Comment: And Newcomer's [analogy between bricklayers and programmers](http://www.flounder.com/bricks.htm) has finally reached transcendence.

Comment: See also on SE Meta: [Can we use 'kbd' according to its definition in HTML5?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215133/can-we-use-kbd-according-to-its-definition-in-html5)

Comment: @unor hmm.. that's almost the same as this question. I should migrate this question to MSE and then mark as duplicate.

Comment: No need, we just need a way to mark cross-meta dupes.

Comment: @BoltClock Is there a feature request somewhere?

Answer (score 57):

> Is this acceptable usage on SO?

<kbd>Sure, why not?</kbd>

You can mark-up your posts however you want, with some exceptions.

### - Excessive or `inappropriate` ***emphasis*** formatting may be <sub>destroyed</sub> in the course of **normal** peer editing.

> Any text that you're quoting verbatim should probably use a >blockquote
> for the sake of clear and explicit attribution

[Nonsensical links may be interpreted as spam - nothing good will come of that.](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=how%20to%20make%20your%20own%20dog%20food)

These tools exist to help you communicate effectively. I wouldn't advocate searching for posts that contain `Ctrl + C` for the sole purpose of marking them up as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> but if you think making a word look like a key or a button is going to make your own contribution come across more clearly, go for it. The worst that's going to happen if the community deems it to be inappropriate is that it'll be edited out and you may receive 1 snark.

Comment: Oh good grief! That's a bit... excessive. I have better uses for my time than going around changing others' posts to use `<kbd>`s. :)

Comment: @metacubed That wasn't aimed at you specifically; I wouldn't want to inadvertently give the impression that tweaking the markup of every post containing `Ctrl` would be acceptable. Some people do *not* have better uses for their time (and assume the same of the rest of us).

Comment: @metacubed The reason you identify in your post is a fine use, unless your post is filled solely with a bunch of buttons that people should be clicking that then makes the post look like an eye sore. As long as you don't start using `<kbd>` to make *links* look like buttons, I won't have to hunt you down. ;)

Comment: Must... resist... editing!

Comment: Today I learned how to make my own dog food.

Answer (score 56):

[<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>I totally agree</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220164/205214)

*as long as you do not do what I did.

The only problem <kbd>I</kbd> see is, that it <kbd>could</kbd> break the <kbd>flow</kbd>, at least if used <kbd>excessively</kbd>.

Comment: I'd love to have a **`flow`** button on my keyboard ;>

Comment: it looks like this css should be fixed.

Comment: I'd rather have the excessively button.

Comment: I could also flow excessively, but I only do that judiciously.

Comment: I'd rather have the **I** button...oh wait.

Comment: I think Windows XP used to do that... once in a while..

Comment: I've thought about replacing my enter keys with either *this* or *Make it so*. *Enter* seems so wrong

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd [Fixed it for ya](http://i.imgur.com/nm7sIfB.jpg) (btw, what a weerd name).

Comment: @CamiloMartin - Nice :) yeah, I never use my last name abroad...

Answer (score 8):

The original use-case for the keyboard tag was [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/150288). It was used as a prototype for the implementation, and as a benchmark platform for performance of the inline CSS and `<table>` tags that power our comments sections.

Any usage outside of the end goals is usually frowned upon, but now that we have [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), the `<kbd>` tag may be phased out.

(Markdown may also be discontinued when Stack Snippets support MediaWiki rendering.)

On a slightly more relevant note. I don't think you will be banned for your mis-use *yet*.

Also:

<kbd><kbd>FooBar's Blog</kbd>`Ads`

<kbd>nav

 

`Ads`

`Ads`</kbd>
<kbd><kbd>Article</kbd>

<kbd>Article</kbd>

<kbd>Article</kbd></kbd>

       <kbd>Footer      `Ads`</kbd></kbd>

Comment: Wait wait…what? The original "use case" for the tag was *not* building castles. That was just a joke, people having fun on Meta. The *use case* is exactly what it seems like: indicating which keys you should press on your keyboard to initiate a particular action. Like `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to build the project` or what have you. That Meta post was certainly used as an example of how the tag can be *misused*, and Jeff issued a stern warning against its misuse, lest it be disabled again. And yeah, it was used for both benchmarking and assessing the layout. But not the "use case".

Comment: Secondly, how in the world does Stack Snippets replace the use of the `<kbd>` tag? You aren't going to write a code snippet to show people which keys to press on their keyboard, are you? I certainly hope not. Stack Snippets is not replacing the way that users post answers, it is *augmenting* it. Just like with any other code sample, you'll still need to have an actual answer.

Comment: @CodyGray: I think your irony detector might be broken. [At least, I hope it was irony... ;-)]

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, this was irony... is it that hard to spot? Also, if you've ever seen MediaWiki... well... yeah, this was a joke...

Comment: @CodyGray On a second thought... If you thought I was being serious, you're severely desensitised to stupidity, lol. I should set up a cron job that prays for you at night.

Comment: I find your use of `Ads` offensive. `</missing-the-point>`

Comment: @michaelb958 Just a realistic rendition. AdBlock is your friend ;)

Comment: Totally missed the irony. I've been hanging out on Meta for a while, there are lots of people with inestimable levels of confusion about how the site works.

Comment: `crontab -e`, 30 2 * * * /bin/pray @CodyGray

Answer (score 3):

I think `<kbd>` is really good when keyboard keys are being mentioned, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. Otherwise, it seems out of place for me (except for the castles case, of course).

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

It's encouraged, as you can see by the fact that there is a nice mechanical-keyboard style associated with it here!

Answer (score -6):

I sometimes highlight links to external IDE sites (e.g. jsFiddle) with the `<kbd>` tag. To me it feels almost like a "Run" button of sorts:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://www.example.com)</kbd>

I guess Stack Snippets will be the way to go in the future, though.

Comment: Don't do this. It's inappropriate.

Comment: That's good to hear, I've never been called out on it before. I will break the habit immediately.

Comment: It _is_ inappropriate and bad and wrong. Still, now I've seen it, I can't help but like it... :/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I saw it, liked it, and adopted it, but never felt 100% that I should be using it. Now I know!

Comment: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit. My first thought was "hey, that's not what it's supposed to... uh, actually looks slick..."

Comment: What's the difference between a link and a button?

Comment: @ADTC I can't find the "jsFiddle Demo" button anywhere on my keyboard.

Comment: @ADTC In what context? HTML? Dress shirts?

Comment: Cody I think they are called keys, not buttons (it's not a buttonboard). @AirThomas Dress shirts and chains.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ AFAIK there's no rule against this, staff/mods telling you that you shouldn't should be interpreted as their strong opinion, not an act of enforcement.