# How to deal with persistent incorrect formatting?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I came across [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083093/devrath?tab=answers) who persistently uses incorrect formatting in their posts. Other users have [communicated to them regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/40696894), but the behavior continues.

How should we deal with this?

---

### Exhibit A:

[image]

---

### Exhibit B:

[image]

---

### Exhibit C:

[image]

Comment: Is the _content_ good? If so, simply edit it. If not, downvote and move on.

Comment: Persist or give up and leave it to others to take over the torch.

Comment: I won't downvote, just because of misguided formatting by a user. I don't mind editing and cleaning up, but I want to know if that is acceptable, because OP might get upset if I edit all their posts and fix the formatting.

Comment: I've just gone through the top-voted ones (anything 10 and up) and cleaned up. Copy editing, toning down the emphasis, including 'backticks are for code' in the summary, etc.

Comment: ... considering how he wrote his about me I doubt he'll change behaviour.

Comment: Are there any guidelines on how to format questions and answers? I took a (very quick) look and can't find anything. Without them, is the user really doing anything wrong?

Comment: Ever thought about that this could be a genuine inability of that user (and possibly others) to express themselves with good formatting? As long as the content is good and salvaging edits get not rejected, I think we have much more important fronts to achieve real improvements on overall quality.

Comment: @DavidG I thought [we have it already](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), but after reading it, it doesn't seem covering what you ask.

Comment: @AndrewT. Exactly, that the general point I was trying to make. If a user chooses to format an answer in his own way, is there anything fundamentally wrong with it? It may look like a car crash to you and me, but to him it's perfect.

Comment: @DavidG: "You, me and him" don't matter on SO. It should be easy to read to the average visitor. Excess boldness and code blocks really don't help.

Comment: @DavidG: Correct formatting is critical to quality of a post, [relevant meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back). Formatting rules apply for all, we can't use them based on our individual preferences.

Comment: I strike it up to bio-diversity; you can't force everyone to think the same because that's not how we're programmed. There are people who take the time and effort to ensure courtesy, and there are people who roll their eyes and only wonder why people make such a fuss; 'if you can read the text then why make a point of when something is bold or not'. Both have a place in this world AND on SO (or any other stackexchange site) in my opinion.

Comment: @Gimby: This is a repository of knowledge we are building, like a wiki. All the pages should look uniform, like all the pages of wikipedia look uniform.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I understand that. That still doesn't change the fact that the people inputting said information are human rather than robotic. It is either accept the fact that questions WILL be poorly formatted often (which in SE is not acceptable), or accept the burden of having to repeatedly edit questions to clean them up. Its the lot of SE that it is necessary to do that forever and always. In my opinion.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Ironically, this question demonstrates my point somewhat. I found it difficult to read and made an edit. In **my** view, it's easier, but you rolled it back. As SO has no guidelines on how to format, either version is correct. PS No hard feelings for the rollback! PPS Can you at least correct the bolding for the "Exhibit A" title? :)

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for the edit, I was thinking about the same irony while rolling it back. Your edit was indeed an eye-opener, and I fixed the Exhibit A now. Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidG: I'd suggest not using HTML (`<hr/>`) on SO. For consistency, stick to markdown.

Comment: Related, but about <2k users: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198142/appropriate-actions-for-user-making-multiple-accepted-incorrect-edits

Comment: You could always go the Jon Skeet route and write a blog entry on how to properly format a question that many people read over time, then link it in your profile, then amass an extraordinary amount of rep / profile views such that everyone on the internet has read it or doesn't have an excuse to not have read it. :)

Comment: I see nothing at all wrong with Exhibit A.  Menu options can include punctuation of their own, so that type of quote is the only way to correctly separate them from the rest of the text while keeping it inline.  It also emphasizes that it's a property of the program, not a title or actual quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing is for

```
fixing grammatical or spelling errors
clarifying meaning without changing it
correcting minor mistakes
adding related resources or links,
```

## improving and fixing the formatting and readability of the post

while always *respecting* the original author

There's **no limit** to users `overusing formatting`, however *when it harms readability*, **you** can always **edit to fix it**.

#### Or, educate them

Which you have attempted and empirically did not help in this case.

There's nothing else we can do here.

Read more:

[Proper use of the <kbd> tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270970/3622940)

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter formatting that you think is wrong then you should ask yourself these questions:

1. Am I having trouble reading and understanding this post, and is the formatting causing this trouble?
2. Is something about this formatting causing the answer communicated to be wrong?

If the answer to either of those questions is **yes**, then you should edit that post and move on.

If the answer to both of these questions is **no**, then the formatting is not really wrong.

Comment: But that's often a subjective viewpoint. What makes sense to me doesn't necessarily make sense to you. What I think we need are some guidelines on how to format. Its never going to be 100% objective but we can try.