# How can I insert a SQL "Live Demo" into my answer?

Tags: support, answers, formatting

I've seen a few people insert a "Live Demo" button in their answers instead of having to link to an external SQLFiddle. How do I do that? Is it restricted to a subset of users based on Reputation?

[This is one such answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903407/2432845):

[image]

Comment: That *is* a link to an external site.. It's just styled like a button (and the link happens to be to a *related* site).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can [compose](https://data.stackexchange.com) a query at the **Stack Exchange Data Explorer**.

Use the following code to create a button like this:
<kbd>**`Example button`**</kbd>

```
<kbd>**[`Example button`](#example-button)**</kbd>
```

Where you replace `#example-button` with a link to your query.

Comment: I actually hadn't seen it since it always scroll outside of the screen '-'. 10 more minutes until I can accept. Thanks.

Comment: Now SEDE has become our own SQLFiddle.  That's great.

Comment: @Becuzz SEDE was around long before SQLFiddle and able to be used for this.

Comment: Be warned that people who care about correct semantic markup do not approve of this use of `kbd` though....

Comment: @MartinSmith what's the proper use of `<kbd>`, and what would be the proper way of linking a demo?

Comment: More on the `kbd-button`: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270967/proper-use-of-the-kbd-tag

Comment: And this one here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules. I guess the "proper" way would be a boring hyperlink.