# Flow for using Stack Snippets in comments

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

It can be very useful to **use a snippet when asking for clarification in a comment**. For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26238196/419956) I posted such a comment:

> There's something else going on in your styles. [The code as posted works as you want it to.](http://jsfiddle.net/ygyjzzd4/) Please update your question with (as little as possible) extra code to help us repro your scenario.

Note that the comment currently links to jsfiddle. It would be nice to be able to use the built-in Stack Snippets feature as well, *given* that the [original announcement's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/419956) "why" section indicated that one goal was to remove reliance on off-site resources.

I am not sure how the UI or UX for all this should work; perhaps someone can propose something in an answer, or perhaps if this request makes the road map the team should design a flow.

Comment: Not an easy thing to implement, but it would definitely be useful.  I know that I have posted many answers with JSFiddle links where a little bit of back-and-forth modifying the example through comments is required before all the original poster's issues are addressed.

Comment: Aye, that happens. However, my feature request was *not* meant for the "back and forth" situation (i.e. I don't need support for cloning comment snippets in new comments), only to help explain users how to improve their question (i.e. show that they should include a repro in their question).

Comment: I think it can be very usefull. I wanted to add three lines to a suggested answer but didn't want to duplicate the suggested answer code. I ended up writing the code in the comment but it doesn't look too nice.