# Stack Snippet vs Code Snippet - Inconsistent naming

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

Following is the tooltip for [stack-snippets](/questions/tagged/stack-snippets) :

- Stack Overflow:

  > [image: SO tooltip]
- Meta Stack Overflow

  > [image: Meta tooltip]
- Meta Stack Exchange

  > [image]

Why do we generally call it [stack-snippets](/questions/tagged/stack-snippets), but the tooltip reads *code snippet*..?

This is irritating me for a while because whenever I have to suggest adding a *stack-snippet* to a **new user**, I've to mention *Code snippet*, because that's the name he'll find when he looks for the the option.

Inconsistent design is bad. Can we either change the tooltip to *Stack snippet* or rename the [stack-snippets](/questions/tagged/stack-snippets) tag to *code-snippets*..?

---

If this is not possible, then a [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-links/info) to [introduction of *stack snippets*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/2333214) or [the tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) will be helpful.

Comment: What is the point in creating a feature-request and not tagging it a feature-request? It makes almost no difference to how people vote and that doesn't matter anyway because there's no reputation. All you're doing is making it a bit more annoying to find duplicates. Can you either tag this as feature-request or remove the sentence that makes the request?

Comment: @Ben ha, you've a point. feature request it is!

Comment: I don't think renaming a tag is a good idea, `code-snippets` might as well be a tag on its own which can mean code snippets other than on SO's implementation.

Comment: @UmurKontacı What do you mean *"other than on SO's implementation"*... *Stack* Snippet stands for the implementation across all stackexchange sites... the tag name in metastackexchange is also [*stack-snippets*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stack-snippets/info), but tooltip is *code snippet*... this is an issue across all stackexchange sites I believe...

Comment: And now I'm wondering why I posted it here rather than posting in http://meta.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: I should elaborate. `code-snippet` is a more generic name, it doesn't necessary refer to stack snippets. There might be a set of questions talking about how to show a code snippet or something similar in general whereas `stack-snippet` tag directly refers to a feature of SO/SE.

Comment: I'd strongly advise *against* changing the tag name, as "stack snippet" is the official name.

Comment: @AstroCB Yes, I too vote fore *Stack Snippet*... Not sure why the tooltip reads something else...