# Should an answer link to live code?

Tags: discussion, external-links, code

If I'm answering a question and I find myself writing code that lends itself to a live demonstration, as in the case of HTML and JavaScript, should I link to a page where readers can see it in action? My instinct is to do so, but I don't know if it's considered good form.

Comment: For improvement it should, yes. But that's optional though.

Comment: As long as you keep in mind that the answer should be complete even if the link does not work anymore, sure.

Comment: For the case of HTML/JS you can use [stack snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: I don't think that is appropriate, but the question is good so have my +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some time now we've had snippets ([see the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in Lucas's comment). For pure HTML, CSS and Javascript questions, external sources should not be required.

I know may users love JSFiddle and other sites that provide similar service. Just keep in mind that if all you got to show is an external resource, and the link to that resource is dead... Then all downvotes and close votes are not only justified, they are the correct thing to do. A question that is completely self-contained here seems like a better way to ask.