# Should we automatically detect pastebin (and other related) sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, code

New users can only post a limited amount of links. However, they might reserve this link for paste sites such as pastebin, bpaste and so on. In my opinion, these kinds of websites are useless as the code will be moved into the question anyway. Since I don't think banning links is very user friendly, perhaps a warning should be displayed instead. Something along the lines of:

> It appears you're attempting to post a link to an off-site code
>   sharing site. Have you learned about creating a [Minimal, Complete,
>   and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or our
>   [Stack
>   Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)
>   feature? If your code is not written in one of the languages supported by
>   our Stack Snippet, please paste the code into the question box and
>   consider choosing amongst these [free online
>   compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

The last link leads to the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag wiki which has a list of online compilers commonly used by the C++ community. I'm not too happy with this as it contains three links. The warning box probably shouldn't contain links at all. But the key points are there:

- if you have a code dump and it can't fit into the question, reduce it into an MCVE.
- use the feature that's meant to supersede jsfiddle and discourage code paste websites
- use online compilers vetted by the community

The last one is a bit more difficult since it's hidden away in the tag wiki. Some canonical (albeit off-topic) questions may contain online compilers that are commonly used (especially if it supports multiple languages). The goal here is to introduce them to websites that will be familiar to the community.

What should be done here?

Comment: Why mention both StackSnippet and C++ tag wiki in the same warning?

Comment: @nhahtdh Because Stack Snippets only support HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The C++ tag wiki was an example, obviously it will be different for other languages. But there will be overlap for ideone, etc.

Comment: I like the fact you propose to point people to the help and educate them about posting better questions when they're about to do something wrong.

Comment: First of all, we shouldn't treat a link to pastebin or any other site different that all other cases where a user fails to post a MCVE - close with the appropriate close reason. Second, display as many warnings as you want, that doesn't stop people from not reading them. Third, there is exactly one programming language (JS) supported by stack snippets, and people already don't get that they can't paste C code in there; if we were to stick such a warning in peoples faces we would need to make abundantly clear that it's only for JS/HTML/CSS and nothing else.

Comment: @l4mpi I already have a separate proposal for that. Although you have a totally valid argument. OT: I just realized I had this tagged as support. D'oh!

Comment: Isn't this really a feature request, in spite of being framed to encourage discussion?

Comment: @jpmc26 No, I already listed the disadvantages of my current proposal.

Comment: @remyabel I have a feeling I haven't read some post about what is and is not a feature request because I'm not clear why that makes a difference. I only brought it up since you mentioned fixing the tags; sorry to bother you.

Comment: @remyabel When I said, "fixing the tags," I meant where you changed from [tag:support] to [tag:discussion].

Comment: @jpmc26 That was a mistake. It wasn't meant to be tagged support initially.

Comment: This is great, except, please do not mention Stack Snippets, because it already gets misused by new users.

Comment: @Radiodef Why not..? At some point of time they need to learn how to use it... Pointing them to the meta or blog post that explains how to use them wouldn't hurt IMHO.

Comment: @TJ I guess I don't think most new users will read the link. ; )

Comment: There are legitimate uses of those sites. For example if they do not want to post code under the CC license of SO. Remember that you are **not** allowed to remove pastebin&co links and pasting the contents in the question, because the licenses may not be compatible. Only the OP should do that, you can only ask them to do it and downvote/vote to close the question.

Comment: I often encourage users to paste SQL Server execution plans to such sites as they are verbose, XML format and nobody wants to see them in the question itself (even if they would be under the length limit).

Comment: @Bakuriu: Not wanting to post code under the license of SO is not a legitimate reason to use such. At least as far as the question cannot stand on its own without it.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's what I meant by the last sentence: it's a right of the OP to post his contents where he wants with the license he chooses however it's his duty to follow SO guidelines and if he doesn't then downvote & close vote the question.