# Is it ok to fix broken code in a question you asked so you can use that code (JSfiddle) somewhere else?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I asked a question and created a fiddle to show my code so I could request people review and help me find out where I went wrong. Folks gave me *wonderful* answers that fixed my primary problem.

Now I have a secondary, unrelated problem involving this newly-fixed code. I'd like to just fix the fiddle and reuse it in a secondary question about something unrelated at all to my original question, but doing so breaks my original question as it looks like I'm asking how to fix "fixed" code.

What's the etiquette on this? Do I copy my broken code into a *new* fiddle and post that separately, leaving the original to show its brokenness, or may I edit my broken fiddle to use elsewhere anew?

Comment: Can't you just copy the code to your new question and fix it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insist on using the original fiddle, you can click on the <kbd>Fork</kbd> button to create a new fiddle. There's also a number at the end of the url i.e. `http://jsfiddle.net/q7ghLvkd/2/` which indicates a different version (or revision, I'm not entirely familiar with how jsfiddle works.)

But you shouldn't be using jsfiddle in the first place, now that [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) have been rolled out. There is no excuse to host code dumps on external sites anymore. If there's too much code to show, you can hide them. It also eliminates the problem of link rot and lack of a real "revision history". Hosting the code here allows SO's moderation tools to take full effect.

The problem is confounded if the original code that was buggy is now fixed in your current jsfiddle URL. Now the answers are permanently invalidated. *If* you still have access to the original buggy code, please paste them in a stack snippet and edit your question. Then use a stack snippet for your new question.

If you still feel that there is too much code to paste, then visit [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about Stack Snippets. I was completely unaware of this feature. I'll start using it from now on. I'll also consider your other advice and change the way I ask questions/construct the actual question text/code snippets here.