# Does the new "runnable snippets" feature poses security risks?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, editor

Runnable snippets are very handy, especially when tackling JS and HTML questions, but they basically allow random people to execute random code in your browser.

I realize that snippets are iframed, thus sandboxed etc. etc. and that you have to run them explicitely, but aren't they just too open to malicious usages, like triggering social engineering tricks or vulnerabilities hidden in a JS mess? Would a basic sanitization be even possible?

Of course, any tech-savvy user would flag such a post immediately, but beginners might not spot the issue until it's too late.

Comment: I can't imagine how the social engineering tricks would work within the context of Stack Snippets. In any case, [this answer on the original post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269810/359284) is related.

Comment: Speaking of social engineering: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287238