# Posting malicious code as an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

**A note to the reader**:
I posted this question because I felt that something more needed to be done than I had already done. I was wrong. After a spirited, but civilized debate, a definitive answer was posted by moderator Ed Cottrell. I wish to bring to your attention the following portion of that answer (emphasis added):

> ... the best solution is just go ahead and edit it yourself. In this
>   case, **the author of the post didn't mind your edit**, so this really
>   was the best solution.

I respectfully request that we leave it that, and drop the matter. And my apologies to KemyLand, since it has become abundantly clear to me that no harm was intended, and that KemyLand is a person of extraordinary character. I hope you will show the support and respect that KemyLand deserves.

---

What is the correct course of action when a user posts malicious code as a joke?

[Here's the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926150/3386109) that is the source of my concern. In the first version of the answer, the author provided a complete set of code that could be compiled and run. If any user was foolish enough to actually run the code, the code would attempt to wipe their hard drive.

I edited the answer to replace the malicious line of code with something harmless, and the author accepted that change. However, in the discussion that followed, it's clear that the author is unrepentant, and does not appreciate the gravity of the situation.

Having lost a hard drive to a mechanical failure, I can tell you that it is a catastrophic event to lose a hard drive that isn't fully backed up. So I feel that it's beyond irresponsible for the author to post that code. And I think the author of that post needs to be corrected.

What is my correct course of action at this point?

**Edit:** Based on Servy's answer and the discussion between Servy and Carpetsmoker, it seems that the question comes down to this: Is it useful to flag the post for moderator attention? Assuming that the flag is declined, does flagging provide useful information to the mods. Will a series of similar flags against a single user expose a pattern of behavior. Or will each flag be declined, and then forgotten?

Comment: Moderator flag...with details.

Comment: That's why _we hate fun_ on Stack Overflow :-P ...

Comment: I seriously would like not to have written that answer. It's right now getting hard-downvoted because of all this hassle, even given that the answer is valid, responds to the OP's question, and the harmful code has been removed. Of course, there are also delete posts as of now. Seriously, I'm not sure if the joke here was my `system("sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /")` line (wasn't intended as a joke, BTW), or all the bad reputation my answer gained...

Comment: @KemyLand Welcome to the [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/166789). On the upside, you'll probably also get more upvotes ;-) I wouldn't worry about a few downvotes.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I'm not worried about the downvotes, but rather all the internal (meta?) discussion this has triggered.

Comment: At this moment your answer has 4 upvotes and 3 down votes, so an overall positive score, and +34 reputation. So no harm done. We need to have this discussion to determine the proper etiquette when this sort of thing happens. (Or at least I need to have this discussion, so I know the proper etiquette.)

Comment: @KemyLand Your answer has attracted zero delete votes total (and zero since the meta question was posted).  Since this meta question was posted it has attracted 2 downvotes and 4 upvotes, for a net change of +2.

Comment: @KemyLand What's wrong with discussions?

Comment: @Servy: Well, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the stats!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I meant all the "negative"-class discussion it generated.

Comment: @KemyLand I don't know what you mean with that exactly? IMHO it's a constructive discussion about what sort of answers we (as a community) do and don't want, and how to best deal with a particular type of answer that we don't want. I don't really see any "negativity" here...

Comment: IMHO, it is easy to know when not to do something. Consider what would happen if everybody did it. What if everybody put "jokes" in their code snippets that wiped the whole drive? Would SO be a joke then? Yes.

Comment: Ah, so it wasn't a joke then? What was it then, an example of something malicious? This is like saying what to mix to make a bomb on a chemistry site. Even if you didn't intend anyone to mix those chemicals.

Comment: @doug65536: I did never intended that as a "joke", but rather just wrote some line of code to put inside the `NeverRunThis` function, and thought that `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` was a good example of something you should never run. Is it that hard to understand?

Comment: Related question on meta.apple: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/maliciously-wrong-answers-should-be-flag-worthy

Comment: When posting dangerous code, put zero width spaces at key points in the code, the error will confuse the new users so much, that the only way they can solve the problem is retyping it from scratch, hopefully quitting in the process for a easier code to copy that just works.

Comment: Downvote for suggestion of physical violence

Comment: There's all the difference in the world between "malicious" and "dangerous".

Comment: That line of code has nothing to do with the question or answer. Including such a line without context or explanatory warning seems malicious to me, even though OP probably thought it was funny.

Comment: Why are you convinced the author was being malicious?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287327/1394393

Comment: @KemyLand You still do not seem to understand the potential damage of you answer. *Is it that hard to understand?*

Comment: @edc65: Eh... sorry? I already iterated several times that it was not the best of my ideas, and if someone would have been dismissed enough, it would have been **really** harmful. Yet, I didn't intended so, neither did I intended for that to be a joke, but rather some sort of placeholder code. Please don't be that harsh/misleading if you don't understand/know the context in which you're talking.

Comment: I'm so confused about this. Unless someone is stupid enough to be signed-in as root (which systems support this now days?), and then compile&execute the code, the user would have to provide a password/signature for the `sudo` command anyway, which mean the answer is completely harmless for anyone who didn't override the default do-not-run-as-root settings. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KemyLand It got posted on [/r/programming](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4a6mrk/stackoverflow_goes_from_unfriendly_to_malicious/), where Stack Exchange will forever be the worst place ever, plus the person who posted it fabricated a story about you intentionally trying to destroy hard drives to punish amateurs, so any comments that get posted in the next day are probably not going to be very constructive

Comment: @doug65536 http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=explosive

Comment: @hobbs: I'm refering to its *social* effect. I mean, it's just disgusting for me to read the amount of insults and menaces to me found on that same subreddit... Then we have the fact that downvotes are being heavily overused incorrectly in this case.

Comment: @KemyLand IIRC the mass drive-by votes that happen when a post is linked in a major forum can be reversed. As for rude people... yeah, you get those on the internet. Sorry.

Comment: @KemyLand that post has been deleted. Another link might surface, but you're out of the line of fire for the moment. Be thankful it's the weekend.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Looks like the mods there deleted it, but it's still on /r/ProgrammerHumor for some reason.

Comment: @MichaelMyers The OP of the post [apologised for brigading](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4a6mrk/stackoverflow_goes_from_unfriendly_to_malicious/d0xx7j2) and [self-deleted](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4a6mrk/stackoverflow_goes_from_unfriendly_to_malicious/d0xxjzt) the post. If there's another post on /r/ProgrammerHumor, then that was likely posted by a different person. (And, as a different sub, /r/ProgrammerHumor would also have an entirely different team of moderators.)

Comment: @KemyLand Hey Kemmy - I'd just like you to know I don't you deserve the flak you're getting.  I'm even critical at times of the jerky culture of some people on S.O. but I'm more critical of people who copy and paste code and run it without understanding it.  Regardless, I think it's probably a good thing for Stack Overflow for your answer to have been censored as it has been.  I frequently make code that is jocular when giving some sort of example - and could see how one could think everyone already understands what "sudo rm \" does and hence knows not to run the code.

Comment: You think _wiping a harddisk_ is severe? Well, I reckon Haskell is the only language with [a `launchMissiles` function, which is specified to cause “serious international side-effects”](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles/docs/Acme-Missiles.html#v:launchMissiles)...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The proof is there! I knew Haskell **is** the most powerful language out there... in both practical and politically incorrect terms.

Comment: I don't get what the big deal is. I'm running the original code right now, and everything į̥͈͍̩͡s̵̬ ̵̵̝̤̘͉̟̭͇j̮̝̬͔̪̟͓͍́u̶͉̮͚͔̰̬͔͇̤s͏̤͟t͙̲̲͕͝͝ ͚̪̟̳̱̬f̷̮i̜͔͍̲̖͇̝̳n̷҉͈̳̣̻ͅ  ..9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with dangerous answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276496/how-to-deal-with-dangerous-answers)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

## The Problem

I agree with you that this is a problem. People *shouldn't* copy and run code they don't understand from Stack Overflow. People *actually do it* every day. And even when people do understand it and intend to edit it before using it, it's all too easy to copy, paste, get distracted, hit compile, go get a cup of coffee, and come back to find a freshly-nuked hard drive.

## Some Philosophical Musings

When possible, we'd rather protect people from their own ignorance and carelessness just a little bit if it doesn't destroy the point of a post.

That does *not* mean the poster who posted that code was necessarily being malicious. In fact, it's pretty clearly *not* malicious, just ill-advised. It even includes some warnings, though they are not as obvious as one might like. So, we don't need to "slap" anyone, but it's worth a few seconds to protect the hapless from themselves.

## How to Handle It

You have a few options:

- The best option: edit it, preferably by simply commenting out the offending code and replacing it with something not actually dangerous, like `doHorriblyDangerousThingHere()` (or `recursivelyDeleteRootAsTheSuperuserOrSomethingOfTheLike()`, as in the actual post). You can also always add a warning, like this:

  ## DANGER: WILL NUKE YOUR HARD DRIVE (and may even [brick your system](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/16/02/01/1357237))
- Raise a custom moderator flag and make very clear what you're concerned about. "This is dangerous code" won't cut it. Tell us *what* is dangerous, so we don't have to wade through it all looking for issues.

If you flag it, we moderators will most likely end up deleting the post altogether (and losing valuable content), declining the flag because we don't know what you're worried about, or editing it ourselves. This takes moderator time and, more importantly, is slow. The flag queue routinely has 2,000 items in it, and there's no magic filter to make "really dangerous code" pop to the top. As a result, if you flag it, the bad code might linger for hours (or worse) before anyone deals with it.

So, really, the best solution is just go ahead and edit it yourself. In this case, the author of the post didn't mind your edit, so this really was the best solution.

## How to Handle *Actually* Malicious Behavior

If you do, in the future, see someone engaging in a pattern of malicious behavior, such as posting links to malware-infested sites "for more information" or actually inviting people to run clearly malicious code, raise a custom flag. Mods have a few abilities and tools to help us investigate and resolve such problems more effectively than normal users, so a custom flag is totally appropriate in that context.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer. And you make a good point about how to write the custom flag. One of the reasons I didn't flag was I wasn't sure how to properly communicate the problem.

Comment: What if code that you lazily copy and paste without understanding contains a mistake? And that bug costs your company a million dollars? Will you try to pass responsibility to StackOverflow, or the person who posted the answer?  The one who hit "Ctrl-V", compile and run is responsible.

Comment: @Kaz If someone does that, the responsibility is on the user who actually used (copied and pasted) the code. I'm not saying that SO bears the blame for someone who does something very stupid and hurts themselves. I'm just saying we -- as nice and helpful people, not out of some legal or other responsibilty -- ought to try to make it a little harder for that to happen if we notice bad code, just like we would improve any other posts.

Comment: If I was a moderator, and this being SO, "this is dangerous code" would probably make me suspect they left a variable as non-`const`, or they aliased pointers of different types, or they didn't religiously check every pointer for NULLness.

Comment: @immibis Exactly. We see a lot of nonsensical flags, and even more that may or may not be correct but are not at all obvious. If it's not fairly obvious why you flagged something, you need a custom flag.

Comment: @immibis All inside a `void main` program that dared to close a non-empty text output stream without making the last character a newline.

Comment: @EdCottrell, I don't see any sense putting a warning like **DANGER: WILL NUKE YOUR HARD DRIVE**. Many people who visit SO, just copy paste the code without caring about warnings and reading the explanation. I agree this might reduce the people who will copy paste the malicious code, but this will still not stop everyone. One of a good colleague to whom I taught C, used to always copy paste code from websites like SO, if he found a solution to a problem he was facing. I told him not to do that (not because of the malicious purpose). But this is still dangerous as some person might still copy it

Comment: Also, posting malicious code is dangerous. But a person (not a member) when seeing the code and figuring out that it is malicious, might think that the author does not know much about the topic, and just copy-pasted malicious code from somewhere. But when you put a warning telling that it is malicious, more articles like [this](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.z8y2densg) and [this](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/) criticizing SO will come. They will also say that SO posts malicious code and say it is malicious.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ As I said, that's usually not the best solution. Sometimes, though, the question is about doing something inherently dangerous, and the dangerous code is essential to the answer. Not in the example at issue here, no, but in other questions, a warning might be better than removing some essential piece of an answer.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ if someone copies and pastes code with a big warning that says: **DANGER: WILL NUKE YOUR HARD DRIVE** and actually executes it... that's natural selection :-) I understand one may not be able to understand something like `sudo rm --no-preserve-root -rf /` and may want to run that code to see what it does... a warning would be fine, IMO. Or are we going to ban the "malicious" options in the `rm` manual just in case someone copies and pastes from there?

Comment: I think the user who posted that answer has to have a punishment. Their reputation is over 3,000 which automatically would make any new programmer trust them. For people who say the guy who asked the question shouldn't copy and paste, well funnily enough what do you do when you first start reading how to program books? You just copy everything word for word, the same thing would be done online. Yes, new programmers shouldn't copy and paste absolutely everything but if they do they'll eventually have to figure out that they'll have to change their code to fit their scenario.

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 that's not really how things work around here. We don't punish people for posting code that is broken, wrong, or even dangerous. We will take necessary steps to protect the community from maliciousness, but there's no real evidence of malice here, just a very poorly-thought-out answer.

Answer (score 26):

Downvote the post, because it's not helpful, and vote to delete it.  You have the ability to vote to delete answers; use it.

You can also comment, to explain to the author, and other readers, what the problem is.

That said, reading the post and the comments it's quite clear that your assertion that this answer is in any way malicious, trolling, or anything other than a serious, genuine answer, is just false.  You might think that it's harmful, and you're free to vote accordingly, but it's quite clear to me that there is no malice here.  The answer provided some harmful code as an example of harmful code, that shouldn't' be run.  It's there to prove a valid and relevant point, not to troll people.  Editing it to accomplish that same goal without potentially harming people running random code snippets without reading them is a fine edit to make, and clearly the author didn't have a problem with that edit, so if anything, I'd say you're the one being out of line here.

Comment: I think my ability to delete carries a two day delay at this point :(

Comment: Except that the question has nothing to do with that line of code. The question asks about using the preprocessor to avoid name-space conflicts, and the answer is an example of how to create such a function. The body of the function is totally irrelevant to the question/answer. And yet the author of the answer felt it would be amusing to add a command to erase the user's hard-drive there. That wouldn't be so bad, except that the code is fully formed, ready to compile and run.

Comment: IMHO putting a `system("sudo rm --no-preserve-root -rf /");` in example code (like in this case) is perhaps not "malicious" or "trolling" especially is the answer if useful,  but it's most definitely harmful and something we *don't* want. Editing it out (as @user3386109 did) and flagging it with a custom flag (so it goes on the user's "record") would definitely be appropriate here. What other "fun" gotchas does this person's other answers have?

Comment: @user3386109 Which is why editing it to something edit is appropriate; you can accomplish what the answers is trying to convey without posting that code, so that edit improves the answer, without meaningfully changing the author's intent.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm glad you agree with everything that I've said in my answer, with the exception of the fact that flagging is pointless, you can fix the problem yourself (and he did), there is no need for a mod; they will have nothing to do.

Comment: @Servy But what if (for example) 25 other answers of this user do the same thing? If individual users keep editing it out, no one will ever see the "pattern". Having a flag on the user's profile won't warrant action the first time, or the second time, but the third or fourth time, a mod might send a message that this is not acceptable...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Like I said, there is no indication of malice here.  If there were indications that the author was going out of his way to actively try to cause harm to readers then *that* would merit  flag, because that's something a mod could actually act on.  But a user posting an answer that you think is harmful, with no malice shown, is simply not something for a mod to do anything about.

Comment: @Servy  So if I call people a shithead as a joke but not out of malice then that's okay?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That'd pretty clearly fall under the "rude or offensive" flag reason.  It would apply even if there wasn't malicious intent there.  It actually comes up a lot in chat, where certain rooms, as a culture, feel that language like that (and much worse) is appropriate; there is no malice to the target of the language intended, but the behavior is still considered rude and offensive despite the lack of malice.

Comment: I agree, but why would this be different? A joke that causes harm still ... causes harm. The motive doesn't change that. I'm not advocating that a mod *should* immediately act on this, merely that this be recorded on this user's profile so that a consistent pattern of "harmful jokes" (or other dubious behaviour) can be seen if there is any. As far as I know, a flag is the best way to record such information.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Note the distinct lack of a flag reason for, "answer that causes harm".  Like I said, a mod is going to have noting to do in response to that flag except ignore it.  A user posting an answer with entirely sincere intentions, but inadvertently posting something that others feel is harmful is not something that merits moderation action.  Also note that this isn't a joke.  It's not trying to be humorous; it's using the code as an example of harmful code to prove a point, not to be funny.  That's not dubious behavior, it's simply poor execution of a good idea.

Comment: "Proving a point" by erasing the user's hard drive is like "proving a point" by stealing my bike when I forget to lock it. And again, I am *not* advocating action here. Not actually acting on a flag yet marking it "helpful" is not uncommon AFAIK. And the lack of a pre-existing flag reason is not a very strong argument. There are dozens, of not hundreds, of valid reasons that could be put in the flag dialog. Instead, the sane thing is done: provide a textarea.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Did you read the answer?  Clearly that was neither the goal of the answer, nor how it was trying to prove its point.  Describing a bad situation as an example of something bad happening is *radically* different from doing a really bad thing to prove the same point.  He isn't going up to someone's machine when they left it unattended and wiping it to show them not to leave it unattended.  He's *describing* such a situation.  Someone taking, and executing, code that someone is providing *as an example of what not to do* is pretty clearly not the goal; the point is the opposite.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Like I said.  The post doesn't merit flagging.  If you think an answer harmful, the appropriate course of action is to downvote it, or in some circumstances (which this post meets) edit it.  When you flag a post for something when *you're entirely capable of fixing that problem yourself*, and especially if you have *already* handled the situation yourself, is not appropriate.  The mod is just going to decline the flag; that is the correct response for them, so telling people to cast flags that a mod is just going to decline is just wasing people's time.

Comment: @ Servy and @Carpetsmoker Thank-you for these comments. This is exactly the discussion I was looking for.  It seems then that the whole question comes down to whether it's useful to flag. I was initially going to flag, but figured it would just be declined. I'm not sure whether a series of declined flags will be useful to the mods (for the purpose of detecting a pattern of behavior). So I've updated the question to ask that directly.

Comment: I found that the "harmful" code in @kemy's answer just distracted from the preprocessor issue.  It caught my attention, and I was left wondering why it was there.  I eventually realized it was just an example function, and not actually relevant.  A trivial function like `return 42;` would have been better, since it wouldn't have warranted all the clutter of those warning `printf`s.  I don't think there's any reason to use "dangerous" example code for no reason. Even in questions messing with hard drives, I write `dd ... of=/dev/sdX2 ...`, rather than `of=/dev/sda2`, so a copy/paste is harmless

Comment: this is an incomprehensibly long discussion of basically *a trivial social interaction gone slightly bad*.  As I humorously put it in my superb answer below, it's a case of "Meta is not the headmaster's office" or perhaps that old classic "geez get a life guys".

Comment: Someone lost their hard drive because someone else left a loaded weapon out to make a point.  Commence the "but it isn't the bad actor's fault that they left unnecessarily dangerous things in a place where it was possible to accidentally use them" discussion.  With that, watch StackOverflow cease to be a safe place.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland Did you see me say that the post should just be left the way that it was, or that it wasn't in any way problematic?  If you see a loaded weapon out, put it away, don't shoot the person that left it out to punish him.

Comment: @Servy: "*If you see a loaded weapon out, put it away, don't shoot the person that left it out to punish him.*" Shooting such a person would be extreme, yes. But doing nothing more than putting it away isn't a good idea either. I would say that *some* form of punishment should be in order. It wasn't an accident, after all. The user deliberately choose to include a line that could be dangerous. It may not have been intended to be harmless, but we have the concept of "negligence" specifically for cases when you do something that you didn't mean to harm someone but could reasonably lead to it.

Comment: @NicolBolas And presumably you're well aware that there are rather high standards for what negligence is.  There would need to actually be harm shown, an expectation that the perpetrator should have reasonably expected the harm to come from their actions, etc.  And then of course there's the fact that SO has nothing in their rules about it.  You've got a *lot* of things that you'd need to make happen first.

Answer (score -7):

How we treat this answer has less to do with whether this answer was  malicious on its own and more to do with what actions we deem as acceptable for the community. It's important with issues like this to define clear lines over what we allow and *only then* judge incidents on their relative merits, else we end up underplaying the importance of or legitimizing actions based on circumstances specific to a given case.

It should be clear that this is not an acceptable action. Writing dangerous code without extremely clear warning labels damages the community, and by extension those within it, in the same way unwanted language or hostile behaviour would. I think the community has the moral responsibility to make that clear on the *first* occurrence, in order to make it clear where those lines lay. Anyone who takes actions like this needs to be told outright and with no ambiguity that they have broken our rules of conduct.

That this action was taken without the author being aware of its hostility means this is more than a simple accident. Rather, it means we haven't made these lines clear enough that the fact this is a policy violation is obvious to *everyone* posting answers.

By now, it's clear that this incident was a simple mistake. But I do feel disappointed that the responses to this question made many people visiting it feel that Stack Overflow didn't care. By the time the question was asked, the code was already removed, so the focus should have been not on excusing this case in isolation and more on the question actually asked:

> What is the correct course of action when a user posts malicious code as a joke?

I don't see how any answer other than "edit and flag" is possibly correct.

Comment: Are you certain the intent here was to punish copy-pasters? The answerer also stated here: """I did never intended that as a "joke", but rather just wrote some line of code to put inside the NeverRunThis function, and thought that `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` was a good example of something you should never run. Is it that hard to understand?""" Also, this doesn't even seem like the type of code you'd expect to be copy-pasted. It wasn't a solution to a "what code can I use to do this type problem".

Comment: @Ajedi32 "Are you certain the intent here was to punish copy-pasters?" → I don't think it was. But laughing about it as an unintended side-effect shows malintent. And, FWIW, I don't think malintent is needed. Imagine the author used a racial slur without intending it to be directed at anyone. That the slur wasn't intended to insult doesn't mean it's wrong to flag it.

Comment: True, there is perhaps a larger discussion to be had here about the cynical attitude the SO community tends to have towards newer users, but I think in this particular case the situation was handled appropriately.

Comment: "Imagine the author used a racial slur"  You've got to be kidding me.  That situation is nothing at all like the situation we're discussing.

Comment: @MichaelShaw The situations are inequivalent, but I don't think a comparison is unfair. In both cases I'm talking about actions which are intrinsically hostile and potentially very damaging. They're damaging in entirely different ways, but both are very valid causes for concern.

Comment: @Veedrac Do you know what the word hostile means?  Posting an answer that you don't like isn't a hostile act.  The SO post was *potentially* damaging, but not hostile.  Of course, you could say the same thing of any answer with a SQL injection vulnerability in it, or answers with any number of other possible serious flaws.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I know what "hostile" means. Mars is hostile to life even though there's no martian overlord *intending* it to be hostile. The answer is hostile to the Stack Overflow community in an analogous manner.

Comment: @Veedrac: Mars is an inanimate object, not a person.  If we say Mars is hostile, the feelings of Mars are not going to be hurt, and nobody will worry about whether we're being too rude and mean to Mars.  If we say that a specific SO user is doing something so hostile it needs to be compared to *racial slurs* when all they're trying to do is answer a question on SO, maybe we ought to stop and think about how mean we're being to that real person.

Comment: @MichaelShaw If that someone has done something that could, in the extreme, pretty much ruin someone's life, they need to be told it. The offense someone might take to *their action* being called "intrinsically hostile" is miniscule in comparison.

Comment: @MichaelShaw And, FWIW, I don't think that an *inadvertent* racial slur is the pinnacle of evil, like some of you seem to be implying. Ignorance of our cultural norms doesn't make someone bad, it just means they've taken damaging actions unknowingly. Ergo why it's important to be able to distinguish the damage of an action from the malintent of a person.

Comment: "pretty much ruin someone's life" You've got to be kidding me.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Eh, it's not that much of a leap. A studying CS student wipes their year-long project and fails their course in response. Not forever-doomed kind'a ruin, but it could certainly change it for the worse. Alternatively it could get someone fired at a difficult time in their life.

Comment: Downvoted for comparing a legit, working code snippet (albeit a potentially dangerous one) to racial slurs.  That's like comparing apples and...well...racial slurs.  Quite a bit overboard and just a touch offensive.

Comment: @Kalmino No, it's like comparing possibly wiping someone's hard drive to inadvertent racial slurs. That you think possibly wiping someone's hard drive is at all akin to an apple is the absurdity here.

Comment: "A studying CS student wipes their year-long project and fails their course in response."  There are 4 separate ridiculous leaps here.  First, the leap from a CS student wiping their hard drive to losing their code, in the era of the internet and source code control.  Second, the leap from losing their code to failing a single CS course, when either hard work or getting an extension or an incomplete from their professor would likely prevent it.  Third, the leap from failing a single CS class to being unable to complete a CS degree.

Comment: ... Fourth, the leap from being unable to complete a CS degree to a ruined life.

Comment: @MichaelShaw Leap #1 is not unreasonable. CS students especially aren't all adept in the ways of source control. Leaps #2 and #3 are also not unreasonable; maybe it's an American vs British uni experience but you could very easily fail the course I took by losing 25% of your grade (which, in my case, you would). Leap #4 smacks of apologism and I don't even care to respond to it.

Comment: In my experience, professors are likely to introduce students to things like source control, internet sites like github, the capabilities of the local CS network, and the basic idea of backing up your work.  Your attempted debunking of points #2 and #3 only addresses #2, and not very well.  You completely ignore the possibility of the professor granting an extension or allowing the student to get an incomplete grade, finishing the work later.  Your claim that my point #4 "smacks of apologism" is just empty verbiage.

Comment: @MichaelShaw My university barely covered source control, basically never allow for extensions on the 3rd year project and, being a British university, the "failing a single CS class" idea just doesn't apply. And, yes, I do think "oh, making someone fail university isn't ruining their *entire* life" is needless apologism, and if you think I need to justify that we're probably never going to see eye-to-eye. The possibility of some people weaselling out of disaster doesn't make it OK.

Comment: "My university barely covered source control" Barely covering something does actually introduce that idea.  "basically never allow for extensions on the 3rd year project" So basically, you aren't discussing just any CS student taking any class, you're specifically discussing a British CS student who is working on their 3rd year project, and it must be so far along in the year that losing their current work will render them incapable of completing the project.  You're also specifically talking about such a late-in-the-3rd-year British CS student who decided not to back up their work at all.

Comment: "needless apologism, and if you think I need to justify that" You do need to justify that, as being unable to complete a degree simply does not ruin someone's life.  That you are unable to defend this idea beyond throwing around the vague, archaic word "apologism" is telling.

Comment: @MichaelShaw These comments are far too short and clumsy to run you through the foundations of ethics I'd need to teach you for you to come to the realization that derailing someone's life is not an ethical act, so I'm not going to argue this further.

Comment: You've missed the point rather spectacularly.  I never said anything about derailing somebody's life being ethical.  I just called out your inability to argue your point and your crazy leaps of logic, including the silly idea that the post in question could possibly have derailed somebody's life.

Comment: @MichaelShaw That I'm struggling to express my argument to you is a fault of the brevity these comments, not a lack of thought. I'm relying on the reader to flesh back out the elided arguments.

Comment: I'll leave one last clarification before abandoning this argument. My argument is about the existence that this could, "*in the extreme*, pretty much ruin someone's life". Not an argument that this *will certainly* do so. Ergo I'm making an existential argument, and your claims that *one* of my examples of such a circumstance was restricted to universities unlike your own doesn't invalidate that, unless you can show that *all* universities are in fact like your own. Which they are not, given the existence of mine.

Comment: Note: That we're arguing about what this could do "*in the extreme*" does not mean my point here relies upon it. The ability for it to waste a day of someone's time to reinstall from a daily backup would more than suffice my attitude towards it.

Comment: Now that you've actually completed your argument, I can address it.  Imagine a scenario where a child accidentally bumps into another child, and immediately says "I'm sorry".  Should we freak out and arrest the kid for assault with a deadly weapon?  After all, it's possible, though unlikely, that the other kid could have lost their balance.  And then fallen if they didn't regain their balance.  And then hit their head in the unlikely event that they don't put their hands up in time.  And if they hit their head on a particularly unfortunately placed rock, they could die, although probably not.

Comment: @MichaelShaw My argument is in no sense complete, as I have tried to express. Clearly I'm not making an existential claim in the mathematical sense (else I'd be talking about butterflies and hurricanes). Your analogy isn't as clear-cut as you made it sound; schools often ban running in corridors for exactly this reason, and people slow down around the elderly. On the internet you don't know how many people of what demographic are around, so it's better to take the cautious stance. And nobody's talking about arresting the OP, just telling him sternly to stick to walking.

Comment: You've claimed that the author of the answer had done something equivalent to racist comments, possibly ruining someone's life.  You called it a "grave error in judgement" and you claim the answerer was malicious and hostile.  You speak about "malintent" and talk about how disgusted you are.  In reality, the answerer just answered a question helpfully.  In your answer, you remind people to "be nice".  I wish you would take your own advice.

Comment: @MichaelShaw I never said the act was equivalent to racist comments. In fact, I clearly said they were inequivalent. Saying the act could potentially ruin someone's life is no more mean than telling people to use hand sanitizer at a talk. My disgust was about them laughing at the idea of someone wiping their hard drive, a disgust no more unjust than the disgust I have at people who think it's funny to tease other people. My idea of being nice does not involve ignoring the act to avoid offending the bully (even if in this case the bullying was unintentional).

Comment: @MichaelShaw And since you keep bringing up the point of racial slurs, perhaps I should clarify what context an *inadvertent* racial slur might appear in. As one hypothetical, let's say someone comes from a culture that's reappropriated a given racial slur, and happens to use that in their post, unaware of the problems of using that kind of language on this forum. I struggle to see how this either represents a grave personal flaw of the user nor how its temporary appearance on this site causes anything beyond temporary upset. [...]

Comment: All I ask is that we, as a community, make it clear that this kind of language is damaging and not appropriate for the site. A similar post to meta about *that* would not have answers that try to downplay the contents of the post or excuse the action of the poster, but that doesn't mean one has to end up witch-hunting that person either.

Comment: You've repeatedly backed away from what you said about racial slurs in the OP in the comments.  However, in the OP, your original verbiage stands, and you don't talk about understandable errors or inadvertent accidents.  The original verbiage looks like an indirect attempt to smear this innocent guy as equivalent to a racist.

Comment: You keep saying that you think it's disgusting that people were making jokes, but I don't see why.  It's not like anyone was actually harmed; they're joking about a hypothetical situation.  On the other hand, the answerer actually was distressed about the extreme and unwarranted nastiness shown to him on some parts of the internet.

Comment: @MichaelShaw What claims about racial slurs have I backed away from? The very second comment on this post (which is my first comment on this post) clearly says "Imagine the author used a racial slur without intending it to be directed at anyone." Arguing I've been saying anything else is a straw-man.

Comment: @MichaelShaw It would be a fine joke about a hypothetical situation if the malicious code was a hypothetical situation. It's like laughing about having driven drunk just because you managed not to hit anyone. (Though, since you like taking my word literally, I'm not actually saying this is close to as bad as drunk driving, which deserves jail time.)

Comment: You say "without  intending it to be directed at anyone" in the comments.  You say "let's say someone comes from a culture that's reappropriated a given racial slur, and happens to use that in their post, unaware of the problems of using that kind of language on this forum" in the comments.  But in the OP you say nothing of the kind.

Comment: Calling the code malicious is wrong.  Clearly it has no malintent.  Clearly it wasn't meant to be run, by anyone, ever.  This was a *subtle* mistake, easily missed.  Drunk driving is something everyone knows is wrong, illegal, and extremely dangerous.

Comment: @MichaelShaw My post talks about how we as a community should act towards these things in posts; my point is that this action should be against our code of conduct. The intent of the author of the respective violations is an orthogonal issue. *Ceteris paribus*, as they say. If one was to talk about *intended* racial slurs, the analogy would be to *intended* wiping of drives, which is not what I was claiming.

Comment: @MichaelShaw It's a fair point that my original post was perhaps unclear on this matter, but it's not like I didn't repeatedly emphasise my intention with the analogy.

Comment: The offending code was not hypothetical, but the possibility of damage actually occurring because of it is hypothetical. The code was up for 4 minutes before being edited out.  The code wouldn't have worked on a non-unix system.  The answer was about something that a complete noob wouldn't have been interested in seeing, and a non-noob would have seen the danger of running it.  If the code hadn't been edited out after 4 minutes and had instead stayed up forever, it is still extremely unlikely that anyone would have been harmed by it ever.

Comment: @MichaelShaw And fine, not malicious. Dangerous, then. Whether that one specific adjective (that I've described it as *only once*, by the way) is valid in this circumstance is an irrelevant matter of semantics.

Comment: @MichaelShaw The 4 minutes aspect does change things, FWIW, but I wasn't aware of that until you mentioned it just now.

Comment: Your OP uses rather harsh and intolerant language which is not warranted for this situation or any situation involving an honest mistake.  It's not reasonable to call an honest mistake "against our code of conduct".  In your OP, you don't treat the answerer as a guy who made an honest mistake and just needs to be alerted to the existence of his error.

Comment: Honestly, a lot of the ideas you've expressed in the comments are basically reasonable.  The way things are expressed in the OP is what bothers me.

Comment: @MichaelShaw I suppose that means my post needs rewriting then. I no longer even agree with my quoting his comments, to be honest, since it didn't end up being representative.

Comment: @MichaelShaw I've edited it. How about now?

Comment: I've removed my downvote.  I still don't agree with it enough to upvote, but I do consider it much improved.