# Fixing answers that recommend "chmod 777"

Tags: discussion, answers, security

After stumbling upon both a question which mentioned "I did `chmod 777`"<sup>1</sup> and an answer which recommended "do `chmod 777`" yesterday I did a basic search and found quite a few answers which recommend this practice—some with a disturbing amount of upvotes.

This is especially dangerous since many of these answers revolve around web development, and recommendations such as "you need to run `chmod -R 777 /var/www/wordpress` are not uncommon. I've had to clean up after an unwise chmod more than once, both through Stack Overflow answers, as well as outside of that.

Therefore I tried to fix this at least a little bit by leaving a comment on those answers. I felt that an edit would be inappropriate as it would change the meaning of the post too much (you can't always just change this to `chmod 755`; usually the solution is to set the `user` and/or `group`, depending on the OP's situation/problem). In addition, a comment would hopefully be seen by the author of the answer, who would hopefully be educated by it.

This is the sort of comment  that *should* have been created when the answer was first posted, but for whatever reason wasn't.

Adding these comments was, apparently, not appreciated by at least some moderators. To quote:

> You did just carpet-bomb *[pun intended? probably not]* our site with 154 comments in a very short amount of time. Please don't do that. If there is a wider technological issue like this, bring it to Meta first, so the community can help figure out a response.

And subsequently, these comments were deleted.<sup>2</sup>

Yes, 154 are quite a few comments. But Stack Overflow has a whopping 18.3 *million* answers, so on that scale, it's really not that much. And if a comment pointing out a mistake on *one* answers is appropriate, then why not on 154 answers with the same mistake?

Without going into too much detail on my feelings about having >2 hours of what I see as constructive and meaningful, yet boring and thankless, work undone at the press of a button, I am bringing this to meta as suggested: **what should we do about this?**

- Leaving it be doesn't strike me as a very appealing option.

  - This sort of stuff is *a lot* more dangerous than, for example, the "malicious sudo rm -rf" on which there are currently two meta questions and a reddit thread. Instead of clobbering all your files, it's much more insidious and the consequences may go undetected for weeks, months, and even *years*.
  - It doesn't just harm whoever runs it; compromised machines send out spam, malware, etc. and may (and have!) cause data leaks.
  - In some scenarios it may *indeed* clobber a significant part of your files; an unwise `rm -rf` or *malicious* `rm -rf` by another user will now remove those files.
  - People read these Stack Overflow answers every day; even old ones. I see them being referenced in Stack Overflow questions mentioning "I did chmod 777 as recommended here".
  - The good folks at Server Fault have a more comprehensive list of why this is bad: [Why is “chmod -R 777 /” destructive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive) (many of these issues also apply to `chmod 777` in general, and not just `/`).
- Editing also doesn't strike me as the best option, as it changes too much from the original intent, and doesn't (try to) educate the author about the mistake, but it's an option.
- Adding a new answer doesn't "fix" anything. The answers will still be there. Upvoted. Accepted. Above my "good one". It will also not inform the author of the answer that they did something pretty silly.
- Leaving a comment still strikes me as the best option, for the reasons outlined above: it doesn't change the meaning, it (tries to) educate the author, and it warns visitors.  I should point out, that in the short time that the comments were there, a few of the authors replied with "Oops, sorry, I'll go fix it!" so they **did** have effect and *were* useful!

---

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> For those not familiar with Unix-y systems, this will give full read *and* write permissions to *everyone* on the system. A very bad idea. To be clear, there is practically never a reason to do this. Things like the `/tmp` directory are an exception, and even then you need to make sure you set the sticky bit to make it secure. In fact, `/tmp` and similar directories *in combination* with the sticky bit is the *only* valid use case I can think of; although I'm sure someone will point out another exceedingly rare use case in the comments soon.

---

<sup>2</sup> To provide a brief clarification to @Shog9's response to this in his answer:

> You obviously didn't read any of the answers you were commenting on, as evidenced by this same cookie-cutter comment left on answers that already urged readers not to use `chmod 777`

Which is not true. I *did* read all of those answers, and probably *skipped* more than commented on. Although it's entirely possible I misunderstood a few (it's not possible for me to go back and check since it's deleted).

I don't want to go on about these comments though − that's not really why posted this thread − what's done is done and move on. But Shog9's answer is, unfortunately, rather wrong on this...

Comment: Those moderators and their puns!

Comment: You of course cannot "fix" such an answer without radically changing its intention.  And "don't do that" is pretty useless if you don't give a better alternative.  Properly stopping programmers from doing stoopid stuff is work, it cannot be dusted off with a bunch of comments.  If you have time to post 154 comments then you also have time to post one good answer, that's how we do it here.

Comment: @HansPassant "One good answer" is not a fix. The answers will still be there. Upvoted. Accepted. Above my "good one". It will also not inform the author of the answer that they did something really silly. In addition, I should point out, that in the short time that the comments were there, a few people replied with "Oops, sorry, I'll go fix it!" so they **did** have effect!

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293930/792066

Comment: Comments are fungible, and not all comments can be visible at first. Let the moderators/high-rep users edit the answers and put a prominent caveat at the top of the post. This is a security issue, and SO shouldn't be seen as a supplier of **bad advice** (TM).

Comment: I guess the moral is 'do a few each day for lots of days', rather than 154 all at once.  I don't think this was a good moderation decision…but I'm not a moderator, so I don't know which rules were broken that warranted bulk undo.  It seems counter-productive to remove improvements to the site.

Comment: Have you tried changing permissions to the answers so that they're writeable by everyone?

Comment: What's so bad about 154 comments? If necessary they can be spread a bit over time. I surely wrote at least a thousand comments here and the number is still increasing.

Comment: @Trilarion It's probably flagged automatically by the system as suspicious. The site monitors this stuff to guard against malicious behavior or misguided unilateral efforts. Think serial voting. Serial downvoting as a malicious revenge action, serial upvoting as a misguided way of trying to reward a user. There's a certain parallel.

Comment: Just unilaterally dumping the same comment on over 150 answers is a bad idea. No matter how good your intentions are. At 25 comments you should've already started to think there must be a better way to deal with the issue. I can completely understand the removal. No-one ever reads comments, least of all users looking for a copy-paste solution.

Comment: @Cerbrus The answerers get a comment notification and absolutely DO read them. The idea was for the authors to fix their answers, not only as a warning to readers.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker How is the “executable” part not relevant here? Do you really want your static web pages and potentially even uploaded user-content to be executable?

Comment: @5gon12eder `php h4xx0r.php`. And in this context it mostly relates to setting it on a directory tree. I don't see any real need to mention it and make this and *even longer* post...

Comment: @NewWorld: I don't think every single answerer reads a comment like that on a X-year-old post. Even if he does, who's to say he'll actually edit the post? And even if a quarter of the posts get edited, there's still 75% left with the "bad" code, which is still a significant majority.

Comment: @Cerbrus So the situation got at least 25% better. And what harm did it do? None as far as I can see...

Comment: That's a very optimistic point of view. The way I look at it, the minority that _did_ edit the answers is just too small to make a dent.

Comment: In my opinion it's redundant. Aren't those boards for professionals? You cannot provide an obvious explanation for every answer you give, especially when someone asks to solve his homework for him (and it happens a lot). It shouldn't be needed to state security warnings when someone uses chmod 777 or his code can be exploited by injections. Also in my opinion chmod 777 is as good to troubleshoot potential problems as any other idea, that's what I would start with, of course you don't leave it like that after. People should RTFM before posting here and we will be ok.

Comment: @vove: even as a trouble-shooting measure, `chmod 777` is downright dangerous.  No, it is not good advice ever.  It may be convenient, but it isn't good.  And people here are not all experienced enough to recognize that there is danger.

Comment: Even professionals were clueless n00bs once.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler with all due respect but people should read linux for dummies or stop working on an operating system without having any clue what they are doing. It's the same thing with windows os, most users are working under admin account. You want to add that as a notice to every answer as well? No, it's obvious you shouldn't do that. I am seeing here American tendency to put useless warnings everywhere (i.e. "watch out, your hot coffee might be hot"). Seriously.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Not everyone starts out blindly copy-pasting code. Quite a few programmers do _proper_ research in order to fix a bug. Why should we lower our standards to accommodate laziness?

Comment: @Cerbrus How exactly does not giving out incredibly bad and irresponsible advice lead to a lowering to standards?

Comment: @vove: With all due respect, that is not reasonable.  People coming to SO are often working in unfamiliar territory, trying to resolve a problem outside their regular knowledge domains, in a hurry, under stress, without time to read or access to 'Linux for Dummies'.  Having bad advice on the site is not sensible.

Comment: @biziclop: Demanding a warning for every single potentially harmful piece of code that shouldn't be copy-pasted. Enabling low quality answers like that. That's lowering standards. Tolerating laziness, that's lowering standards.

Comment: @vove You say "RTFM", but I've seen many installation manuals recommending `chmod 777` (I used to collect examples on rwxrwxrwx.net until I got bored of it). Yeah, usually crappy PHP crap (the usual...), but people read it and it sticks. And while we can't fix all of the world, we can fix our tiny corner, at least a little bit. A small improvement is sill ... an improvement...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Are those actual manuals? Or blogs by some PHP "expert"?

Comment: @Cerbrus Nope. Actual installation manuals. Not php-noobz-blog.com

Comment: @Cerbrus That seems like a straw man argument seeing as no-one has demanded a warning for every single potentially harmful piece of code. Just flagging up incredibly bad but nevertheless popular advice as incredibly bad.

Comment: @biziclop: So, where do we stop? at 777? At `eval`? at deprecated `mysql` functions?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: So then the issue isn't with SO. It's the php community as a whole (or a large part of it, at least).

Comment: @Cerbrus When the advice stops being incredibly bad? Danger is a red herring here, all powerful tools are inherently dangerous. But some advice is just plain bad, and needs to be flagged up as such.

Comment: @Cerbrus And I agree that not "every single potentially harmful piece of code" should have a warning; I narrowed this down to a very specific *particular* example which, regardless of context, is *always* harmful. As I stated in the comments on one of the answers, I have no interest in hunting down every unwise `eval()` call or unescaped HTML or whatnot. This is really unrelated to what we're discussing here...

Comment: Guys, ___my point is___: This is something SO can't fix. Edit / comment _when you see it_. Just don't go searching for it, 'cause you'll be wasting your time editing it all.

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right, there is definitely no automated, technological solution to this. But it's still worth discussing the techniques of dealing with it. Having a standard warning template you can manually(!) stick on answers advocating certain bad habits is not inherently a bad idea.

Comment: @Cerbrus On whether it's a waste of time, I think we will have to agree to disagree. However, it is *my* time to waste, and so far, no one has put forth a good argument how this would make matters *worse* ...

Comment: And the purpose of this exercise (as far as I can tell) is not to stop people **following** stupid advice blindly, that would be a Sisyphean task. But if at least a few people **spreading** bad advice (unwittingly and in good faith) can be educated, that seems like a worthwhile endeavour.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Edits on _old_ dead questions with outdated could lead to those getting new visitors, who'd have been better off finding a newer Q/A. (I had to dig deep for that one). I can agree it isn't necessarily _bad_. I just don't see the benefit of spending that much time on it.

Comment: Ok, you win. Let's change stackoverflow into bring your homework here and we gonna solve it. Sometimes people post here code with more holes in it than a mosquito net. Instead of answering the question, boards will become dummy training grounds. Don't you see what's happening with that site? Every day I see the level of professionalism diving down. People don't use search at all, edit nazis are racing for the first edit, people post questions on stack asking how to update software in ubuntu... The end is nigh. Also: Book of Leviticus 20; 13, you read those manuals same way you read the Bible.

Comment: "Editing also doesn't strike me as the best option, as it changes too much from the original intent, and doesn't (try to) educate the author about the mistake" - What you are describing seems to be a bad edit. Why can't these things be accomplished? Adding useful information to an answer seems exactly what edits are for

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272570/1157054

Comment: See also [What to do when massive downvoting hits you due to an external source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318863/what-to-do-when-massive-downvoting-hits-you-due-to-an-external-source?) and [Posting malicious code as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318722/posting-malicious-code-as-an-answer/) for a variation on the theme of `chmod 777`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the problem is, SO doesn't encourage deleting or flagging 'wrong' answers, it allows votes to float the order of the answers. There is not real way to circumvent crap that floats to the top, as we are dealing with a wide range of programming skills, unfortunately the expert programmers may not hold the majority of voting rights. I am hesitant about upvoting any answer, unless I fully understand it and know it works  as I don't want to float crap to the top.

Comment: Reading Shog9's edited answer, @Carpetsmoker, I have to agree you went about this the wrong way. Unfortunately there is no easy way to automate good commenting. If your automation is a mix of helpful, redundant, inapplicable, and incorrect, than I'd rather you don't make noise at all.

Comment: @DavidS Shog9's revised answer is even more wrong, as his claim that I "did not read any of the answers" is flat-out wrong. I read every single one of them, and *may* have made a few mistakes there (I can't check now), but I most certainly didn't just add a comment to every answer which mentioned "chmod 777" as is implied.

Comment: oi! you did wrong,  /r/pitchforkemporium against the moderator, OR the moderator just saw the number of comments and the time and did actually read any of the comments, which is totally justified if we think about it that way _lowers pitchfork_

Comment: One should note that this incident is a side effect of [duplicate comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276380) moderator tool introduction. As usual, a shiny new toy invites experimentation.

Comment: While the question contains a good summary in the footnotes, if you came here looking for a good source for why exactly `chmod 777` is terrible advice, maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous

Answer (score 98):

Given the user's story, I believe the moderator did the wrong thing in this case.

Leaving 154 *helpful* comments is doing a great service to our community. Doing it in a short amount of time is efficient and productive.

I can think of a couple of topics on which I've left scores of comments that say basically the same thing. But I've done it over time, and somewhat haphazardly. I did nothing wrong in this, but it's taken me longer, and I have only helped those I happened to stumble across. Does the fact that I was inefficient about it somehow make it okay?

Of course, spamming the site with unhelpful comments is bad. And since the system can't tell the difference between helpful and unhelpful comments, there might be alarms that go off whenever anyone spams the site with comments. If there are, I presume it's so that human intelligence can be brought to bear, not to invite a human to implement a reflexive and destructive response.

Life is full of situations where human judgment provides the best outcome. Not everything is algorithmic and rule-bound. According to the user, he or she proceeded carefully, case-by-case, and this flurry of activity should have been given the same consideration.

Comment: definitely +1. We should just go and fix the offending content instead of beating around the bush.

Comment: Agreed - I'm a bit peeved that the official response is that they should have 'done it right, not fast' which is exactly what the moderator did not do - rather than contact Carpetsmoker and/or delete the few bad comments, they decided to nuke it all. Not to mention the response that Carpetsmoker should have completely fixed all the answers *entirely* rather than making small steps towards the goal.

Comment: Looking at the discussion on Shog's post, a _lot_ of those comments were out of place on the answers. IE: Noise.
Spamming comments or edits is _never_ a good idea.

Comment: I've also gotten my answers removed even though they were important to place in many questions.

Answer (score 20):

The real problem here is not being addressed as far as I can see, which is: votes don't indicate post quality.

You can't blame someone for posting a shotgun-approach answer like *"Do a `chmod 777`, it fixes all permission issues"*. The same happens for Windows Services (*"Just run it as Local System [i.e. administrator]"*).

You can't blame such posters for not knowing better. You can't blame later visitors from believing that that answer, still being on the site with a positive score, is supposedly something good, nor can you blame them for upvoting it because it solved their problem, keeping the answer on the top.

Yes, it is intensely stupid to copy-paste anything off the web and run that on any machine, but that's just how the world works: people are going to do that. We can't put disclaimers on every post.

The real problem is that crap isn't downvoted.

Comment: There is many problems with the site and none of them being addressed since trivial stuff is more important :'(

Comment: @vove It is a sad state of events, but likely true.  I can see problems with enough information to answer getting harangued for not being in the correct format.  I see people with little reputation being snotty in rule application to the top 0.5% in all time contribution.  StackOverflow hopes that popularity and truth align, but they only do so when the answers don't depend on popular but wildly dangerous answers. Brings to mind all the "turn off selinux" answers to all the "I got a selinux warning" questions (or older yet, the "turn off the firewall" answers to fix network connections)

Comment: Agreed. Downvoting the answer is in the vein of this site and the spirit of not enabling low quality answers. Unfortunately, the single downvote that you're able to apply when you come across such an answer may not make a dent in the substantial upvotes that the answer may have, as you mention.

Comment: What are your thoughts on organizing people to try to shift the tide, so to speak, by pouring on downvotes and maybe upvoting an alternative answer?

Comment: @jpmc26 everyone's vote is equal, so that doesn't work unless you really organise the voters - and I don't like mob voting. Also, there are more people looking for the copy-pasteable quick-fix than there are people who are willing to thoroughly review, test and criticize answers, which in general is reflected by the votes, especially on answers. I also don't really think applying a banner to such answers is a great idea either; who gets to decide which banners to place, who will review that and where to draw the line of which principles are _too_ bad a practice to warrant such a banner?

Comment: @CodeCaster There is no need to comment on the banners. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @jpmc26 I didn't mean your answer in particular, and it's been suggested before (in the context of SQL injection).

Comment: It's not just the votes. In my experience, people rarely ever look past the answer with the accept mark, and the only person capable of controlling the accept mark (and thus, the first answer displayed), is the original asker. Who, in many cases, is the noob who doesn't know a good solution from a working solution, and will accept whatever he used to solve the problem. I think that there's room for improvement there (say, N gold badge holders able to vote change an accept mark on an old question). The details need to be ironed out, but I feel like that's a good direction to go to.

Answer (score 13):

FWIW, I have to agree the moderator did SO a disservice if he deleted 154 helpful comments merely because they all arrived at once.

I don't agree with the warning label jpmc26 suggests.  It is nebulous, and the hair-on-fire ServerFault answer it references is basically *wrong*: the consequences it describes flow from 1) having root privilege and 2) using `chmod -R 777 /`.  An organization that grants root privilege to someone who doesn't understand what that command does deserves what's coming to it.  I believe it's called a *teachable moment*.

While perhaps inappropriate, setting a single file, or all files in a single directory, to mode 777 isn't nearly so deleterious as plonking the whole system.  That's doubly true if the user owns the files.  And mode 777 can be a useful debugging technique, if only to demonstrate that permissions are *not* the problem.  Haven't we all done that at some point?

A better answer would guide the reader in a productive direction.  Permission problems often mean the uid (or sometimes gid) that owns the process does not have appropriate permissions on the file.  Sometimes, a directory in the pathname is the culprit; troubleshooting can be complicated by the use of symbolic links because the effective pathname isn't obvious.  When the documentation is unclear, ambiguous, inaccurate, or missing -- that *never happens*, right? -- `chmod` won't be used on the file the application is trying to open.  `strace` is a great tool for discovering what pathname was used.

To boil it down, a better warning might say:

- Mode 777 is rarely the right choice because it defeats security considerations that the application and the system depend on.
- Make sure you know what uid and gid own the affected process, and by what permissions -- via user, group, or other -- the process is supposed to be able to open the file.
- You might use mode 777 temporarily to determine if file permissions are actually the problem.  Do so carefully, in such a way that you can restore the original permissions.
- Ensure the uid/gid of the process opening the file matches that of the file.  World-read privilege is often used for static, nonsensitive information, such as documentation.  World-write privilege is rare.
- Remember that privilege is checked in order of uid, gid, other.  If, for example, the file and process have the same uid, that is the controlling permission, regardless of gid or other.  Wider grants do not override a narrower denial.
- Ensure the uid/gid of the process has execute privilege on each directory in the path to the file.  Follow any symbolic links used.
- Verify that the file that "can't be opened" is the one the application is opening, and not another by the same name in a different directory.  strace(1) will show the name of each file opened.

Answer (score 9):

I am writing to support jmpc26's answer. It is rather meant as a comment, but there is not enough place, and no pictures are possible.

In the German Wikipedia, there are such hints for instance for medical and legal subjects. They are signals for readers that they must be careful in the application of the written text, and it is IMHO also some nonwarranty clause for Wikipedia.

See the hint for medical subjects:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angina 
[image]
Rough translation: "This article is about health. It is not meant to be used for medical self-testing, nor can it replace the consultation of a professional medic. Please read the hints for [health subjects](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hinweis_Gesundheitsthemen)."

Here the hint for legal subjects:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absonderungsrecht
[image] 
Rough translation: "Please consider our hints about [legal subjects](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hinweis_Rechtsthemen)!"

In answer to g00glen00b's comment: yes, those marks should be set on `eval` too. If they were not too heavy in the layout yet alerting enough, they'd be useful. Here on meta, there is also a known discussion about questions that are suspicious for trying to find out how to abuse a system.

Comment: You mean SO should have a disclaimer of the sort: "This site may contain malicious code, don't use if you are not sure what you are doing. In doubt ask a professional. Upvotes are not a reliable guarantee of correctness."

Comment: `eval` isn't that dangerous. Doing things with untrusted user input is dangerous. `eval()` is just one example. This applies to many things: database access (SQL injections), file paths (`../../../../../etc/passwd`), usernames (faking other users using clever Unicode), XSS (My username is `<script>...`), etc. etc. etc. Yes, many things *can* be used dangerously, but *this* is a very specific and objectively dangerous thing to do that is unfortunately also something of a "meme" in the original sense of the word. We can't fix the world; we can just try to fix the worst of it.

Comment: @Trilarion, I'm not sure about how SO *must* disclaim, e.g. from the angle of a lawyer. But, if I see recommendation of `chmod 777` or an (-> Carpetsmoker) *unreflected* usage of `eval`, then yes, such a disclaimer is a good thing.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, thank you. To me, your suggestion contains what could be written in disclaimers :-) "Be aware that by usage of `eval()`, you are opening doors for software attacks ..." To trigger that such a disclaimer is read and consumed, or, where to put the warning mark, `eval()` is the right place.

Comment: This warning applies to StackOverflow as a whole, not just specific cases. You should not just copy-paste code blindly, **never**, whether or not they contain `chmod 777` or `eval()` or ... shouldn't matter.

Comment: @g00glen00b: Clearly the solution to blind copy-paste is for all code blocks to be presented to viewers as images, not text.  As a side benefit, the whole question of which license to use for code will become moot.  Of course, we will then have the problem of blind transcribers instead of blind copy-paste, but hey, you can't win them all.

Comment: This seems like it'd be ripe for abuse and trigger edit wars. Medicine and law have external legal requirements around giving advice, and these banners basically just say "This is opinion. Talk to a professional." The problem is that on SO, we *are* the professionals and there aren't any external legal guidelines to use when determining whether a banner should be displayed or not. `eval` has appropriate uses - that's why it was created. Every technical decision must balance risk and reward, and every professional is going to balance them differently based on circumstances.

Comment: @JDB, thx for your contribution. Hopefully writers on Wikipedia very often are professionals. To me, the banners are not about the quality of the authors, but about the meaning of the text. On the other hand, may I ask if absolutely all people on Stack Overflow are experts? -- There are lots of little warning plates in the world: "Caution, stage" yet no law forces people to do so. -- To me, all this is much more about establishing a constructive and careful style of communication than about forcing and prohibiting.

Comment: @BenVoigt that also applies to adding a warning, you'll always have blind warning-ignorant cop-pastes. You'll always have that kind of species, trying to fix it with a warning solves nothing in my opinion. In contrary, it makes it messy, because in my opinion `chmod 777` is not a standalone case. Applying these warnings to all these posts is an impossible job, and adding it only to a few of those posts won't make a difference either.

Comment: @peter_the_oak - The real problem is: "Who has the authority to hang the sign, or mandate that the sign be hung?" In all your examples, there is a clear authority (government, building owner). On SO, not so much. And wikipedia is a very different scenario. It's one thing to say "citation needed", which makes no judgment on the validity, truth or wisdom of a statement. It's another thing entirely to say "don't do what the author just said to do" (which is how many will interpret such a banner).

Comment: @peter_the_oak - To answer your first question though... it's the case moreso on SO then elsewhere (in my ignorant opinion) that the people reading answers on this are themselves the "professional" within their context. Unlike me reading medical advice that I can then take to my doctor, users here typically have no one to take advice to. They are typically building out solutions themselves, so "talk to a professional before acting on this" is simply impractical.

Comment: You may wish to edit your answer. In light of Shog's advice, I've deleted mine. I don't want to be guilty of the very thing we're discussing here: highly upvoted answers that are bad advice.

Comment: @jpmc26 - By deleting you did the wrong thing. Your answer was sound. Please, please undelete it.

Comment: @DeerHunter SO may be a community, but it's a managed one. If it's not something the people who own and run SO want us doing, I don't want to advise people to do it. Given that they've done more for people across the world than I would ever dare hope I could, I'll defer to their judgement. =)

Comment: @jpmc26 - be brave. It's the Internet, and nobody really cares. Sometimes you have to speak up, though.

Comment: @DeerHunter If I felt my suggestion was defensible despite what Shog said, I would. I don't think it is. If you feel that strongly, maybe ask a few high rep users to undelete it.

Comment: @jpmc26 - all right, you've just let yourself be bullied by Shog. If that's fine by you, it's fine by me.

Comment: @DeerHunter I disagree with the description of "bulling", but this is not fine by me and I've voted to undelete. I feel like the community is finally becoming more aware of the importance of **responsibly** addressing security concerns. The votes on jpmc26's post were a useful visible expression of that, and I'd like it restored. We won't convince Stack Exchange Inc., or continue to convince more of the community, if we just give up. (More broadly, the negligence in our industry is becoming a greater and greater risk to the public at large, and we have an obligation to get our act together.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks - you are restoring my faith in humanity : ) Thanks for your vote.

Answer (score -3):

At your place I would edit in the first place, as you did. But if the author doesn't correct it in few days, I would edit in some huge (probably red) warning, including some basic reason why it's a bad idea and a link to some more detailed reasoning on it.

Well, I probably wouldn't do it, because I'm not (quite) a high-rep user like you and I wouldn't like to bother all those who do the suggested edits reviews, but that's nothing to stop you.

Comment: "I would sign it with my nick" The name and usercard of an editor to an answer they do not own is already attached to the answer. Such a signature is not necessary.

Comment: @BoltClock: didn't know that, edited now.

Answer (score -20):

### Spam: always a bad choice

I'm adding a short note here, because folks have indicated in the comments that they're confused by the slightly disparaging remark I made about these comments in my closing. That's usually a sign that I've been less than candid. So let's be crystal clear about something:

**You just spammed scores of people on Stack Overflow with this crap.** You obviously didn't read any of the answers you were commenting on, as evidenced by this same cookie-cutter comment left on answers that *already* urged readers not to use `chmod 777`, answers to questions where *the only viable answer* was `chmod 777`, and answers that were so poorly written and received no one in their right mind would skip past the legible, upvoted, accepted answers to read them. You just did a simple keyword search and blasted these out, in the hope that they would magically make things better. That's abuse, and you're lucky the moderator who found them was kind enough to just delete them.

Now...

### The right way

> (you can't always just change this to chmod 755; usually the solution is to set the user and/or group, depending on the OP's situation/problem)

So, do that then. If the solution that folks are looking for requires an understanding of the specific problem being solved, then that's what you'll have to give them if you want to dissuade them from `chmod 777`. Which kinda rules out a uniform fix that can be slapped onto hundreds of posts without regard to context. Catharsis lost.

But that's what needs to happen: either edits, or alternate answers. A generic comment (that might not even be picked up by folks quoting or scraping the post) doesn't do anything to stand in the way of folks looking for a quick fix. The path of least resistance remains chmod 777.

So if you're serious about this - if you honestly believe it's a problem that needs to be solved - then organize a campaign to fix it. Identify problematic answers, compile a list of valid solutions, and provide them via edits or answers as your conscience allows.

OTOH, if you're *not* serious, then do nothing. That's easier for you *and* the moderators who had to clean up after you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on organizing people to try to shift the tide, so to speak, by pouring on downvotes and maybe upvoting an alternative answer? Obviously, when a small edit is appropriate, then that makes the most sense, but if a substantial edit that would change the entire intent of the post is required, normal site etiquette would insist a new answer instead. But when a new answer is added, a highly upvoted answer with bad advice remains.

Comment: *Providing* an alternate answer is infinitely more important than organized voting, @jpmc26. If you can't get an answer that works, is easy to understand, and is appreciably safer than the existing one... Then such activity is just pointless thuggery; folks will still take the path of least resistance.

Comment: That's fair, but I was more asking in the context of when there *is* a better alternative answer. Sorry for not being clear. The question is really: is organized voting an appropriate way of trying to reduce the prominence of bad advice in favor of better alternatives? My gut says no, but I don't know of any other alternative that has a chance of working when a bad answer has gotten highly upvoted.

Comment: I'm not a fan of organized voting *period*, @jpmc26. If there's an alternate answer that's actually *better* than the chmod one, upvote it, downvote the other, and move on to the next problem. IOW, the scenario you describe is somewhere between "good problem to have" and "not a problem at all". I suspect if this was common Carpetsmoker wouldn't have felt the need to drop comments everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Re: "...had to clean up after you". It seems to me the OP's comments were helpful contributions to the site and therefore required no cleaning up, even if they weren't as good an option as posting his own answers. Even if he had posted his own answer, a comment to alert the author of the dangerous answer would probably be in order as well anyway.

Comment: @Shog9 do you mean we should stop all comments about bad practices (i.e. SQL injection, storing passwords in DBs)? I probably made 100+ of those so far - sounds like it was a mistake.

Comment: `the moderators who had to clean up after you` c'mon, "clean up"? really? That implies that something harmful was done. Is this harmful? You may feel like this is a useless exercise and that I'm pissing in the wind − fine; we can disagree on that. You could also say that going to meta *first* would have been a better option − and you would be right. Sorry :-( But "clean up" :-/ You know, that comment, combined with some others in the TL, makes me extremely unmotivated to spend *any* time fixing crap on SO because as soon as mod decides it's not required you get this sort of crap slung at you..

Comment: You posted about 140 of the same comment in about 90 minutes, @Carpetsmoker. I estimate *about* one every 40 seconds. So I should either be impressed by your ability to read and comprehend so quickly, or dismayed that you didn't try to get closer to the minimum rate-limit when scripting these.

Comment: [Here's a useful discussion piece](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328481/chmod-777-to-a-folder-and-all-contents), @Ergwun. 400 *thousand* views, 5 answers that *all* recommend `chmod 777`. No other answers. There's a comment on the *question* that tries to dissuade the asker from doing this, but it's what he asked for. Explain to me how 5 additional comments, all identical, makes any difference here.

Comment: There's not a lot of reading comprehension required to understand "you need to do `chmod 777`" ;-) I skipped the ones that seemed okay or doubtful. I still don't really understand how the time frame is really that important, I'm afraid. I must have left 100 or more links back to the "How do I prevent SQL injections in PHP"-question back in the day, and so have many others. How is this different, other than the time frame?

Comment: Well, the idea was that a) at least *some* readers would pick the comments up, and that b) at least *some* authors would come back and fix their answers (and some indeed did!). We can't fix everything, but a 50% improvement is stll, well, a 50% improvement. I felt uncomfortable making too many edits and felt that comments were less intrusive :-/ At any rate, would you recommend editing those five answers? Or adding a new one?

Comment: If you can think of a good answer to "how do I chmod 777 everything?" that doesn't involve chmod 777, yes, you should post it @Carpetsmoker.

Comment: Anyway, the problem with just blindly doing this is that you end up adding a lot of noise for little or no gain. That comment got slapped on answers that weren't about web-dev, answers that weren't problematic, answers that weren't upvoted or even formatted well enough to be understood... It was essentially spam: massive numbers of messages in the hope of hitting a few targets. Why would that ever be appropriate?

Comment: And my answer will then sit there as the sixth answer ... Mostly unviewed ... This particular answer might get some love and upvotes on account of being mentioned here, but that's an exception. How is that more useful than a comment below the *top* answer? That seems much more visible to me... And how how of these answers should be posted? 25? 50? 100? 150?

Comment: So you got about a hundred thousand people a year *looking for* instructions on making a whole *directory tree* world-everything, @Carpetsmoker. You'd think this would be the *motherlode of chmod 777 questions*, the White Whale to your Ahab, the Mecca to your Mohammedan. And your solution is... A repetitious comment? This is Carnegie Hall, brother - no holding back, give it everything you got 'cause if you don't make a difference here you've failed more people than will ever see most of your other comments.

Comment: When the question is asking how to do `chmod 777`, I agree that commenting with a warning to each answer is not helpful. But I think there are two different issues here (1): should it be allowed to add duplicate comments to hundreds of different answers warning of a common danger, and (2) did the OP execute this effectively?
Now without mod tools, we can't see the answer to (2), but I think your answer argues against (1) in general, which I disagree with. If you are actually taking issue with the way OP did it (e.g. in question you refer to) then maybe you could clarify this in your answer.

Comment: Those are people looking to *fix a problem*. And we are offering them a downright stupid answer. Somehow I always thought SO was about offering quality, so excuse me for caring about that and giving a damn. The fact of the world is that every redneck in Alabama can and does run a Wordpress or eCommerce VPS for $5/month. You can call them idiots all you want, but that's not going to stop their Wordpress crap from sending out malware and spam − and that *is* what those hacked Wordpress installs are doing. A few proper instructions (and it's not *that* hard) will fix at least *some* of it...

Comment: ... At any rate, I am not at all fixated on the comments as such, and that's not really why I started this question as such. I just want to figure out the best way to fix this crap.

Comment: If you wanna fix it, then fix it @Carpetsmoker: edit existing answers or add better ones. That's the Stack Overflow way. Why bother allowing edits and answers to questions asked years ago, if not to enable exactly this? It's never too late...

Comment: @Shog9 Because not everyone has the time or willpower to pore over hundreds of questions to apply a fix. The comment was better than nothing. In that particular post (#8328481) - if the comment was on *all the answers*, then yes, I agree that maybe they should be removed (especially since there was an upvoted comment on the question). However, just because they didn't fix the problem entirely, doesn't mean it was unhelpful. If even one person edited the answer because of the comment, it would be a win. If even one person saw the comment and decided to research further, it would be a win.

Comment: Shog9, you forgot to explain how commenting is worse than doing nothing at all.

Comment: Okay; so to be clear and avoid confusion: if I edit a whole bunch of answers and add a whole bunch of new answers, that is fine and not considered spam?

Comment: So suddenly I have 4 different people here telling me the comments were a good idea because, hey, no one had any better ideas and [at least it was something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician%27s_syllogism). I'm sure thousands of people feel the same way about `chmod 777` answers, of course. So which is it: anything is good when you're in a hurry, or slow down and do it right? Because, and I do want to put a fine point on this, I'm sensing an *absolutely ridiculous* amount of hypocrisy here right now.

Comment: "anything is good when you're in a hurry, or slow down and do it right" that's not how the people downvoting you see it, Shog9. Your stance on this seems small-minded.

Comment: OK, I just read your edit and that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `"You obviously didn't read any of the answers you were commenting on, as evidenced by this same cookie-cutter comment left on answers that already urged readers not to use chmod 777"` -> No, that's not true. I *did* read every answer, I think *skipped* more answers than I commented on. Although it's of course entirely possible that I may have misunderstood a few (I can't go back and verify). `"answers to questions where the only viable answer was chmod 777"` -> I can't really think of a situation where this is the case to be honest...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: You keep claiming you read ___every single answer___. But 140 comments in ~90 minutes? While you claimed to have skipped the majority of answers? That results in a minimum of 281 answers read in 90 minutes, which is barely 20 seconds per answer. How do you expect _anyone_ to believe you there?

Comment: @Cerbrus It was more like two hours according to my browser's logs, and I viewed about 260 questions; which leaves us with about 45s per question on average, which perhaps doesn't sound like a lot, but is plenty of time to judge the context of a command. Perhaps more importantly, I am quite surprised that now only am I made out to be an abuser and generic asshole over this, but apparently also a liar. :-/ Great. I'll try and help out again...

Comment: `(120 minutes / 260 questions) * 60 seconds == 27.7 seconds`. Math, mate.

Comment: @Cerbrus It seems odd that people are claiming that a couple of posts per minute is too fast, when Stack Overflow moderators are frequently going through the flag queue at the rate. Deep analysis of these posts is not required; this could easily be in line with our (imperfect) standards of moderation accuracy.

Comment: Moderators aren't *generally* being asked to vet posts for possible security issues, @Jeremy.

Comment: That's true, but an expert roughly vetting for security issues isn't necessarily more intensive than what they are asked to do.

Comment: "Isn't necessarily" being the crucial aspect there, @Jeremy. You might recall that the fastest mods tend to filter down to flags and posts that can be quickly processed, and then handle more difficult ones at a slower pace (Bill was particularly adept at this, and the tooling for it mostly exists because of his urging). When you can't do that, the context switching kills your time... or you start to make mistakes.

Comment: Sure. But from Carpetsmoker's post it sounded like he was simply skipping over the more ambiguous cases, much as the moderators would. That sounded good to me. However I haven't looked too closely at his actual actions, so I could be mistaken. (More broadly, I encourage action like this, even with some errors, because large-scale full-quality cleanup of posts like this is probably impractical, and letting so many potentially-dangerous posts remain untouched is somewhat irresponsible. But that's getting away from my original comment.)

Comment: Yeah, that's... Not really what I saw. I'm somewhat reluctant to post a full list of posts here, because I don't see the point of pushing the comment issue further and because I'd much rather see some agreement on techniques for actually fixing the problems before throwing stuff in the pillory. But I did go through them (after a moderator had already handled all this), and it was pretty scatter-shot.

Comment: Personally I find the OP's claim credible that ~150 comments is a tiny fraction of the site, and the "I want to help" concern they were delivered under, seems valid to me. It would have been more correct to take it to meta _first_, but I personally would not go to war over 150 comments on what is quite plainly a dangerous recommendation even in the best of situations.

Comment: 150 comments *is* tiny, @Jeff. 150 comments in < 2 hours was the concerning part here.

Answer (score -20):

First of all I think administration should really look into it as it is clear this topic started many controversies. So, should we babyproof the boards or not?

I think the answer is way simpler than it seems:

1. Is stackoverflow.com meant to be used by professionals? If yes then no warnings needed.
2. Is stackoverflow.com meant to be used by everyone (including people who just started learning to program)? If yes then implement the warnings for everything.

Personally I would love to see in the end that the boards are mainly targeted at professional use. If there is a need to post a warning notice on everything so noone puts himself in danger maybe we should do that to save innocent lives...

Hard topic because it isn't easy to determine what is considered obvious and what not. In my opinion after finishing any IT school one should have certain level of knowledge. Now for me that knowledge might be basics, but for a person working in the field for some time problems I struggle with might be basics. Seems that another question to answer would be 'when I can consider myself a professional?'

So, stack for pros or free for all? If users want to implement the warnings though, in my opinion it would be better to implement basic knowledge in kind of some 'READ THIS BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING ON THIS SITE' faq or something similar.

Comment: You mean like in the [tour], which I'm not convinced people actually read.

Comment: Exactly, sometimes I check who has the badge for that and you would be surprised.

Comment: Even _as professionals_ there are things that individuals don't know. I work on a Unix-y system, so I have an idea that chmod 777 is dodgy. But suppose I had a problem with a Windows machine, which I know next to nothing about, and found equivalent advice in an answer, with bunch of upvotes. Still, I'm paranoid and suspicious enough to double-check, so then I find there's dozens of _other_ upvoted answers saying the same thing. Now what? A whole bunch of people have vouched for this information, but the picture is incomplete, or they were flat-out wrong.

Comment: Use the common sense I guess. Does it look safe? Do you know what you are about to do? Thinking before doing something instead of following "monkey sees monkey does" ideology could be a real lifesaver. Even when you are at the learning level.

Comment: @vove Hardly. There are plenty of exploits which require deep understanding of the system and would completely fail the naive 'common sense' check. To ignore what others say and do what you 'think' is best is just as dangerous

Comment: I doubt exploits you have in mind compare to setting chmod 777 or running windows os as an admin instead of working from user account. You just disagree to disagree. Every pro argument I read here makes no sense (common sense, washing machine, people not using linux, seriously, wth is wrong with you?). You also failed to understand my point in here, but yeah, let's stick to that mumbo jumbo and start proofing the boards, so some kids hosting apps on local (!!) don't put their system at risk of being vulnerable. Only thing I can say is I am deeply disappointed with the approach to these boards.

Answer (score -39):

You're wasting your time trying to solve a non-problem. Anyone who comes across a "run `chmod 777`" answer falls into one of three groups:

- people like you and me, who know what it does and what the potentially harmful consequences are, and will never use it
- people who don't know or understand what it does, but will do some research to determine if it's the best solution, find out it has the drawbacks mentioned, conclude that it's a poor solution, and never use it
- people who don't know or understand what it does and don't care to find out because they just want their s**t to work

The first two groups aren't affected. The third group is, but:

- it's not the responsibility of Stack Overflow and its answerers to do due diligence for users
- they don't care about the dangers, or the right way, or any of that important stuff. They sure as hell aren't going to read a comment telling them not to do that, or a warning in a post's body. The only thing you're achieving by trying to help such help vampires, is a waste of your (and in this case, moderators') time.

The only thing you, as a responsible Stack Overflow user, can and should do is downvote `chmod 777` answers - but only when there are better alternatives available.

Comment: _"They sure as hell aren't going to read a comment telling them not to do that, or a warning in a post's body"_. This, tenfold. Excellent answer.

Comment: These comments weren't *just* intended for the readership, they're **also** intended for the author, several of whom have now *fixed* their posts! I have seen several people *repeat* this "advice" on more than one question. And no, I also don't think that people "who don't know or understand what it does" somehow "don't care". Some, sure. But I feel that that most *do* care, but just *don't understand it*. The best solution to that is to try and *educate* them, not throw our hands in the air and shout "whatever, they're just idiots".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I agree with you: a comment and a downvote is better than a downvote alone. But, maybe like Ian suggests, a systematic approach is overkill? By "overkill" I mean good but not needed - not something to be rolled back, nor something to add an official disclaimer for.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I had a look at some of your comments and from my small sample size, I saw exactly **one** instance that caused someone to delete their `chmod 777` *comment*, and zero *answers* that were modified after the fact. This further reinforces my belief that the people posting these answers don't care (except about rep) or understand, and further reinforces my belief that people who blindly use those answers don't care about anything except "making it work". In both cases, the problem is education, and while your attempts to educate people are noble, they are also misguided... (cont)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker ... because these are people who **don't want to be educated**. There is an old saying about giving a man a fish versus teaching him to fish; you are trying to teach men who only want 1 fish.

Comment: @IanKemp There were about five people who responded in total (but I'd have to check to be sure). It's about 4% which is not very large, but most comments were deleted fairly quickly and were probably unseen. I don't really agree with with your observation that I am "trying to teach men who don't want to fish". For some this is true, sure. But i don't think this applies to *most* of these people... I am less cynical and more hopeful than you on this point I guess...

Comment: And it seems that five was correct, at least those that I can trace because the response comments aren't deleted: [answer fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35636756/660921), [now-removed comment said that "777 is not a security issue"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35127849/660921) (wtf?!), [fixed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34281366/660921), [fixed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34281628/660921) (I saw four or five "chmod 777" answer from this person btw, not sure if they're all fixed), [educated on a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35967081/660921)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Trying to educate people is always laudable, I'm just suggesting that your enthusiasm and willingness to help may have greater benefits if applied elsewhere. Regardless, please don't let this cynical old fart discourage you from being a useful contributor to Stack Overflow!

Comment: 5 edited posts. Heck, let's call it 10. Out of how many? 150? That's not even `7%`. Mass comments like that aren't effective.

Comment: I think that you're missing the point. Someone reading an answer will likely assume that the solution has no drawbacks unless they are specifically mentioned!

Comment: @Troyseph There's an old saying about assumptions and what they make of you and me. Don't assume, check. [Don't think, know.](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/131)

Comment: for me, many years ago, chmod 777 was that command that you run when apache doesn't let you upload files in wordpress. then I learned that chmod 755 was better, and why, and what could happen when you run 777. in both instances I was just looking for a solution to my problem, clicking through the internet at breakneck speed, copypasting code to run  to see if it would help, because I need a goddam fix RIGHT NOW. I'm the third, second and first group all in one, at different times... but I never didn't care. a notice about the dangers would have helped me learn faster.

Comment: "people like you and me" are those who know about unix style permissions, the other two groups are those who don't.... that's knowledge, not some innate inability or unwillingness to learn. lets help those that don't know by sharing what we do.

Comment: chmod 777 is almost always bad approach and almost always chmod 775 works the same for most. If you let all around stack answers like chmod 777, people will use it, share the knowledge with others (so more people will use it) and they never know there is another solution, that works and is not so big security risk. I had to reinstall system at least 5 times when i mispelled chmod 777 in command line and making all files on os writable and destroying whole system.

Comment: I've seen a lot of missing the point on Meta, but this takes the cake, so let me put it simply: if you are stupid enough to run code off the internet without finding out what it does first, you deserve whatever happens to you. That is all.

Comment: Your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: I wonder if you have taken every piece of advice on the Internet in this manner. When you last Googled for a reason why your computer/car/washing machine wasn't working and someone said "You need to calibrate your flux capacitor by pressing the rest button three times", did you go off and figure out what that actually did? And have you done that every time you found an answer online? We have a responsibility to be the guardians of truth as well of good practice here, not just leave people to their own (potentially) well intentioned actions.

Comment: @IanKemp You are right, its dummy thing to copy paste code without understanding what it does, however one does not know everything, so pointing out he is stupid is not the right thing to do.

Comment: @IanKemp In a similar thought process, you could argue that taking random advice from anywhere online without knowing the underlying reasons is a dumb idea. Let's say I'm looking for a way to clean a stain in my carpet, so I look up some solutions. One such "answer" is to mix some bleach with ammonia. If the site looks reputable and it's one of the first few Google results, why would I have any reason to doubt the validity of the answer? So I go ahead, mix the two together, and fall over dead thanks to the toxic vapors created by the chemical reaction. Are you seriously telling me that

Comment: (continued) I deserved to die because I didn't happen to know that specific combination of liquids would kill me? If someone had warned me ahead of time, I might have either avoided that solution altogether or (if I'm really desperate) at least taken some precautions like a gas mask. How am I supposed to learn without being given an opportunity to do so?

Comment: @DavidG Doh, of course? You would start unscrewing your washing machine without even having a clue what you are about to do? Only a complete idiot would do that. I think it's crystal clear: if you have no idea- take it to the professional, otherwise you might hurt yourself.

Comment: @Mage Xy another horrible example. Learning by putting oneself in danger is not the best practice to follow. This topic is completely derailed at the moment and mods are deleting the wrong content.

Comment: @vove: It's not a bad example. It's the exact same situation, albeit with the consequences applied to a living person instead of a web server. My point is, how would I know if I'm putting myself in danger in the first place if I've never seen this information before? You seem to be under the impression that good security practices are de facto knowledge that everyone has, but that's simply not the case.

Comment: I simply have no answer. If you look for solutions to problems you are experiencing in a field you have completely no idea about and you take stranger's anonymous advice without even a tiny doubt crossing your mind saying "you sure about that?" (it's your common sense by the way) I cannot answer that. I wouldn't trust anyone and before I mindlessly copypaste any code into my own I analyze it. Of course bleach and ammonia is basic chemistry, nevertheless many ppl, mostly kids, almost killed themselve trying to create home magic crystals. Another example yenkem. We cannot babyproof the world for

Comment: for that kind of people in our society.

Comment: @vove Absolutely I would, if I was told it was a simple thing to do and that information came from a respected source like SO. For clarity, I *have* fixed my computer, my car and my washing machine using advice found on the internet, and I was able to browse websites, drive myself home and clean my clothes afterwards.

Comment: @IanKemp The comments were deleted (which prompted this post, obviously). You won't be able to find their comments in their profile.

Comment: @IanKemp we aren't here to punish stupidity.  we are on SO to learn, and to help others learn. leaving this kind of dangerous (and on the face of it, accepted by the community) advice in answers without a forewarning of some sort is tantamount to leaving sharp knives lying on the floor for children to find. Then calling the child stupid for picking them up and trying to figure out what they can use them for. It's great that you know all this stuff, but others dont - please don't call others stupid for trying solutions that were found here, posted by users like you and me.