# Is it okay to show a screenshot of a deleted question to low reputation users?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, meta

Just now I saw [a Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326031/how-is-this-answer-consisting-only-of-nos-an-answer-or-am-i-missing-something?cb=1) in which the discussion is related to some question that is deleted. The user who asked the question has used a screenshot of the deleted post so that users with less than 10000 reputation can see the question. I guess that the user who asked the Meta question used somebody else's account to see the post since they don't have enough reputation to see it. (Or maybe somebody added it later.)

Now, if deleted questions are supposed to be completely hidden from low reputation users for some reason, how did the community not object to posting the screenshot of the deleted question? Is one allowed to do that in general, or only in some special circumstances?

Comment: A lot of people do it all the time including myself. If the mods had issues with it, they probably would've stopped us by now.

Comment: @CherubimAnand It's fine.  Anyone can see the post using any search engine (viewing cached pages), through the SE Data Explorer, and there is at least one website designed to allow anybody to view a deleted post (don't remember the addy)

Comment: @Will MetaSmoke?

Comment: @cybermonkey nah.  The one I'm talking about allows you to enter a URL to a deleted question.  But you can probably find it on metasmoke, if it was detected by the bot.

Comment: "Or maybe somebody added it later." as seen in the revision history http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/326031/revisions, it's Glorfindel who added it.

Comment: Someone asked this a few months ago. Can't find the dupe now though.

Comment: @Will http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted

Comment: I've seen people do it hundreds of times on meta, including SE employees sometimes. I don't think anyone will ever begrudge.

Comment: "*Low reputation users*". 9999 rep is not so low :'(

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yes, it is ok.

It is actually important for proper moderation - if question is deleted for reasons that need to be discussed every user of meta should be able to see the question - image is good way (additionally adding some bump on meta-effect).

The main goal of deleting question is to keep searchable content clean and on-topic. Images of deleted questions are not searchable.

There is nothing really making it non-legal/bad/impossible otherwise:

- It is also ok based on way how SO content is licensed.
- There is nothing "hidden" on internet if it was ever published with access to everyone - so determined user can find such information (caches, way back machine,..) without screenshot.

Note: if content actually has problems (i.e. incorrect license of code sample) - one can request explicit content removal and it will be really removed from SO and no longer visible to anyone on SE network.

Comment: Given that, could it be beneficial for deleted posts to automatically be visible when linked from a meta post? Would that be a worthwhile feature request? (I don't know how possible/difficult that would be, just wondering.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I wouldn't go that far. But showing screenshots is not harmful at all.

Comment: If it is perfectly OK for low-rep users to see deleted posts, then why does the system go to the trouble of redirecting those users away whenever they reach such a page?

Comment: @MrLister For same reason [we do not like when answer contains harmful code even to illustrate dangers of something](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318722/posting-malicious-code-as-an-answer) — average user is not the brightest one and might actually follow advice or links even if they are bad or actually harmful and he is warned about it. Hi-rep user are expected to have enough cognitive function to distinguish between good and bad content and understand implications of their actions

Comment: @Don'tPanic Reminds me of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269201/1157054

Comment: @MrLister The same reason why the default windows GUI doesn't show file extensions.  It is trying to provide a simple, clean interface, without "unimportant stuff" clogging it up.  10k users are offered the crappier, raw interface, partly because they have the right to *revert* the delete (and it is hard to revert a delete on something you cannot see)

Comment: @MrLister The idea is basicly that once you're at 10k you know what this is and how this works enough that you won't misuse or damage yourself with the ability to see them - some of the deleted content is really nasty (Spam and abusive nuked stuff gets censored even for 10k users, they have to click through a banner to see it) or otherwise harmful to a normal onlooker. The system assumes that  when you reach 10k you know how to handle that kind of stuff.

Comment: Huh. Does this mean we are not allowed to add alt text or otherwise make the deleted content accessible for people who use screen-readers? Is there an official position on what markup SO considers searchable and not searchable, to clarify this?

Comment: @sourcejedi it's ok to show deleted content as quoted text too. Screenshots already should be used as clarification of the concern covered in the text of the meta post as requirements for posts are the same as on main site - so for a quality post on meta there should be no need to provide *additional* annotation for the screenshot. You are welcome to pick either approach, but keep in mind that screenshots are often used to minimize "meta effect" - it's easier to find back the original post from a text representation rather than image.

Answer (score 48):

This is not just okay, it should be encouraged.

Deleted posts are hidden from lower-rep users *on the main site* for a variety of reasons, but the general idea is to keep people from being distracted by "clutter", for some definition of "clutter".

High-rep users have the ability to see deleted material as part of their moderation privilege/responsibilty: reviewing stuff that other people have removed, just in case a mistake was made. Note that even those who can *view* deleted questions won't see them unless they deliberately go looking for them: the questions don't appear in question lists (deleted answers still show up in casual browsing because, well, where else would they go).

But a Meta question is not the same situation. Here, either we're talking about the deleted post in detail, or we're using it as an example of something. If some large percentage of the Meta readership can't even see the material under discussion, how are they supposed to participate?

Posting a screenshot allows *everyone*, not just the privileged few, to see what's being talked about, and therefore to engage on Meta. (We take egalitarianism on Meta as a self-evidently good thing.)

Comment: I particularly agree with the last paragraph.  There are fewer than 10,000 users out of the 5,000,000 who can view these privileged links.   Meta is an invaluable learning resource for us lower rep users.  If the link is important context, please, please, please put it in as a screenshot so that we can better understand the question.

Answer (score 15):

User contributions are copyleft so you can redistribute questions and answers with attribution, e.g. http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted.

I think the major purpose behind hiding deleted posts is to avoid the [broken-window effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory). If someone wants to go out-of-their-way to see the broken windows, or showcase a particularly curious broken window, whatever (*see [ruin photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruins_photography)*).

Comment: It's particularly useful when discussing whether or not a post should have been deleted, or for historical reasons.

Comment: The statement that you're not violating copyright law by posting the screenshot doesn't actually answer the question of whether or not it violates SE rules/policy to do so.  There are lots of actions that one can perform on SE that aren't illegal but that violate SE rules.

Answer (score 5):

Showing a deleted question in the context of examining it (or in this case the answers) should be <strike>allowed</strike> considered if it uncovers something useful. There are lots of good examples, but this would serve to show why an answer or question wasn't. Maybe censoring or blacking out names to protect the innocent might be considered as well.

I don't know what the purpose or purposes are for hiding deleted posts, but if a high reputation user chose to display it because they see some value in examining it, then it probably should be available (or the minimum to convey the issue) for display.