# Non-downvoted question with accepted answer deleted by moderator

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Yesterday a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709380) (10k rep required to view) with an accepted answer of mine was deleted by a moderator. AFAICS the question wasn't closed or downvoted, and I don't see anything particularly wrong with it (except maybe that it was a trivial question and the user didn't bother reading the error message he got).

What gives? Even though it's not a big deal I'd still like to know the reason behind it.

Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot of the question and answer]

Comment: Can you provide Screenshots?

Comment: The OP raised a custom flag asking for deletion. The moderator chose to oblige.

Comment: @JonClements Can moderators not disassociate posts?

Comment: @Stijn not directly - any such requests we forward to the CM team

Comment: I'm really curious as to what reason they could give to get this removed as this fly against how SO works.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess he didn't felt well about making that error. As for SO works, this question doesn't seems to have any value for others, so not worth of keeping it if user want its deletion.

Comment: @Walfrat That will teach me to read the screen shot ;)  Thanks.

Comment: Should someone delete the Meta question now? Just sayin'...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As Jon mentioned in the comments, the user in question flagged a couple of their questions and requested they be deleted. Typically, I decline flags like this on questions with upvoted answers.

However, I didn't think there was much here that would help people outside of the asker, and the answer seemed to be just pointing out something they should have noticed themselves, so I didn't think it was worth the effort to fight this user over this. That's why I deleted this particular question. I did not delete the other question they had requested, because there was the potential for that one to help others.

Comment: Would the typo/no-repo close reason apply here? I'm not sure it counts as unreproducible but "solved in a way unlikely to help others" appears to apply.

Comment: @BSMP: Sure, but that amounts to eventual deletion anyway.

Comment: Perhaps the tone of the answer, starting with a somewhat confrontational question in return, contributed to the inexperienced questioners perception that his question wasn't well received.   In such a case it seems entirely appropriate to remove the question on request.

Comment: Would preserving the screenshot in this question works against the user's request to delete it? I guess the screenshot should not be made available

Comment: @just No, [the screenshot is not a problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/is-it-okay-to-show-a-screenshot-of-a-deleted-question-to-low-reputation-users). Nothing is ever truly deleted on Stack Overflow. All deletions are "soft" deletions, visible to users with moderation privileges. It's part of the general principle that all actions are subject to audit by other users, including actions taken by moderators. And the only possible way to have this Meta discussion is to include the text of the question. There's no sensitive information here nickm could object to being public.