# Asked to get question removed, but haven't got a reply yet

Tags: support

I posted a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933237/if-statement-or-loops
) where I needed some guidance as to what to follow. I received replies straight away with the answer, but the question stated that I didn't want the answer because it was for my assignment. I do not want my college to find this thread that I posted a question on and got a answer for, as I'm not sure what they will make of it.

Could somebody delete the question for me? There are actually two questions, not one. I tried to report the question to the developers and it said they reply within 24 hours, but I didn't get any reply.

Comment: Pretty sure there is a duplicate somewhere of this question, but here's my advice: ***Don't post anything on the internet you don't want someone to find later.*** Even if mods do delete your question (extremely doubtful) it's already likely been picked up by scrapers and will still be googleable. Once something is on the internet, you will be very unlikely to ever completely remove it.

Comment: Your flag was processed (and declined) by a moderator yesterday. To see the response, view your flagging history; http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/6941622.

Comment: declined - I am not deleting these answers? Was that the reply I got?

Comment: @hassy786 That sounds like something a mod would have said. When you ask for this question to be deleted, you're also asking for the deletion of the work the answerers put into their answers, which is not fair to them. Only when the question is not useful/off-topic/really deserves to be deleted will it usually be deleted, precisely because it would be unfair to the answerers if a decent/on-topic/useful question was deleted just so the asker didn't have to deal with a hassle of a cheating system at school.

Comment: Nothing to do with this thread, but you really only need one period/full stop at the end of a sentence. Not two, and certainly not 22. Maybe three if you want an ellipsis, but those should not be used often.

Comment: You are not permitted to delete questions that have upvoted and/or accepted answers - after all, that just means that the people who bothered to write an answer have wasted their time, as it will never help anybody else. If you don't evidence of your cheating on your homework, don't do it.

Comment: Am I supposed to just think that the people who answered my question are uneducated idiots and do not know what it means when the question states DO NOT GIVE ME THE ANSWER but they did any way and now, that I need it to be deleted.. I will be denied for it EVEN THOUGH I SAID I DO NOT WANT THE ANSWER? Makes no sense but okay I will take that :)

Comment: If you didn't want an answer, don't write a question. If you just want coaching, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Does an educated non-idiot ask a question and demand not to be given an answer on a Question & Answer site?

Comment: Looks like I noticed the coaching bit late then

Comment: @hassy786 If you felt that the answers weren't good answers then why did you accept one of them (and potentially upvote some of them)?

Comment: If it states, I only need guidance then was I expected a answer on my code?

Comment: Jheez because I know how this website works..

Comment: Erm, no, it seems you don't

Comment: It was sarcasm..

Comment: I know that feel bro. Not sure why there is no permanent delete option.

Comment: @ManojKumar You should read the answers then. Quite carefully, I would say, and several times, until they sink in. Someone with your reputation shouldn't be so unaware of how the site works. You have enough privileges for it to be a problem.

Comment: @Clive Next time I will, bro.

Comment: @ManojKumar don't bro too hard bro or you might bro-ke something.

Comment: @Will As you say bro.

Answer (score 38):

> I had no intention of coming on this website FOR AN ANSWER OTHER THAN SOME GUIDANCE.

Then your question should not have been asked in the first place.

Stack Overflow is not your personal help desk. We do not give "guidance". SO is not here to give you hints or clues to your homework questions.

The point of SO is to build an easily-searchable knowledge base. That way, if someone has a question similar to yours, they can see the answers and not have to ask a question themselves.

Giving incomplete answers to a question (i.e. guidance) does not help other people; it only helps you. We don't want to help *only* you. You should not ask a question here that you do not want to see answered *completely*.

Deleting your question because it might get you personally in trouble does not serve the needs of the *community*; it only serves your needs. We delete questions for reasons of violating community standards, or because of plagiarism or some such. We don't delete questions you ask just because you don't want to be accused of cheating.

You danced to the tune; now it's time to pay the piper.

Comment: Agreed. He couldve asked: "How can I repetedly ask a user for the same input until the input is valid using a console application" or something similar.

Answer (score 22):

I can tell you know that the flag is just going to be declined.  Questions aren't deleted here just because they're proof that you cheated on your homework; they're only deleted if we feel that the questions aren't useful (or won't become useful if kept around).

Comment: Before you say I cheated on my homework.. No I havent. Read the link and explain how I cheated my assignment.

Comment: @hassy786 If you haven't cheated on your homework then why would you have a problem with your teacher finding the question?

Comment: Not the teacher, the cheating system.. I do not want to get in the hassle of my work being declined because I asked a question online about a code.

Comment: @hassy786 If you really aren't cheating, then you should have nothing to fear from any cheating system, because you weren't cheating.

Comment: Doesnt change the fact I dont want to go through the hassle of being accused of cheating when I didnt cheat ...

Comment: @hassy786 Questions are also not deleted to save you the hassle of being falsely accused of cheating.

Comment: Maybe when giving answers, the person giving the answer should read they only want guidance and not the answer.

Comment: @hassy786 If you feel that a given answer doesn't properly answer the question, you're more than welcome to downvote that answer and/or comment to explain why it is not an acceptable answer to the question.  It is not grounds for deletion of the question though.

Comment: well, he would be free to do so if he had enough rep to.

Comment: Your missing the point.. I am not here to say that the answer I received was or was not good enough.. I am here to ask how I can get the question deleted so I do not get falsely accused of cheating when I had no intention of coming on this website FOR AN ANSWER OTHER THAN SOME GUIDANCE.

Comment: the answer is.... you don't. the most you can do is get it disassociated from your account, but i'm not sure if even that would happen.

Comment: I dont think there is any chance considering the reply I got was "I am not deleting these answers"

Comment: Which is a very unfair comment considering I explained everything as to why it SHOULD be deleted.

Comment: @hassy786 and you've been told why it shouldn't be. Also, maybe cool it with the *"falsely accused"* - you did, after all, publicly solicit help with what was supposed to be your own work.

Comment: help with if I should use a IF statement or a while loop.. Does not mean.. I am asking this question for you to tell me how to do my homework :)

Comment: Does any body want to guide me on how I should try and get it disassociated from my account?

Comment: After being declined to delete it obviously..

Comment: @hassy786 - I was the one who declined your request, as I usually do for questions with upvoted answers. To delete those answers would disrespect the time of those who answered, and would most likely [lead to a complaint](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334504/non-downvoted-question-with-accepted-answer-deleted-by-moderator) about the lost reputation from those answers. "I need to delete this because our school's plagiarism detector will use it against me" is something that we regularly see flags for, and we don't judge those questions any differently than any other deletion request.

Comment: I understand the fact that people have spent their time answering the question but my question did state not to give the answer which some people kindly didnt give the answer however few people decided to give the full answer instead which is what I didnt want, that is why I asked for it to be deleted. I did not have any intention of "cheating" before I posted it up therefore the answers I got, I did not expect them. Can I at least ask kindly if you could disassociate me from the question?

Answer (score 14):

When you write a question - you have to remember that this is not a help-site, we do not give 'guidance'. The question and answers are there now to **help other people** with a similar problem - they likely don't want hints, but rather, they would want sample code.

It is considerably selfish to post a question, get comprehensive answers (many you commended in the comments) and then demand we delete the question (and answers) just because you don't want any 'hassle' of being caught asking your homework question here.