# Edit review on question being discussed on Meta

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933237/should-i-use-an-if-statement-or-loops-to-re-request-input-from-the-user) question is being [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336431/asked-to-get-question-removed-but-havent-got-a-reply-yet) on Meta. It also just came up in my [Suggested Edit Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14020928) Queue. The edit basically removes all content, and replaces it with "Please Delete Me". I'm looking for advice on what to do with the edit. My first reaction, also confirmed by the above Meta post, is to reject the edit, but then what reason should I give?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The edit is vandalizing the post.  Reject it accordingly.  There is a reason specifically for vandalism.

If you see such an edit ever applied (either because it's erroneously accepted, or because the edit doesn't require approval), roll it back.  If the vandalism continues to be applied, flag for moderator attention so that they can address the vandalism.

Comment: Done, that what I thought I should do, but I just wanted confirmation