# Answer got deleted. Is it possible to retrieve it?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

One answer that i liked got deleted. It was on this question that i posted : 
[copying array of string pointers to a new array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221381/copying-array-of-string-pointers-to-a-new-array-in-c/41221502#41221502)

there were 2 answers and now is only one. I forgot to mark it as accepted answer.
is it possible to retrieve it ?

Comment: The owner deleted the answer.

Comment: Just asking, why you are interested in an already deleted answer?

Comment: At 20 rep you can start a chat with the author, and ask them to undelete it. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023

Comment: yes after the one i looked for got deleted, i marked second answer as accepted, just to save it

Comment: Marking it as accepted won't save it. Authors are always free to delete their answers

Comment: @StoryTeller Users cannot delete their own accepted answer.

Comment: @2501 - News to me. Although it seems to have been requested an ample amount of times

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, why do you think it was requested?

Comment: @2501 - Naturally because bad answers received a downpour of negative votes. And yet there are up voted answers which users wanted to delete for various reasons. Regardless, if a user can't improve their answer. They should be allowed to delete it to give the author and future readers a chance to examine better answers. This matter is hardly black and white.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Users with 10k+ reputation can see deleted answers, so technically yes, it can be retrieved. But this ability is intended for moderation purposes, not to violate a user's right to delete their answers without cause.

I don't see a good reason in this case why that right should be violated. [user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023) posted an answer on December 19th, 2016, and then deleted it approximately one day later. I doubt he deleted it simply because you didn't accept it. If he thought it was a valid and helpful answer to the question that was asked, he would not have deleted it.

Perhaps he will see this Meta question and reconsider his decision, or explain why he thought it best to delete his answer.

Comment: This answer disagrees with a post last summer that [screenshots of deleted answers are encouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/is-it-okay-to-show-a-screenshot-of-a-deleted-question-to-low-reputation-users).

Comment: I don't think so, @andy. Read [Alexei's rationale](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326225/366904): *"It is actually important for proper moderation - if question is deleted for reasons that need to be discussed every user of meta should be able to see the question - image is good way"* We aren't discussing the deletion of the post itself here. In fact, no moderation issue is up for discussion at all. Someone just came to Meta and asked if they could see the answer. It would be different if someone were asking why a moderator deleted it, why a flag was declined, etc.

Comment: But can the OP with low rep see a deleted answer to own question? The OP asked because of wanting to mark it up, not because can't use its content.

Comment: @weather No, I don't believe that is possible. I can't find an authoritative reference, but I'm pretty sure that you cannot see deleted answers to your question. You can only see your *own* deleted answers, i.e. ones that you posted.

Comment: @CodyGray, When we look at [10K privilege description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), it suggests that we ought to `Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team`. However, your answer seems to imply that a user's right to delete their answers without cause overrides the community's judgement about whether the deletion was harmful. Is this documented somewhere, or am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: Additionally, the restriction against deleting accepted answers seems to put the community's interests above the individual's rights in the case of answer deletion.

Comment: @merlin2011, It is a balancing act. There are conflicting rights both for the OP/everyone to see it, and the answering user's right to delete it. As it is, the system is designed such that a user can delete their own posts, unless the post is accepted. My point of view is that the design establishes a *default* for the side we should come down on. For a 10k+ user to just copy/show the answer is the opposite of that. It *should* be done in cases where the reason for the deletion is being discussed, so that the community can discuss it. But, *just* because some user wants to see it…not so much.

Comment: @makyen, how would you feel if the OP's meta question had implied that the answer should not have been deleted,  rather than merely asking to see it?

Comment: @merlin2011, Then we would be discussing a moderation issue. If the argument that the answer should not have been deleted was not frivolous, then it should be discussed (part of which is that the relevant post be visible for people to discuss it). So, yeah, if there was a reason that it should not have been deleted, then it should be made visible (e.g. a screenshot, or link to a cached/archived version). However, that *might* be mitigated by the author's reasons for deleting the answer. I have left a comment for the answer's author about the existence of this meta question.

Comment: @merlin Yes, that would be a complete misinterpretation of my answer. As Mayken commented already, that's a moderation issue. No one is questioning whether or not the answer should have been deleted. The question is, can I retrieve it after it has been deleted? The answer is no. That's how deletion works. And I don't think making a superficial change to this Meta question would change that, it would just be an abuse of the system. The answer was self-deleted by its author, not deleted by a moderator or a quorum of privileged users. There's no question about whether the deletion was valid.

Comment: The extended comment thread here explains one reason someone might want to delete an answer—they get tired of continuous pings and the need to explain and support it.