# Why was the question about revenge downvote deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, moderation

There was a question about a specific instance of commenting and revenge downvotes ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjXfY.jpg)) that was up for more than a day and generated some interesting answers and discussion. If it violated some rules I would like to know what those are, where are they stated and why wasn't it deleted sooner.

If it didn't violate any rules then why was it suddenly deleted?

Comment: related: [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601)

Comment: @gnat Somewhat, that was a reverse meta effect. Or maybe a meta meta effect or something.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, I want to know what the outcome of the discussion there was - *was* the offending user contacted by the mods? Is overt revenge downvoting something that they consider it their business to act on, or is their stance that we should just accept such things and not report them? There were competing opinions (by non-mods) on this on the now-deleted Meta question, with roughly equal support, and now we don't know the answer and will need to ask another question to find out. I guess once I'm done with work, I'll post a question and stir the pot yet further.

Comment: @MarkAmery don't forget to publicly blame and shame one or two users ... looking forward to your post.

Comment: @rene I'll look into how I can retaliate against Brad Larson for deleting the post, and perhaps identify somebody else whose actions I disagree with and poison their cat.

Comment: @MarkAmery Please do. I suggest you make it general, this way we might actually get a response. Asking the mods how they handled a specific case probably won't be productive.

Comment: I'm going to interpret the "please do" as responding to my first comment, there, @Oleg, although I got a laugh out of it appearing right after my cat-poisoning proposal.

Comment: @MarkAmery Yeah... I was just editing it. I'm a dog person but no... I don't condone cat poisoning.

Comment: @Oleg don't worry, I'll be sure not to poison a specific cat but instead to poison cats in general.

Comment: Let me find some cats ...

Comment: @MarkAmery - I escalated the whole situation to SE employees to review. Moderators cannot see individual votes, so I can't even prove that what was stated to have happened did. I *can* see that the two users involved were being serially downvoted by multiple people, and the discussion there was devolving into torches and pitchforks, so I decided to stop this and let impartial parties review the votes for invalidation. It's a textbook case of why public shaming on Meta [isn't healthy for the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289913/135615) and it probably should have been deleted earlier.

Comment: Not a good day for the SO community in my view. Reacting to revenge voting with revenge voting, I thought we were above that sort of thing (for the most part anyway)

Comment: Right, so the next time I downvote and someone asks for clarification, I'll comment "I didn't downvote, but it was probably because ..."

Comment: @BradLarson Good move, there was nothing constructive about it all. Best to let everyone cool down, take a deep breath, let everyone put things in perspective. Two things crossed my mind: [Somebody's wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/), and [Monthy Python's Witch Scene](https://youtu.be/yp_l5ntikaU).

Comment: @BradLarson:  Thoughts on an informal procedure then:  questions which explicitly name a user which is suspected of serial downvoting or retaliation should be immediately closed/deleted then?  (If so, that'd be *amazing*.  We don't need that kind of drama here.)

Comment: @Makoto if the response is indeed *immediate*, there's no reason for deletion - a mod has the power to edit the name out of the post without leaving a revision, which achieves the desired outcome. That option wasn't available to Brad in this case though (by the time he took action) since the offending user's name was already all over the place.

Comment: This question belongs to the *Meta Meta StackOverflow*... (rule #1, you don't talk about the Meta on the Meta). Of course, discussions about if this question actually belongs to the *Meta Meta StackOverflow* should be posted only on the *Meta Meta Meta StackOverflow*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Meta is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) for Meta.SO. It's within the purview of discussing how the site works or site policies and norms or getting feedback.

Comment: @MarkAmery In general, the outcome of a dispute between two individual users is none of our business. If you need to post any questions, then they should be about how *you* should behave in such a situation (either as one of the involved parties or as a bystander). I suspect such questions have already been asked for the most part. I've already posted a comment on the post Brad linked asking for clarification about how uninvolved users should handle it when an accusatory post *does* come along, but if I don't get an answer in the next few days, I'll post a specific question about it.

Comment: @jpmc26 it was a joke...

Comment: Interesting thread. Problem is, exactly **what** is being discussed? I get bits and pieces. But with no links to a question or comment, with no *relevant* links to pretty much anything... this question belongs as a "hot meta post" as is? Scripts gone crazy....

Comment: I want to know whether Stack Exchange are going to compensate me for the pitchfork that I now have no use for.

Comment: @dfd You had to be there in the thread. Be thankful you weren't.

Comment: Cases like this are why moderators and SE staff handle user specific issues instead of the community. Witch hunting is always bad if the goal is to stop bad behavior.

Comment: Yes, @Makoto, that is a sane practice. Any Meta question which focuses specifically on the behavior of an individual user should be deleted and replaced with a (private) moderator flag. Not only are moderators the only ones with the relevant information accessible to them, but private matters need to be kept private. I believe that we moderators were mistaken in not deleting the question in question earlier. If you want to discuss an issue *generally*, then that's a fine Meta question, but don't refer to a specific user. In this case, though, everyone already knows revenge downvotes aren't OK.

Comment: @jpmc26 I've said this on the previous question, but I'll say it again: no, knowing (and *advocating for*) policies followed by the moderators *is* our business. It's a large part of what Meta is for. We should not expect to be kept in the dark about what sort of behaviours merit moderator action.

Comment: @dfd [It's a good point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326226/603977). I've added a screenshot of the subject post -- with the poster's username redacted -- to the question here. You would need 10k rep to view the deleted question directly.

Comment: @MarkAmery If you have a question about a policy or norm and what *should* usually happen, sure. If something specifically happened to you personally, then yes, you have some business knowing what the outcome was. For something to which you were a bystanding third party, no, you really don't have a right to know about the outcome of that specific event. In particular, the moderators won't be able to divulge all the information used to decide on their course of action, so the community can't effectively police them. If you have evidence of moderator misbehavior, use Contact Us.

Comment: When the hornet's nest was buzzing the loudest right before Brad did the only right thing to do, I saw the single revenge downvote being described as a "revenge spree" by someone; at that point something broke inside of me. If you go that far to overstate something so you can condemn someone for their actions, you're out for blood. And that was pretty much the running theme in my opinion... fighting fire with even hotter fire. Makes you feel a little helpless.

Comment: @Gimby Describing what he did as 'single revenge downvote' is a gross understatement. He 1. Asked for an explanation 2. revenge downvoted **after he got what he asked for** 3. **bragged** about it 4. Had a very high rep. The combination of all those things is what got people riled up (especially the emphasized part). Also only a small number of people(probably 4-5) revenged the revenge downvote all the others were only discussing it.

Comment: @Oleg Yes, it's egregious, *assuming that all that was as we assumed it was*. No, it's not a spree. Gimby is correct that the particular comment they mentioned exaggerated what happened. Gimby is also correct that the situation was just escalating and getting worse on all fronts.

Comment: @jpmc26 **Assuming**??? What?! There is no assuming, we know exactly what happened, there was 99.99% certainty from the beginning and it's 100% after he admitted that it's exactly what happened. I didn't see that comment, I don't know why it was made, there was a spree of downvotes against the victim which we don't know were it came from maybe the user who made that comment assumed that it was from the same person. Gimby is not correct that it was made in order to condemn him, absolutely no exaggeration is required in order to do that.

Comment: @Oleg You are only making the situation worse by continuing to put your nose in it. Let it go. It was never your fight. Don't be dragged into it.

Comment: @Oleg [Be nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) I never took a side in this issue. I said from the moment I saw it that it should be handled privately. I trust our moderation team to handle the original actions that spawned the dispute. Please stop escalating this situation. My apologies for using the phrase, "put your nose in it." I wasn't able to think of better wording at the time. I really just meant don't involve yourself.

Comment: @jpmc26 Saying that it should be handled privately and trusting moderators to handle it is taking a side. I was referring to your previous comment "You are only making the situation worse by continuing to put your nose in it. Let it go. It was never your fight. Don't be dragged into it." applies to you as much as it applies to me. "Please stop escalating this situation." as well. It's not about the phrasing I don't mind, involving yourself and at the same time telling someone else not to involve himself is hypocritical.

Comment: @Oleg There is a massive difference between 1) telling people to take a problem to the appropriate venue and others to stay out of it, and 2) deciding who involved is wrong or right and attempting to "defend" or "punish" someone. The former deescalates the situation and moves it towards resolution. The latter results in increasing antagonization of an increasing number of people. This is demonstrable; there was a comment accusing me of defending one particular involved party (now deleted), which never happened. When I say not to involve yourself, I am referring to the latter behavior.

Comment: @jpmc26 The only thing the former does is antagonize people for yet another reason. This is demonstrable; there was a now deleted comment correctly accusing you of something that did happen(claiming that there is some doubt about what happened is defending him). Your response to me after I responded to Gimby was completely unnecessary, there was no reason for you to get involved and all it did was continue the discussion about this which was pretty much over. Same goes to your edit of the answer, all it did was bring this question to the top of the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158199/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-oleg).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The moderator who deleted it gave this reason:

[image: "As this question has resulted in targeted harassment of multiple parties, as well as the public shaming of people, I'm deleting it."]

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't see the reason when I go to the page, probably that's a 10k rep thing.

Comment: Ha! What are they planning to do about the everyday targeted harrassment that comes from nearly any Meta question in which an SO thread or user is mentioned and tens of readers from Meta pile on with downvotes?

Comment: How should I know? Sounds like a Meta question of its own, @underscore_d

Comment: @underscore_d see [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/839601)

Comment: It would be unsurprising if some users chose to flag the post as well, given the situation Brad noted.

Comment: Using this link 10k users can still read it all, get enraged and downvote one of those persons. Hopefully they are responsible enough or fear the votes review now.

Comment: The revenge downvoters have attracted moderator attention now. They certainly have every reason to fear the review. We will almost certainly be contacting people who have tried to take justice into their own hands. This was completely unacceptable, and in blatant violation of not only the site's ethos but the site's actual rules. @Vladimir

Comment: @CodyGray I think you try to make it look more scary than it really is. Worst case there will be brief cool-down suspensions handed to particularly persistent repeat offenders. Serial downvoting has never been considered "big abuse" and this is unlikely to change in foreseeable future

Comment: @gnat Yes, the first suspension duration is only 7 days. That's all you'd get for the first offense, and that's meant as little more than a warning and cool-down period. Repeat offenses get much longer suspensions: 30 days, and then 365 days. I don't know what you mean by "serial downvoting has never been considered 'big abuse'". Yes, it has. All vote fraud is suspension-worthy, which is about a bad as it gets here. We don't reach through the monitor and slap you. The devs tell me that feature's still 6-8 weeks out...

Comment: @CodyGray I have been serially voted down several times and at least twice I knew who did it (helps to have only answers so you can see a drop in the rep of the guy who voted down a bunch of these) and nothing happened to these guys. Whatever threats you dream of here, these are currently no more scary than Halloween masks, and will likely stay that way (not that I complain though)

Comment: It has been my experience that what looks like serial downvoting from the perspective of a *receiving* user is often not actually serial downvoting when investigated by a moderator and/or community manager (the latter of whom can actually see individual votes and who cast them). We get a fair number of flags from people claiming they're the recipient of serial DVs, even citing similar evidence and fingering specific users, but more often than not, their assumptions are incorrect. That's not to say you should stop flagging. We don't mind investigating, precisely *because* we take it seriously.

Comment: my cases I refer to in prior comment were definitely serial - I saw system reverted these in my rep tab and I saw rep of the downvoter getting recovered after -1s they've got while voting my answers. So, no, it is not that I am imagining things. Serial downvoting isn't dealt with as a big abuse and unlikely will ever be ...and unlikely that it even needs to be, if you take into account that automated vote reversal seems to become [stricter at repeat attempts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773)

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to link the question, given all the trouble it caused. I'm considering editing it out, but I didn't want to do so unilaterally without saying anything.

Comment: @underscore_d There's a big difference between a bunch of people voting on the one post presented to them, which is what usually happens, and those people voting on a bunch of random posts of a user to enact vigilante justice on them instead of letting mods handle it. The former is voting on content, or at least indistinguishable from voting on content, the latter user targeting - user targeting is against the rules. Maybe the meta effect is undesirable, but this is much worse.

Comment: @jpmc26 I've mod flagged to have the edit history redacted, so the link is wiped.

Comment: I don't mind that the link was edited out, I was on the fence about including it anyways. But the contents are only visible to 10k users, and they will be able to find the question in the 10k tools anyways for several days -- erasing it from history seems like overkill, @YvetteColomb. Deleting this entire question and answer would probably make more sense.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Eh, someone wanted to know why it disappeared. Given how upset people were, it's probably not bad for there to be *some* indication why it went away. I just thought it would be better not to link to it, so people wouldn't go find out all the details and then know who to target and all that. I was kinda on the fence about editing it out; I just thought it was probably better.