# Can moderators see a user's votes?

Tags: support, voting, moderation

A line in a question posted by a moderator, recently, caught my eye:

> [image]

That line was edited out by a (normal) user, but the edit was rolled back by another user.

I've always been under the impression that only those with database access can determine who voted for what.

Is that incorrect?

Or simply put:
What can moderators see, in regard to votes?

Comment: What sort of votes? I think moderators can see close votes.

Comment: I was under your same impression there. That mods can only see patterns, but cannot see who voted. I don't know if this was hyperbole, or not thought through, but I was under the impression that statement was 100% incorrect for an elected moderator. (that is indeed with the assumption the line refers to downvotes)

Comment: @PeterJ: The context of that line implied up / downvotes. Or at least, votes that require "moderator" status to be visible.

Comment: What's the context? What question was this line in?

Comment: @apaul full sentence "The group of regulars who pile on in the meta comments and downvotes on meta and which will occasionally trickle into the main site. (I'm a mod I can see the votes.)"  and this is the question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366969/stack-overflow-is-not-a-welcoming-site-when-will-the-community-accept-that-and

Comment: Couldn't that be talking about the up-down split that any user with sufficient rep can see?

Comment: @apaul: That doesn't require modhood, though.

Comment: In context it could have been used for emphasis, as in "Of course I can see downvotes vs upvotes, I'm a mod after all"

Comment: @apaul: Argh, stop giving us more reasons to find Yvette's statement confusing and unnecessary!

Comment: @gnat Yea, sortof. Something could've changed since '14. Especially since that statement came from a mod. This question is mostly about that statement. I'm not gonna "accept" the dupe immediately, but if the votes have it, I won't vote to re-open...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Moderators can see patterns of votes, but they cannot see individual votes on posts.

Only SE employees with database access can see actual votes.

Comment: Beyond this, what I think Yvette was referring to are incidents of serial downvoting (that we can see patterns for) that we can trace back to arguments on Meta. Meta disagreements can get pretty heated at times, and that sometimes spills over into retaliatory downvoting on the main site. It also is fairly common for someone who is being publicly called out for behavior in a Meta post to face vigilante-style serial downvoting on the main site.

Comment: @BradLarson that is a very fair way of seeing it, and potentially what was meant by Yvette (it's the only thing that would make sense). The way it was phrased makes it sound more like "I know the usual meta crew that answers most of the new users questions here also go in and downvote the posts". Maybe people are just too sensitive and itching to pick a fight since "the blog", but I definitely read it this way, which I found... odd.

Comment: So. someone participates in a very active meta post, then gets a lot of downvotes on main? Can't we all see that or even automate it with a scraper?

Comment: @ivarni: See the meta effect? Yes, the meta effect does everything to make itself as conspicuous as possible. But only moderators can identify those who enacted or at least contributed to that effect.

Comment: @BoltClock so... you CAN see who voted then? That statement just seems even more confusing. I get that seeing "hey this user posted on meta, and then 50% of his questions got a downvote" is easy, and probably even easier from where you sit. But can you correlate who actually voted, or is it just conjecture? I was under the impression you could see "anonymised user 1 voted on this, this, this, and this". Without ANY clue who anonymised user 1 is (short of who spoke on the meta question). Is it actually different? (maybe it is and you guys can't share, I'unno)

Comment: @ivarni - Even in [this recent case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358729/why-was-the-question-about-revenge-downvote-deleted-by-a-moderator#comment528040_358729), the existing serial voting script let a lot of that through. Moderators could see most of the picture as to what happened, but we still need to escalate to employees to verify our suspicions and act on any clear targeting. Could the automated systems for this be improved? Certainly, and I know Shog9 has talked about some ideas that are being tested internally. For now, it's a pretty manual process with levels of review.

Comment: @Patrice: As Taryn said, we can see patterns of votes. That's why we can identify and discipline users for serial and/or targeted voting. We can't see which posts they voted on, which votes were cast when, etc, and in fact we can *only* see patterns of votes from users with a substantial number of votes, which means users who haven't voted on a specific user all that many times will remain completely hidden from us (because frankly we don't need to know until a certain point). I am just as confused as you are by Yvette's statement.

Comment: @BoltClock ok, makes more sense. I was under a complete wrong impression then, and this clarification makes it seem a lot more sensible. Thx for taking a second to clarify :)

Comment: Hmm.. serial downvotes on main as fallout from meta 'discussions'..  I don't do such things, but Imma going to check out my own votes/meta activity, for sure.

Comment: @MartinJames Unfortunately it happens much more often that we'd like.

Comment: @Taryn I get the ordinary 'meta effect' after someone brings a terribru question to meta in an attempt to get.. something.  I get it, but I don't actually do it, specifically to avoid nasty and unwarranted escalations.  If sundry non-main-question-related serial downvoting happens too, I will be dismayed, (again:).

Comment: What do you mean by patterns of votes?

Comment: @revo: I'm pretty sure that level of detail isn't supposed to be public information.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate. I agree with that, but as Cerbrus pointed out, something might have changed since the dupe was asked. Could the answer be edited to add the rationale why even diamond moderators can't see votes? I understand the rationale myself, but adding it would make the answer more timeless.