# Why was this spam flag declined by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I'm a bit confused about why my spam flag on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611822) was

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

- The post's original title was "Free Unlimited Cloud Hosting"
- Its content was more of a basic tutorial than a question
- The post body contained what appeared to be the name of a hosting product, though it didn't contain any hyperlinks
- In the 11 minutes between when it was asked and deleted

  - It was aggressively downvoted to -11, and
  - Two users suggested in the comments that the post was spam and were upvoted
- When it was deleted it was

  > marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown

  by Community

Does not containing hyperlinks disqualify it from being spam, or is there something else I missed that tips the balance?

[Screenshot of the original revision for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcbwE.png)

Comment: *it contains hyperlink, check code. Mod went with let's presume good faith but most likely it was wrong decision*

Comment: Perhaps [there was an autoflag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317987/5067311)...

Comment: Was it declined before or after the question was deleted?

Comment: I've let the mod know about this post - although it looks like spam flags were declined at the start, but others approved 30 seconds or so later. So might have been a change of mind after looking again or something...

Comment: Most likely just a misclick by the mod.   Maybe they meant to approve, maybe they thought they were clicking the button for a different post's flags, etc.

Comment: @Cœur What are your concerns about flagging policy that would be answered by seeing the question?  What about the call is "edgy"?  All of the details that are actually relevant are all already in the meta question.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, that's a URL, not a hyperlink. I'm not sure if that's a meaningful difference in how SO handles spam, but there is no clickable link in the post.

Comment: You'd have to wonder a bit if spam that is so incredibly clumsy is still spam.  Erm, no, that didn't last long, it is spam.  Only saving grace is if it could fool rene then it could fool a mod.  Not a problem, it is gonzo and the account is destroyed.

Comment: @Chris you are right sorry an URL :), but I have never heard that you need some clickable to be consider spam, spam is just spam. I'm neither not sure yet why if it is kids promoting their stuff we should not flag; in hope for them to become nice community members? A more responsabile kid maybe should have consider to delete after the first comments.  Anyway I think it's just 1 of those cases with mods handling hundreds of flag each day where they get it wrong and could just as well approve it or at least hit dispute.

Comment: @Chris Adding a screenshot so <10k users can participate in the Meta question [is a good thig](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/is-it-okay-to-show-a-screenshot-of-a-deleted-question-to-low-reputation-users/326226#326226), not an evasion. Only things to watch out for really are offensive material and dragging another user's dirty laundry into public.

Comment: Oye, it was **declined** for me as well for same post. I just checked it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was the mod that declined the first bunch of flags, then realised my mistake and flagged it as spam as more flags were pouring in. I also nuked the account (at 13:11:58, 18 seconds after spam-flagging the post).

At least, that's what I think must've happened, because I *can't actually recall this specific post*.

At any rate, yes, this was spam. It has a spammy title. It has a description stating that they'll show you how easy it is to set up a server with their free unlimited service. There is a total lack of an actual question. The account probably offered more evidence to convince me that nuking it was a good idea, but I didn't make note of exactly what I found.

So, hereby apologies that I declined a valid flag. The post must've thrown me for a bit.

Comment: *The post must've thrown me* ... for the train? Overboard? Bad karma? Off? Up? Down? I guess it is *off* missing but one mistake per day is all I can bare ...

Comment: @rene: *throw* -> verb, meaning *to confuse or shock someone or cause difficulty for them*. *To be thrown* means you were confused by something. See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw

Comment: That is confusing then ...

Comment: Thanks for following up, and no need to apologize. These things happen. I just wanted to make sure I hadn't misunderstood the purpose of the spam flag. One of my favourite things about SO is how accessible the moderators are.

Comment: @rene: or if you if you like Wiktionary: [*(transitive, informal) To confuse or mislead. The deliberate red herring threw me at first.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/throw#Verb)

Comment: @rene this is a professional site, please don't bare anything.

Comment: @rene Could you say that... Martijn's use of the word "thrown" threw you for a bit?

Answer (score -21):

As the community user deleted **and** locked the post binding spam flags have been cast (thanks BoltClock) so a mod is involved. It only needs one spam flag to get the hide content effect.

I can understand you reached for the spam flag but on closer inspection that might have been the wrong call.

Visiting https://rekuza.000webhostapp.com

allows me to do [setdata.php?key=foo&value=bar](https://rekuza.000webhostapp.com/setdata.php?key=suakey&value=seuvalue) (yes, the redirect result they send is broken)

and then [getdata.php?key=foo](https://rekuza.000webhostapp.com/getdata.php?key=foo) (but that looks like it is broken now and open for a [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Their "question" was about these features using some Android activity.

So yes, your spam flag was declined correctly, the lack of a link to an actual website/paywall should have been a first sign something was off. The question itself was poor, if a question at all and I doubt it was salvageable so to that extent we didn't lose value but we might have lost a potential new user.

As the jury is obviously still out on this one, the website url is [added to Smokey](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43817022#43817022) just in case I got this totally wrong ...

Comment: hmm are you sure Rene, too me it seems like a post promoting a "free" service "ReKuZa Cloud Service" with some code on how to access it. User could be confused what SO is, but yeah that's a lot of promotional text.. or maybe someone just trolling...

Comment: Well @PetterFriberg I know you and I are in the *we've seen all spam by now camp* and I give you that the question had all the ingredients to be a spam attempt. But landing on that page, fiddling a bit with the urls all I can conclude this are probably some enthusiastic kids that need a stern talking to from YCS then anything else. But we'll see how this ends. Maybe the mod will reveal stuff that makes me call defeat ;)

Comment: maybe. How do you conclude that user self deleted and was not nuked by mod?, anyway it's harsh to decline these (if user nuked by mods that have more info it should be approved), if not a disputed maybe would have been more smooth.

Comment: I didn't see Jon;s comment until I posted and decide to not change it too much (added the word expect) but you're right: I don't know what happened there but self-delete seemed plausible until Jon came by ...

Comment: I'm all in for presume good faith, but my gut says it's time for the paper bag.

Comment: The post was both locked and deleted by Community. So, binding spam flags were cast.

Comment: @rene, sure, it's _possible_ that this was just a very badly asked question. But don't you think visiting the site and playing with the response it sends is a lot to expect of users for something that looks so spammy? I have to squint _very_ hard to see anything even approaching a question here; I'm not sure how you've concluded that it's asking how to use those features from an Android activity. And not including a hyperlink could easily be an attempt at avoiding spam detection. Is it meaningfully better to include the name of a product in plain text than to link to it?

Comment: @clive I don't think trying to find the link and then visiting is a lot to expect. And I'm well aware about spam, spam seeds and their various tactics. I'm simply not convinced *this* particular question is one. I admit I had to use a lot of detective work, as I searched SOCVR, SOBotics, Charcoal and Metasmoke to see if I could find earlier occurances of that site or user. Also the Google cache page only showed me the few comments that hint on spam but that is about it. I'm not 100% convinced and given the red-flag penalty of -100 for the OP I think I should be 100% convinced.

Comment: @rene, of course this is subjective. But IMO this post doesn't contain a question; as far as I can tell its only purpose is to demonstrate (poorly) how to use a particular service. I don't know for sure that the OP is affiliated with the service, but I think that's a reasonable guess. Based on Jon's comments it looks like other users also flagged the post as spam and had their flags approved. I'm still comfortable with my flag.

Comment: @Chris OP is affiliated with the service. The [Google's cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jVUUTQQfE7wJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611822/free-unlimited-cloud-hosting+) shown Zek as the username, which is the name shown in the linked URL "*Created by Zek*", and a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ZekIsKek/rekuzakloud) that was created at the same day. So, yeah... it's a spam although it needs a further research to see the relation, which might trip mods.

Comment: @AndrewT. of course they are, their question is about it ... and that github repo ... come on... this are just kids ...

Comment: I kind of enjoy the idea that if it is kids (we evaluate how crappy the service is), we don't spam flag it, we try to teach'em some sense instead; but I guess this will not fly on meta.

Comment: Maybe this wasn't spam. BUT 1) I don't know where this idea that the fact we can't prove affiliation makes it okay to post ads on SO. That's ridiculous. 2) That you're willing to first dig up and then actually visit a sketchy-looking URL like that does not oblige everyone else to do so.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm not advocating that posting something that smells like an ad is OK. So yes, agree with the ridiculous. As for 2), I'm always a bit curious when "spam" goes wrong so for my own amusement I venture a bit to see what they screwed up. That is my *defect* not something I expect anyone else to do.

Comment: Martijn says it was spam. This raises the obvious question: who is rene working for?