# Wrong answers on SO question with high SERP

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

Ran into a question on Stack Overflow where the correct answer is accepted, but the votes are overwhelmingly for the patently wrong one. I don't have the reputation to flag (or comment), and another Meta question suggested to post here instead. So:

[Redirect URL with hash using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185188/redirect-url-with-hash-using-htaccess-file)

Don't know if the question was changed after the fact, or there was an attempt at malicious manipulation, but given it is a top search result for redirecting with fragments it seems quite a disservice to the community to leave such a confusing set of answers as is. Could a mod clean it up?

Comment: Score 42 & no accept for "the patently wrong one"? I'm underwhelmed. Check out [this score-6336 accepted incomplete unclear partly wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/3404097).

Comment: Don't anybody change the accepted answer @philipxy linked, it's a masterpiece!!

Comment: @bad_coder I'd appreciate it if you could explain that comment. I hope for your sake that it's sarcastic.

Comment: @philipxy don't know if I was being sarcastic, but the joke in your link was so good it deserved a reaction.

Comment: With my 25-years-of-web-programming hat on: **that answer is not wrong** and in fact, the other answer is wrong. **Browsers really do not send hash fragments to the server**. That it is possible to rewrite URLs with a hash fragment is nice and all, but pointless if your goal was for browsers to be redirected with the hash fragment intact.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That seems to correspond with what OP says. OP claims that the accepted answer is correct whereas the most upvoted one is wrong.

Comment: @Ivar: ah, yes, I should have read more thoroughly. However, the other answer is also, technically, not wrong. Just.. very ignorant of the fact that hash fragments are not normally included.

Comment: @MartijnPieters By that logic answering "how do I cure my cancer" with "homeopathy" is also technically not wrong, since it would be right if homeopathy worked.
Depressing hilarity aside, point remains that it is confusing to anyone who finds themselves on that page and wastes hours trying to implement the most upvoted answer, since that often IS the most correct answer. Funny to me that questions are so harshly squashed on Stack but bad answers are not.

Comment: @frEEk that’s community voting. Add your own vote, I added mine. There is also a comment on that answer pointing out there are issues.

Comment: SERP = [search engine results page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page). But "high search engine results page" does not make sense. Do you mean [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) (or SEO ranking)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Meant it was a top result for a search on redirecting fragments, hence stands a good chance of being seen by our fellow programmers and wasting hours of their time while they bang their heads against their desks following a bad claim.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't flag a wrong answer. This is because moderators, while knowledgeable, are not SME's in everything, and will not judge the technical accuracy of an answer.

To me the answer looks wrong, but if indeed the answer happens to be malicious, then mod flag and **explain *why* the answer is malicious/dangerous**. Make it clear exactly what about this answer is dangerous.

Here's what you can do if the answer is just a wrong answer:

1. Downvote, and write a comment explaining *why* it is wrong. [This has already been done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185188/redirect-url-with-hash-using-htaccess-file#comment47283259_14962116).
2. If the answer is malicious, you may want to either change the code, or add a warning into the post (in your case, suggest an edit).

To quote from [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318726/12708583):

> You can also always add a warning, like this:
>
> DANGER: WILL NUKE YOUR HARD DRIVE (and may even brick your system)

Other than that, there is nothing you can do, really. Typically wrong/malicious answers tend to garner downvotes once folks are informed that it *actually is* a wrong/malicious answer.

Comment: The answer is not incorrect however. Nor is it dangerous. It is just... missing an important detail: browsers don’t send hash fragments so the fact that Apache _could_ be told to not drop a fragment is just very very ineffective.

Comment: Adding a warning to a "yes it can be done" answer to say that it infact cannot seems a bit crazy to me. What value would answers have that disagree with themselves?

Comment: "then mod flag" Unfortunately that was the core reason for my posting in Meta: I don't have the reputation to flag. Or downvote. Or do ANYTHING but ask a question (which is somewhat ironically misread by half the commenters, just like the question I am posting about. C'est la vie)

Comment: @frEEk then gain the reputation required to do so. Just write one good answer and make one good edit. You can then comment and mod flag if neccessary (which in this case, it doesn't seem to be as the answer is not malicious)