# Is it justifiable to downvote a question because of the asker's intent?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I recently came across this question, asking if it's possible to display `https://` in the browser's address bar when the page is not actually served over an encrypted connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214011/is-it-possible-to-display-https-in-the-url-without-using-https (now deleted, you need 10K rep to view)

The question was heavily downvoted, but I think the reason for most of these downvotes is that the OP seems to be trying to make their site look secure when it really isn't.

A quote from one of the answers:

> No: you can change the path, but not the domain (because that would be very bad. **And you're getting downvoted for that)**

An answer even said that the OP was getting downvoted because it would be very bad if it was possible to do what they asked about.

That question is a valid question, and it seems that it's being downvoted mostly because it seems that the asker might be doing something shady. Is it a valid reason to downvote a post?

---

People do this on other Stack Exchange sites as well: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/how-do-i-remove-a-signature-from-a-photo

The question on Photo.SE was downvoted not because of the post's quality but because it's "wrong" and "a bad idea."

Comment: Yes, you can downvote any question or answer for any reason *you* find appropriate, as long as it's based on the actual content of the post (and not the person who asked it).

Comment: Some might argue that downvoting based on the asker's intent is in fact downvoting based on the person and not the content...

Comment: @BoltClock: But if a person I _really_ like posts a question like that, I'd still downvote it based on the question's (asker's) intent. Intent != person.

Comment: I would maybe downvote for the lack of research and context this question shows. I have learned long ago to not condemn possibly malicious questions on SO, the nature of the site simply makes it the place for such questions to actually be asked. Its valuable knowledge - yes to people who want to exploit the knowledge, but also to people who plug the exploits or developers who want to prevent from exposing them.

Comment: Related, but maybe not a dupe since it's unclear whether the original question was actually malicious: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou

Comment: And also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287327/how-can-we-discuss-malicious-code

Comment: @Cerbrus: That's why I said "some" and not "everyone". You say tomato, I say tomato... (OK maybe you and I say it the same way but you get my point)

Comment: @BoltClock yea, I was just nitpicking :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you *really* be sure that their intent is to perpetrate as if they're a secure site when they're not?  From their question I don't pick up any actual malice.

> I was wondering it it was possible to have a https site with out it being secure or encrypted?

If nothing else, this question is misguided - HTTPS relies on a different protocol than HTTP and has (some) checks in place to prevent this kind of spoofing - but there's no intent that I can plainly see from the OP that they wish to defraud or phish.

The general convention is to **vote based on the usefulness or quality of the question**, and while I don't really see myself upvoting it anytime soon, I don't see myself downvoting it either, since I don't see any real rationale to do so.  Others may disagree and elect to vote on it based on their perception of it *instead* of its usefulness or quality.  Again, I wouldn't, but we can't really stop them from doing that.

Comment: I disagree. I downvoted the question precisely because I do not think that it is useful. It has nothing to do with my perception of its legitimacy or the asker's intent.

Comment: @CodyGray:  You didn't disagree.  You did exactly what I believe you should do when downvoting.

Comment: Fair enough. I meant that I disagreed with *"I don't see myself downvoting it either, since I don't see any real rationale to do so."* The way I read that, it was like you were saying there isn't a good rationale for downvoting it. I disagree with that, although I do agree with the larger point.