# Received request through Stack Overflow to write malicious code

Tags: discussion, users, behavior, code-vulnerabilities

I found [an unorthodox question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490057/weird-youtube-js-api-code) (this question appears to have been deleted just after I posted this meta question, but our chat still exists [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/146378)) that seemed harmless enough, so I offered my help, since I was under the assumption that the asker was the owner of a site that had been exploited.

It turns out the asker intended to reproduce the malicious code in the question, and gave me an unsolicited offer via email, requesting the full code from me in exchange for payment.

This has never happened to me before, and I obviously declined, but I do not know if this behavior is acceptable on Stack Overflow, so I'm asking for guidance as to how I am supposed to handle a situation like this now, and in the future.

For reference, the email I received from him is as follows:

> Hey dude,
>
> we was chatting on stackoverflow like 20 mins ago! Im interesting to have the full code. Let me know if you can complete it and i can pay you! Please send me how much it will cost if its possible!
>
> Thanks!

#### Update

It has been [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350544/received-request-through-stackoverflow-to-write-malicious-code#comment481046_350544) that my concern was unclear. I do not care about the fact I was emailed (though I also was not aware it was publicly available, so if someone could give me a tip on how to resolve that, great), but I **am** concerned that a user on Stack Overflow attempted to request malicious code for personal use, and that is the issue up for discussion.

Comment: if I had my email publicly available I would expect to only receive nice, good faith, polite and positive mails into my inbox. Especially from strangers

Comment: @gnat I assume that was sarcasm, but two things: 1) I was not aware my email was publicly available 2) my concern is not about being emailed, but the fact that a user was requesting to reproduce malicious code

Comment: I see. Consider [edit]ing these details into your post to help readers abstain of stupid comments (or worse, answers) like mine. :) BTW have you seen this question: [How can we discuss malicious code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287327/839601)

Comment: @gnat yes I glanced at that after posting this, but it doesn't really pertain because in this case the asker appears to want to be **using** the code rather than **mitigating** it.

Comment: Just inform him your payment is 20k bitcoins. Then he will quit himself. Don't help such people. Once they caught by any agency, you too may get into trouble

Comment: As for finding your email address, it's not very hard. You link to your github projects from your SO profile and all your commits are tagged with your address. If you click the link for a single commit and add `.patch` to the URL you'll see the raw data. You can then check if that address matches the one they sent an email to.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, the guy simply found your email by googling around based on your SO profile.  (This seems to come up a lot on this meta site ... "Why the hell did SO give away my email?!?!"  "Oh, sorry, it was on these other 15,000 web pages which clearly state my nickname, name, email, social number, etc"   :)  )

Comment: _"Hey dude, we was chatting [...]"_... awesome.

Comment: @canon but they was. ;)

Comment: There is always the chance that they are a benign or benevolent user (or a future security strategist) who just wants to understand what the code is doing to understand how to prevent such attacks or learn more about them.

Comment: To be fair, @gnat, my email address is publicly available and I have only received nice, good faith, polite, and positive mails. It is quite incompatible with my general cynicism.

Comment: Is there a place to report such a thing?

Comment: I downvoted. I don't think this question has much to do with SO specifically. Besides removing your email from the system, what else could _possibly_ be done on SO's end to resolve this? I don't think a 'dont send us messages' note would do much.

Comment: Where do you see the user suggesting he wants to use the code? A quick look through the stuff shown paints more of a naïve-but-innocent picture in my head, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem like a request for writing malicious code, more like a request to deobfuscate something.

Comment: why even report it? Just deal with it (ignore) like you do any other request of that sort. Why get SO involved?

Comment: @Crt I'm not really _reporting_ it per se, but I wanted to get SO involved because I was unclear on the policies we have, regarding the request of malicious code. And to those of you naive enough to claim that the user didn't indicate they wanted to use the code, you obviously haven't considered that no one would offer payment unless they wanted to use it. When I look at the conversation, it's pretty clear to me that the user comes off as a script kiddie more than anything, and wants to promote some sort of youtube channel through _spam_, which is _illegal_ in some jurisdictions.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Think if SO wasn't there and that same person asked the same request what would you do? I think that's how it should be handled. Why give SO another job when you can handle it in the most powerful and quickest way. SO should be working on stuff you and I cannot deal with. In terms of the legal responsibilities, that's a good concern and I think the answer below got to the point on that.

Comment: Maybe related: [Should asking for malicious code be on topic?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/should-asking-for-malicious-code-be-on-topic)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Stack Overflow holds no responsibility for the content contributed by you, the asker, or anyone else. Further, Stack Overflow is not responsible for any external correspondence between its users, such as email, although the community team *does* try to provide support in situations such as harassment (which doesn't seem to be the case here, just a harmless request for something that's uh, not so harmless).

So the question of whether this particular situation is acceptable on Stack Overflow doesn't really have an answer since it happened through email. That said:

- Questions offering payment to be answered are not acceptable, not even in the form of reputation bounties except through the bounty system, subject to all its restrictions.
- Questions asking for help writing malicious code [have been discussed previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287327/how-can-we-discuss-malicious-code). These should be treated on a case-by-case basis, but the majority of such questions are poorly written anyway and should probably just go away as quickly as possible.
- Comments asking for help writing malicious code should be flagged as not constructive, for the simple reason that comments aren't meant for helpdesk sessions (which is why you moved the comments to chat to begin with).

How should you handle such situations? I don't see anything wrong with personally declining their request. But even if you did write Stack Overflow about the request this user made, I'm not sure there's much action to be taken (maybe a gentle talking-to, but even that would be a stretch).

Comment: Perhaps a relevant question might be that if the user had asked for a link to the full code in the comments or in the StackOverflow chat, and @Patrick Roberts had complied and posted that code or a link to it in the chat or comments, would that be in line with StackOverflow policy?

Comment: I second @AdrianSmith's comment, and I apologize if I focused too much on the email. I thought the conversation alone was evidence enough to suggest that the user intended to reproduce / deobfuscate the code for personal use, whether it was to resell or use the code themselves. And while I agree declining and / or ignoring the request might be sufficient in some random forum, I thought maybe Stack Overflow might have some sort of code of ethics that prohibits users from making these sort of requests, considering (in my opinion) a clear intent of misuse.