# Some posts with snippets do not have a run button - Why?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Considering this post (an answer): [`scrollTop()` jQuery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808614)

I couldn't see the <kbd>Run Snippet</kbd> button. Any reason?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the fact that the post has a score <= -3. The layer on top (adding the "faded" effect) is hiding the snippet.

Comment: @Tunaki Woah... Could it be? Are you sure about this? Haven't seen such a "feature" then.

Comment: The mind boggles. Some time ago, several users were unsuccessfully trying to figure out why a Stack Snippet in a particular post couldn't be made to work. Perhaps _this_ was the reason. There should be a bug report or feature-request to have the `[Run snippet]` button replaced by a notice that the Snippet has been disabled in this situation.

Comment: @NisseEngström That's a good one. `:)`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After some digging, this is not a bug. The Stack Snippet is explicitly disabled when the post reaches a score of -3 or lower (i.e. when the post is greyed out), which is the case here.

Quoting [Haney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2420979/haney) from [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0/270981#comment92448_270981) and [this one also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0/270981#comment92885_270981):

> Fixed this by disabling heavily downvoted Snippets, which also gives users control over disabling malicious snippets.

> it might be "overkill" but it adds a layer of user-controlled security. Snippet is malicious? Downvote it and it becomes un-runnable. Best option we could come up with after discussions.

This was tested in [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270251/1743880) on the Stack Snippet sandbox.

Comment: Are malicious snippets frequent/ever occurring?

Comment: @Matsmath I haven't heard of any. Since the JavaScript code in snippets is executed in other domain than Stack Overflow, it's not possible to exploit it for XSS. A snippet could be malicious only if it was exploiting a browser bug.

Comment: @Gothdo It's possible to be malicious without exploiting something. When the snippet feature was first released, there was a user posting snippets that just draw inappropriate things on the screen when you run them.

Comment: @Gothdo [It's possible to do phishing attacks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287238/1529630).

Comment: Wow, what a horrible design decision

Comment: I feel like this feature should be published somewhere, this is the first I've ever heard of this. I just encountered it in the wild and searched around to check if the "bug" had happened before, turns out it's a feature instead.