# Add notice to disabled Stack Snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, user-interface

I recently learned that [Stack Snippets are disabled automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331820/) when a post's score drops below -2.

This can cause confusion when the Snippet mysteriously fails to work for no apparent reason.

Instead of removing the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button altogether, it should be replaced by a notice that it has been disabled, possibly containing a link to a Meta post that explains why.

Comment: An alternative option is to gray out the button and provide a tooltip explaining the reason for it.

Comment: @jpmc26: Currently, there is no button at all. Follow the link and check out the screenshot in the question.

Comment: You should post this as answer @jpmc26, so we can vote on it.

Answer (score 6):

[jpmc26](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) on Aug 9 '16 at 20:37 wrote in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331970/add-notice-to-disabled-stack-snippets#comment381341_331970):

> An alternative option is to gray out the button and provide a tooltip explaining the reason for it.