# Which flag should I have used for this question, given my concerns about it?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41766570/3964881) while reviewing:

> ## WebApi, Wcf , WebService

> ### How to know weather a URL is of WebApi, WCF or WebService. How can we identify a given url.
>
> https://gatabcdef.maxpolicy.com/apiabcgm/sb/soa/MliCreditu/v3

> [web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-services) [wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf) [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api)

It has a bad question in the title, and then a link, without any real explanation. I wasn't sure whether the link was related to the title, or whether it might be spam, or something malicious. If it were just a bad question, I'd have gone for "Too Broad" - but I was more concerned that the link might be spam, malicious, or both. But I didn't want to just flag it as spam because it wasn't definitely the case - and I've had a spam flag declined before when the post was spam, but it wasn't immediately obvious (it was later deleted).

I've seen several posts and comments here on meta recently from mods saying to use a custom flag rather than a standard one when you need to give more information, so I did so, with the message *"I'm not sure if this is spam or just a really terrible question, and I don't really want to click on the link to find out in case it's something malicious. Figured I'd better flag it up in case it's something dodgy."* This was quickly declined, with a message telling me to familiarise myself with the standard flags.

I flag quite a bit (and have a positive track record) but very rarely use custom flags - mostly because they're rarely necessary, but also in part because I feel unsure about when it's OK to use them. I guess there's a bit of a gap in my knowledge on what to do in a situation like this, and when custom flags are and aren't OK, and I'd like to improve on this.

What should I have done in this case, given I wasn't sure about the nature of the post? I'd also appreciate any guidance on when it is and is not suitable to use custom flags.

Comment: Look like spam to me, considering it consists of little more than a link to a dodgy site. But some moderators have an unusual definition of spam, so such a flag is likely to be declined.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the edit - didn't know you could get the tags to show up in a post like that!

Comment: If you're unsure if a post needs to be flagged or closed and which exact reason to use you can always ask for guidance in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). If that will be your first message there you might want to look at their [tour](http://socvr.org/tour) and [FAQ](http://socvr.org/faq)

Comment: @rene - That's not a resource I knew about - thanks! I'll have a read, and bookmark it for future use. Might be worth you adding that as an answer to help other people in future who might have similar questions and come across this?

Comment: I *think* the asker was presenting that as an example of a URL, wondering how to tell what type of URL it is. It doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Funny ... I did something very similar awhile back (custom flagged something that looked ... *wonky*) with a similar custom message and it got marked helpful even though the post only ended up being closed as "unclear" because it wasn't actually spam/trolling (it just looked like it!).  It might just depend on the mod you got.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a mod and I'm not citing any official policy, so my thoughts here don't carry any real weight. But I would like to express my opinion.

I think a custom flag is *completely* appropriate. It's been explained numerous times that flagging for moderator attention is for when the standard, built in mechanisms for the site aren't enough the handle the job. In this case, the link is pretty dodgy, and the question itself doesn't offer any real value. Someone needs to make a determination if that link is malicious or not, or kill the post entirely after deciding it's not worth finding out. Ordinary users shouldn't be expected to click potentially malicious links to find out if they're malicious. And the ordinary process for deleting a question probably wouldn't work fast enough if it really is a malicious link, particularly since ordinary users are discouraged from "organized voting" activities; a malicious link should be deleted *as soon as possible*. So asking a mod to either determine if the link is malicious or nuke the post is a useful course of action.

Again, this is solely my opinion, and I welcome any opinions or feedback from moderators that might suggest I'm wrong. But instructing a user to send something this suspicious through the normal channels seems very unwise.

Comment: If the question itself doesn't offer any real value, a close vote will suffice. A custom flag that requires a moderator's time just because you don't know where a link leads is inappropriate.

Comment: @KenWhite If we were talking about a JSFiddle link, I would agree. Some random who-knows-where link that looks like it's straight out of a phishing attack e-mail? Not so much.

Comment: When did the moderators become the *protect anyone from links they shouldn't click* force? Normal closure (followed by deletion) will get the link off the site. Moderators have better things to do than deal with custom flags for questionable links, like...you know, *real moderation*.

Comment: @KenWhite I can literally think of nothing better for a mod to do than reduce the likelihood someone would be exposed to malicious content from SO. Such content is *worse* than poorly asked questions, *worse* than argumentative users, *worse* than spam, *worse* than any other kind of post. It's not like SO has never had malicious content on it before; it [*does* happen](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287482/1394393) from time to time. And it would even be appropriate for actual malicious content to be eradicated *beyond* what normal deletion does, which still leaves 10k users exposed.

Comment: Except you don't **know** it's malicious content. If someone determines that it is, *then* a custom flag would be appropriate. Speculation that it *looks funny and might be malicious* is simply wasing the mods time.

Comment: @KenWhite Why do you assume that someone who has the skills to make that determination would even encounter the post? Much less that the first person to run across it would have them? And why is it that user's responsibility to take the risk of doing that research anyway? Moderators act on behalf of the people who own this site, and it's the owners who are responsible for mitigating those risks. If a user wants to take the initiative, that's great; if not, that should be fine, too.

Comment: What makes you think the first person who ran across that post has the skills necessary to decide the question needs to be flagged based on the presence of a link? What makes you think a moderator who looks at the link will be able to determine whether it's malicious or not? You're like the doctor that says *I don't like the way that bruise on your arm looks. Let's not bother to do any testing; we'll just amputate it now.* Moderators have enough work to do with actually **moderating this site**, and wasting their time with custom flags because *this link looks a little funny* is silly.

Comment: And the moderator who declined the flag seems to agree. Doesn't that tell you something?

Comment: @KenWhite No, I'm like someone who says, "You have puss coming out of this wound and red streaks near it. I'm no doctor, but those are signs of serious infection. Let's go to the ER." The ER may not have the specialist on hand necessary to deal with it, but it's literally their job to make an evaluation and contact someone more specialized if needed. And in the mean time, there are *some* actions they can take immediately to start addressing the problem. This link has *no* appearance of being legitimate, and the user doesn't explain what it's supposed to be. The red flags are huge.

Comment: @KenWhite The mod declining here is like a doctor at the ER telling a patient, "No, you don't have a serious infection after all. Don't come back if you see anything like this again; just take something for inflamation." This is *not* normal content we're dealing with here. This is content that's *exceptionally* suspicious.

Comment: A moderator is the only person who can make this *instantly* disappear. That alone is sufficient reason to get them involved. It would otherwise take 5 10k+ rep users to close it, a sufficient number of downvotes (which we might be able to take for granted), and *then* 3 20k+ users to vote to delete it. That takes *way* too long and wastes the time of *way* too many valuable users for obvious garbage like this. (cc @ken)

Comment: @KenWhite An answer that states "the moderator was wrong" isn't informed in any sense by saying "the moderator who declined the flag seems to aggree (with me that the moderator isn't wrong by doing the action in the first place)"  So no, that doesn't tell anyone here anything.

Answer (score 8):

Even without the link, the question is fairly unclear, because it's tough to decipher what they're really after, or it's too broad, because there's no magic involved in determining what architecture a system is running underneath.  Flagging it as either of those would've been fine.

A custom flag in this scenario wouldn't have been the right choice since there are flags which can deal with this kind of question.

It *doesn't* look like spam, which is just advertising the link for obvious and blatant scamming purposes.

Comment: My concern with using one of the standard flags was that if the link is malicious, such a flag wouldn't do anything to help remove it from the site. The question is now on hold as Too Broad (which it absolutely is), with the link still accessible. I agree that it's not obvious BUY CHEAP CIALIS NOW style spam, but the link could still lead to something problematic.

Comment: @JoDouglass:  Not that I disagree - that link does look very dodgy and even I'm not keen on clicking it - but if a user decides to click every strange and unverified link they came across, how can we realistically stop them from doing that?

Comment: *"if a user decides to click every strange and unverified link they came across, how can we realistically stop them from doing that?"* So, um, we shouldn't flag spam because people should know better than to fall for it?

Comment: @CodyGray:  Oh no, that's not my intention here at all.  My intention here is that, while this doesn't have the same feeling as spam, it doesn't automatically make the link safe.

Comment: My concern is more for SO as a whole than any individuals who might click on it; it's not really in any of our interests to let this place turn into a good hunting ground for spammers, scammers, and the like.

Comment: @Makoto "how can we realistically stop them from doing that?" Gee, I dunno, maybe by **deleting the post**?

Comment: @JoDouglass Structure-wise, the link looks like a *valid* API URL (specifically, the `/api.../soa/.../v3` bit) to an otherwise dodgy *domain*. If the URL structure seems unfamiliar to you, then I can see why it would look like spam. Since the domain looks dodgy, and the user has not provided further context, I would definitely not click on it (at work, anyway)!