# How can I improve my own experience of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I don't post very much as I'm not anywhere near a professional developer or programmer; however, whenever I do, I am increasingly frustrated by what I view as requests to append or re-examine my code, which does not lead to any satisfactory answers.  Maybe this is paranoia or an inferiority complex on my part; however, it's still something I feel is legitimate for me.

My example is a recent question of mine - [How can I get text content to resize correctly when using Fancybox 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525228/how-can-i-get-text-content-to-resize-correctly-when-using-fancybox-2)

I feel I presented my problem in the best way possible given my knowledge, presented a few attempts to work through my query, again using the full extent of my knowledge, and also have provided updates to show I am still trying to think through my question.  Frustratingly however, I received a downvote with no feedback as to why.

I suppose I have a couple of questions:

- How can I improve this question given that I feel I have reached the
  extent of my knowledge?
- How can I decipher what my downvote was for and act accordingly?
- What else can I do to get a satisfactory answer to my question given that I feel I have presented a well thought out question.

After talking with another SO user (in the real world!!!) we have both discussed how sometimes, users expect those of us with a little less knowledge to be able to answer their own questions - almost like a "you'll never learn if you don't figure it out" tough love aspect.

Often I post because I have reached the limit of my deductive abilities, and I have no other outlet to solve problems, so I feel I should ask the user base for advice.

Comment: The question has a single downvote. I feel the same way on this, and looking at the question, I see attempts to make it clear, with many visual aids. I've upvoted the answer in light of that. I used to be fairly active in the community, constantly reviewing, but I feel like the community is far less considerate of those who genuinely try. Those thoughts have taken a blown to my participation - I only ask the occasional answer if I ***really*** need an answer.

Comment: Just ignore a single downvote, there is no way to know if it was justified or not. You certainly should pay attention to multiple downvotes or critical comments and try to understand what lead to them, but for a single downvote you can't really know if the issue is with your question or the downvoting user.

Comment: Yes, I apologise for what might seem an over dramatic post over a single downvote, but I do work hard to present my problems in a way that is appropriate.  I'm not searching for upvotes, but thank you for that consideration.

Comment: That's fine. Looking at it, the question looks like a good one. Imo, people just look at every member of the community with lower rep: they don't research, and all they want is an answer to the community, and don't bother giving back. Sadly, I find that because of these sad few, this entire tier is painted with the single paintbrush.

Comment: It's something I understand, but it's still my responsibility to see if I can do things a little better.

Comment: The question was fine. Of course, if people want additional information, they will call you out on it.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you.  It's funny really.  The thing I have complained about here is exactly what is happening on the linked question as we speak :-)

Comment: You might want to look at the current comments under your SO post and delete the ones that are obsolete

Comment: I was in the middle of doing that, thanks again.

Comment: Try using the [stack-snippet tool](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), rather than posting screen shots. It will be a lot easier for people to see what your current code is doing, and be easier for them to help you with it.

Comment: @tomdot Now that you know what was the issue, you could edit the question to add the relevant parts. Later, you can add the answer yourself (with proper crediting), if JFK does not add it himself. That could avoid you more downvotes, while it could be helpful for a future visitor with similar problems.

Comment: @Blas Soriano That is exactly what I did, and what I was intending to do in the first place if prompted with the question.  I still stand by this meta question, and believe that it encompassed exactly what happened in my linked question (which appears to have caused a problem for one or two users who have either rescinded their upvotes, or cast downvotes after the fact).

Comment: SO is filled with tons of bad questions. Someone thought yours was - actually 9 people now - (although I think it looks ok in its current state ). I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/204614

Comment: It is worth noting that higher rep users get unexplained downvotes too. It is easier to shrug off when it is a drop in the ocean as far as rep points are concerned; most high rep people care little for their rep. It is easier to not care when you have a lot -- just like money. A speeding ticket for a poor person is a significant financial challenge that might ruin your week or month, a wealthy person shrugs and pays it, maybe slightly annoyed. Ultimately, though, money is useful, rep isn't really. I hate to give the trite answer, but here it's the bottom line: shrug it off and move on.

Comment: "I post because I have reached the limit of my deductive abilities" - everyone does that. What makes it interesting is the wide range of such limits (from "rarely posts questions because they eventually figure it out themselves" to "thinks the SO question title field is a replacement for the Google search box").

Comment: I ask a question with the discussion tag and people vote to close it because it's primarily opinion based, other people ask questions with the discussion tag, and they flock to upvote it.  Taken right from the comments: "most high rep people care little for their rep" -- that's an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: @Zizouz212 "I only ask the occasional [ed: question] if I really need an answer" Maybe it's just me, but this is the approach I've always taken to SO. If you can find the solution yourself, why should you bother others with it?

Comment: @Jan My point is, I was very open towards SO and I really felt a part of the community. However, I feel like many users from the entire reputation spectrum are just rude and disrespectful, and I quite simply have lost interest. Since I'm 15, and I might not be the best of programmers, my "lack of advanced knowledge" seems to put me in the spotlight, and I feel criticized for it, when I am quite genuinely asking since I don't understand. Bottom line: ***I've outright given up*** - not because I have nothing left to achieve (I'm not high on rep), but because I don't feel very respected at all.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> How can I improve this question given that I feel I have reached the extent of my knowledge?

There are good people who will comment on what else you need to add to your question to make it clearer and better. Look for comments that tell you things like, "you need to add this" or "isn't `variable1` supposed to be this?" and stuff like that. They can really help make your post better and give you more knowledge to apply to your future questions. As of this post you have a score of 2, which means your question is clear and shows research and probably matches the requirements of the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

If you gain a downvote, re-read your question and see if you can find any holes in your question. Maybe you are missing some code, or the question needs more information. Not every time are you actually at the extent of your knowledge. There are usually places a lot people can miss and no one is a perfect question maker here. **Honestly, improve your question with the help of extra knowledge that may come from other fellow users if you think your question has maximum quality. There are times you will be proven wrong...**

> How can I decipher what my downvote was for and act accordingly?

You really can't. You need to see if the downvoter has posted a comment on why the question needs fixing or the reason for downvoting. If you get a downvote, re-examine your question for any holes or mistakes in your question. If you can't see any, just wait to see if any helpful comments come. Downvotes are given because the question is:

- Not clear
- Has shown no effort/research
- Can be flagged (spam, rude, unclear, too broad, off-topic (duplicate is an exception))

You can also visit the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for more information on how to make a good, well-received question.

> What else can I do to get a satisfactory answer to my question given that I feel I have presented a well thought out question.

Make your question as clear as possible and hope that someone with good expertise on your subject will find your mistake and fix it. That's really my only advice.

Comment: To your point on "How can I decipher what my downvote was for and act accordingly?" It would be interesting to see what a downvoter would have to say if they were required to leave a reason for the downvote.

Comment: @JosephSilvashy Interestingly enough the downvoter DID leave a comment, almost immediately as far as i can tell. That's a case where I would have downvoted as well. At the time of that comment, the post was missing a very important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @JosephSilvashy: Most likely "qwervshvzhfcghnfchg" or similar. Making comments on downvotes obligatory is a perennial favorite of those who haven't taken the time to read the hundreds of feature-requests on that topic, and why they were always declined as actively harmful to the site.

Answer (score 12):

There are a vast number of people with the right to downvote. Every so often, one will fly over *your* head. There is no possible way to change this.

Having a thick skin is, for better or worse, required when asking the entire internet to help you solve a problem.

Comment: I think you are missing a word in your last sentence. Nevertheless, thank you for saying it!