# Can I edit code in an answer?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

jsfiddle has a feature that the "answer" code is editable.

For example, I asked a question and got an answer. Now I want to learn off this answer by modifying it and seeing if it still works.

I have to start an editor, copy paste the code, save it and run it.

In JSfiddle, the code is modifiable right then and there.

can this feature be added to SO?

Comment: Already exists; its called [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: @Daedalus but I can't edit your snack snippet

Comment: @joeshmoe: Sure you can. Hit Copy To Answer and go from there in your own draft.

Comment: That's not very different from copying and pasting the code in an editor and saving and running it separately though. Every time I find myself doing that I fear accidentally clicking submit thinking I meant to post an answer when in actual fact I did not. The answer field is for writing and submitting answers - it's the last place I'd expect to be if all I want to do is fiddle with an existing snippet. Worse still the fact that the live preview doesn't even totally play well with snippets, with glitches like the preview closing itself every other click, chaotic focus issues, etc.

Comment: Not only that, but if I'm creating an answer and I don't want the snippet in the answer it makes editing the answer a pain in the ass. Very bad UX