# Is there an easier way to mess (fiddle) with someone's code snippet?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-snippets

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979585/how-to-squircle-an-app-icon-image-with-just-css) with an HTML/CSS code snippet. The answer also provides code snippets, but they're not working 100%. Some are close though, so I'd like to mess with them, the same as when I wrote them in my question, or when someone posts a jsfiddle link. Is there any way to do that without (a) editing the question or (b) copying their snippet into a new answer?

I'd like to use the snippet editor, without any immediate intention of posting the updated snippet back to the person's answer. If that's not possible, then I'd like to request that as a feature.

I could see this being useful in the following cases:

- Understanding a solution by experimenting with it (turning parts on/off, etc.)
- Aiding discussion with the poster (to see the effects of certain modifications before suggesting them or asking about them)
- Attempting to trim out pieces that you may not need when you apply the solution to your own code

Comment: @TinyGiant I added a few cases to the question

Comment: @TinyGiant (and @rene) I guess either of those options work, but leave the door open to accidentally saving something you didn't set out to (imagine if you leave your desk for a while and come back to it)

Comment: @rene: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306455/can-i-edit-code-in-an-answer#comment249386_306455 tl;dr the answer field is not suited to fiddling with other snippets, at all (or for any other purpose than *posting answers* for that matter).

Comment: @Tiny Giant: "Saving" in this case doesn't mean saving the code in order to compile and run it, it means persisting it for long after what is meant to be a temporary fiddling session. Also see my response above.

Comment: Should I close this as a dupe of that question, or should I close that as a dupe of this one because this explains the problem better?

Comment: @BoltClock closed voted the other question as a dupe of this one ... and you might write a answer

Comment: I guess copy/pasting 20-30 lines of code into jsfiddle.net is too much work nowadays, huh?

Answer (score 11):

I recommend copying the code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io) and messing with it there. Stack Snippets are great for providing functional code within an answer that can be seen as a working demo, but they're not really meant for just messing with code.

It'd be nice if there was a set of "migrate to [service]" buttons, but then you'd have to have a partnership between SO and the services in question, which brings up all sorts of legal issues.

Comment: Quite [user script-able](https://gist.github.com/paulroub/c87f30e2aaad9cbdec6d), in the meantime.

Comment: @PaulRoub, don't forget to add attribution.

Comment: Good point. Added a JS comment with the source URL.

Comment: @PaulRoub, i'm not familiar with CodePen's api, but if there's a way to pre-fill the pen's description, I'd recommend using that.

Comment: Done. pre-filled title with "Snippet from (page title)", and description with the source URL. Note that neither is visible until the Pen is *saved*, but neither is *needed* until then.