# Create a magic link introducing stack snippets

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets, magic-links

I just happen to come across another fiddle request.

One feedback this thread: [Inform the users about the existence of stack snippet while requesting external demos in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314602/inform-the-users-about-the-existence-of-stack-snippet-while-requesting-external) received was the following:

> The main reason I might still ask a user (particularly a new user) to include a jsfiddle rather than a snippet is because it's far easier to say "Could you put your code in a jsfiddle?" than "Could you put your code in a snippet? You click 'edit', then in the toolbar above the editable field, it's like the sixth or seventh button... let me check... yeah, it's the seventh button, just after the one that kind of looks like mountains. The one that when you hover it says 'snippet'. Click that, then you can put your code into your question." So I guess the point is that it needs to be clearer.

He seems to have a point. Please make `[snippet]`  magic link that leads the user to [introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I would prefer if it was first arranged that snippets don't suck. If it's pain to use, it's stupid to recommend it to other users.

Comment: Having to scroll the window back to where the snippet editor was after scrolling too much in one of the textareas is annoying as hell, makes me think SO devs forgot `position: fixed` is a thing.

Comment: @TomášZato I'd prefer the *quick* win in this feature request is rolled out asap, *and* the Snippet feature gets some extra UX love (i.e. current UX isn't *that* terrible that any and all other improvements should be held off IMHO).

Comment: @Jeroen It doesn't show all code if code is too long. It doesn't backup the code anywhere, I already lost my code twice. Editing post with snippet causes weird lags and tab reloading animation. So it's pretty bad. And the reason I'm bitching about it loud is that I actually would like to use it.

Comment: Is it really that much easier to type `[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deadbeef/)` than to type `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->` ?

Comment: @TomášZato All fair points. Have you posted on meta with those various issues yet? I'd upvote them for sure. (Still UX is not bad enough for me to let the snippet magic quick win wait, but on that we just disagree it seems :D)

Comment: @Jeroen Yes I posted about it. I got downvoted and the post is now deleted: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310536/607407 Along with downvotes, I got comments recommending I shut up and use jsFiddle or external IDE. So that's why I don't post anymore, the Community♦ has spoken clearly.

Comment: *it's stupid to recommend it to other users* @TomášZato - It's still better than telling a new user to use an external site knowing that their question will get closed because the code isn't in the question itself.

Comment: @BSMP Well I think it's not. But of course the attempts to get snippets working were made for a reason.

Comment: How about having it so that if the asker clicks the link generated by `[snippet]`, it opens up the snipper editor directly (maybe with a quick directions slideshow before the editor panes to explain what they clicked). If other users click it, it takes it to that blog post or a help page. Might be a bit forceful, but it would certainly make it easier for users to ask for snippets of code.

Comment: @JoshJanusch That's a good idea, but it's a bit different from the existing magic links, so will be a bit complex and probably take more than 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: snippets can't be forked like all the other sandbox sites can. Makes it a pain to work back and forth with OP trying to work out issues if you want OP to provide an update based on their feedback

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure what you meant... There is a "copy to answer" option. If OP updates the snippet later, you can use the same option, make your changes and once you're done just copy paste whole thing back to your existing answer. I don't think it's harder than going to external site, forking original, making changes, saving the fork, copying it's `URL` and updating your answer with it. It's just a matter of the amount of stuff getting copied into clipboard unless I totally failed to understand what you meant...

Comment: This is a XY problem. The problems with Snippets should be addressed before taking recommendations to a higher level.

Comment: @TomášZato You complain stack snippets don't backup unsaved code. But jsfiddle sucks more, they removed my saved code at least once.

Comment: One of the thing which we can not do in snippet but in JSFiddle is we can resize the width and height of result and other area like HTML, css etc. I think snippet should also have this feature

Comment: @ketan I did request this long back... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214

Comment: [snippet] damnit.