# Help page explaining how Snippets work

Tags: discussion

I've search for a page describing what Snippets are and how they work, so I can link to it in comments on questions that haven't supplied one (or a jsfiddle)... but I can't find such a page.

Is there one?

If so, where is it?

Comment: Closest I've found - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D - I was hoping for more of an instruction manual, rather than a "suggested feature"