# Stack Snippets, hiding code but showing "Run code snippet"

Tags: support

I was wondering if Stack Snippets have an option to toggle the display of the code for the snippet but have the *Run code snippet* button visible?

Comment: Why the down-votes? Why is this a poor question?

Comment: Downvotes are different on Meta -- here they mostly mean disagreement.

Comment: Indeed your question is tagged `[support]`, but the second paragraph looks a lot like a feature request. And support questions can be downvoted too. Anyway, in case you haven't noticed, Meta votes do not impact your rep.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes I know, I've been on the meta before. The second paragraph is just stating a situation where it would be useful. I don't know if it's possible, hence why I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Stack Snippets do not support such functionality without harming the functionality of the snippet. Although in the [Feedback Requested: Runnable Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), there is [feedback covering this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269782/3149020). As of right now there is no way to hide code that an answerer may feel is boilerplate or not entirely necessary to a specific question.

Answer (score 10):

No; that'd pretty much be an invitation for dirty tricks and nasty surprises.

The purpose of snippets is to allow running code that's included for demonstration purposes; you should expect that readers wishing to run the code will also want to see it in context.

Comment: *"that'd pretty much be an invitation for dirty tricks and nasty surprises"*, how so?

Comment: By implying that the code which would be run is other than that which would *actually* be run.

Comment: I could give code snippets, then use a JSfiddle with different code. Same situation, besides it's only toggled. There is really no difference between that and *"Show Stack Snippet"*. That really isn't a problem, people can lie, and would be down-voted anyways.

Comment: To be honest the other than "No", the rest of this is a rant/opinion, and not helpful to the question. You really should not be [immediately assuming bad intentions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: I'm not assuming anything about *your* intentions. But it would be negligent of me to assume good intentions of everyone who could potentially make use of this feature.