# Hide code in a snippet that helps display but isn't relevant to the question

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I wrote this snippet today. The last line of HTML is styling info that makes the presented result clearer, but isn't actually relevant to the question.

```css
.tags { 
  position: relative;
}

.tags:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTb0z.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 1000px;  /* These are just large enough to definitely   */
  height: 1000px; /* contain the image. Image could be any size. */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>No action</td>
    <td>No action</td>
    <td>No action</td>
    <td class="tags">Hover me!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No action</td>
    <td>No action</td>
    <td>No action</td>
    <td class="tags">Hover me!</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--table borders--><style>td{border:1px solid #999;padding:10px;}table{border-collapse:collapse;}</style>
```

---

When writing snippets, if you want to include output in the result, e.g. additional styles or HTML etc., but don't want it visible in the code blocks because it's not actually relevant to the question, is there a way to do that?

Comment: not sure whether you mean setting `hide:true` in `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->` the beginning of your snippet..Is that what you mean?

Comment: [Unfortunately not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324149/stack-snippets-hiding-code-but-showing-run-code-snippet). Mainly because users could be hiding relevant code to the question.

Comment: @SurajRao no clearly not because that hides all code