# Can I upload my own JS/CSS file while creating a code snippet?

Tags: support

How can I upload my own code snippet (JavaScript and CSS) while posting a question/answer on Stack Overflow?

Comment: [**Stack Snippets**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: You have to host it your self, or on github. And then you can include it with a `<script>` tag in your html

Comment: You put necessary JS/CSS/whatever other code inline in the post. Not very clear what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: And a cross-meta dup on Meta SE: [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Copy it, paste into the post (optionally as part of a Stack Snippet, if it's intended to run as is), and *trim to only the relevant bits*. (Or trim it first to make sure it's still producing the same results. That's the best way.) Stack Overflow is not looking for code dumps.

In fact, SO is so uninterested in raw code dumps that there is a custom close reason that, among other things, is used for cases where the code has not been sufficiently trimmed. Your question needs to have a [*Minimal*, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If that happens to be drawn from live code, so much the better, but there's no reason for it to be the *entire* code file, so it is not likely that any provision will ever be made to make it easier to carelessly dump excessive amounts of code into questions. Or answers, for that matter, where it should be even easier to separate out just the important changes to make.