# Why is JSFiddle used so much among questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, jsfiddle

I was just curious: why do we use JSFiddle within questions and answers, as it is a 3rd party website?

Does anybody have an update on this?

Comment: Do you mean as opposed to the built-in code snippets?

Comment: Yes, Like i said it is a 3'rd party website @E_net4

Comment: I'm guessing jsfiddle was primarily used before the built-in thingy was created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Snippets have been introduced [only in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/4751173). Before that, JSFiddle was the usual way to make live demonstrations of your code – [here is a 2010 feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49728/295232) mentioning it. I guess that's why people still use it today on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Another point not covered by [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel) is that when using the given JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet we are not given any option to modify the code when running.  If a JSFiddle is used as well the code can be modified by the answer/asker without actually making permanent changing. This is convenient because it means answers don't have to copy and paste the text to try things.