# How to add SVG picture in Question or Answer on StackOverflow site?

Tags: feature-request

On StackOverflow sites, is it possible to add an SVG image in a post?

If so, how?

Comment: Is your question about the SVG itself?

Comment: It is worth mentoning that your solution is the same as explained in the answer on the duplicate. The down-side of these solutions is the dependency on an off-site server. If svgur.com ever goes belly up the svg is gone with it.

Comment: The duplicate answer take an SVG from Wikipedia that is also an external site. The first question is an Why it is impossible to put SVG ? But my question is Hot to put SVG ? For me, there is a difference between these 2 questions and the answer gived in duplicata is not complete because he doesn't explain completely the solution and don't answer to question that is Why and not How !

Comment: A little example: I have 2 questions. The first is 'Why the wall is painted in blue'. A user answer 'You buy blue painting and you put it on the wall'. This answer is accepted and another user ask 'How to paint the wall in blue ?'. An mediator come there and close the last question because an incorrect answer has been added to the WHY question ! The question now is 'Is there interesting to close correct question and answer or to close it ?'

Comment: Whether you consider something a duplicate depends how you look at it. If you think *the question* is leading then your reasoning holds. If you think *the answers* are leading, this question is closed correctly as the answer on the dupe applies here  as well. Thank god we can have a debate over this and never agree \o/. Put your answer on the duplicate and that also goes for the answer by Robert.

Comment: You’ve tagged this question [[meta-tag:feature-request]], and under that rubric, it’s *definitely* a duplicate. Both questions are requesting a way to upload SVGs.

Comment: As Cody said, if you want to post the answer you have to this question, retag it as support and edit it so that it's about how do you work around the lack of SVG image upload support in imgur.

Comment: @Robert: I waste too time with this post. So, I posted my answer in original question even if NOW this question is incorrect. I have also posted this answer on StackOverflow on another question.

Comment: Adding this answer to [some random SVG question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608309/1038015) on the main site is not the way to go either. It's not appropriate there. Not sure if mods get notification of meta vs main duplication. I really think the best way forward here is to make this question a support question about workarounds, wait for it to be reopened, delete your answer from all the other places it now exists on Meta and Main before @CodyGray or some other moderator has to do it for you.

Comment: I have answered to other question because Cody Gray has written that that my question is 'definitely' a duplicate and so, I don't have any hope that somebody reopen it. I think sincerely that my answer to other question can help other users.

Comment: This question has 3 out of 5 reopen votes already. If you edit it I'm sure it will get the other two.

Comment: I don't understand what you say in writing 'if you edit ...'. Why must I edit my question ? What must I done ? There are something that I don't understand. Can you explain more ? I have already changed tag from feature to support.

Comment: This question could say... I understand that SVG files can't be uploaded and there is a feature-request for that (link to the other question). In the meantime are there any workarounds available if I want to display SVG images in a question...

Answer (score 3):

Put the SVG in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). When the snippet runs you'd see the SVG.

Comment: This solution is not perfect because User must click on Run Code Snippet to see the result. In my solution, SVG image is immediately visible.