# Feature Request: Language support for "Stack Snippets"

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I was looking through [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/), and I saw [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/269756?noredirect=1#comment84526_269756). The comment says:

> Added some notes to the post. (1) It's JS/CSS/HTML right now because that was the easiest. If it's successful we may expand to other languages. (2) All the same rules about code-only questions and answers apply, and in fact it's just inserting code blocks so the existing checks will all work. All this does is make it runnable, which seems like it's always better (?)

That comment was posted in 2014. This is 2020 and "Stack Snippets" are a success. But where's the support for other languages? Other sites that I use like [repl.it](https://www.repl.it), etc, have support for innumerable languages while Stack Snippets only has support for HTML, CSS, and JS. You could at least start with a transpiler, if not an interpreter or compiler. TypeScript, Dart, ClojureScript, and CoffeeScript are examples of great languages that transpile directly into JavaScript.

Comment: "Stack Snippets are a success." I believe some kind of justification is needed for this claim.