# Can we stop asking for demos?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm not actively answering on the main site recently for the past few months, but I do visit some questions listed under my favorite tags. Now as Stack Overflow introduced a snippet feature, previously we used JSFiddle, so that's sweet. Now, instead of answering questions, most of the users are pretty lazy to answer these without a demo so all they do is, write a comment like:

> Can you share a demo?

I am not saying all, but most of them. There's nothing wrong in asking for a demo if the OP is not sharing his/her entire code, or he/she is linking to some random website, but as far as I know, we don't appreciate this. We want the users to share a relevant code with some decent explanation.

According to me, sharing a demo leads to dirty hacky practices all around. Some users highlight JSFiddle links, or some highlight random words just to get rid of the JSFiddle demo warning.

So can we have some auto filters which prevents users to post this useless comments which only asks for demos from the OP? Why not ask a set of complete code if the problem is not solvable with the initial shared code by the OP?

Somewhere, I blame existing users who started off this trend of asking demos on like every question they want to answer and hence, most of the users nowadays are only sharing links to these demos in their question without relevant code.

If there's a demo, no one cares to comment that please share your code, and if they share codes, they comment which asks for a demo.

Hence, according to me, users should pick the code which is provided, read the explanation and work on a demo for their convenience, but asking demos for every minor thing makes no sense. No doubt demo does make the work easy, but let’s leave on the OP whether he/she wants to share it or not.

Some samples I would like to provide from a user with whom I recently debated over this:

> Please provide meaningful HTML& CSS, ideally in a demo.
>
> Can you demo the code?...but it sounds ....
>
> You've spelled center wrong in the CSS section but a demo would be of more use, S ....
>
> You need to provide your HTML & CSS in a demo that shows the issue.
>
> How big is the image?... A demo would be useful.
>
> Please demo the actual issue in a JSfiddle.

These comments are posted by a single user, and I could just go on and on with these, nothing but clutter all around instead of asking for relevant resources from the OP.

P.S: I am not sharing the user profile, because I don't want to publicly shame anyone, and also I've deleted my recent comments debating with that user.

[Somewhat related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266118/1542290)

Comment: I agree that this reliance on demos does lead many to neglect actually including their code in the question.  Otherwise demos make a great, convenient addition to the provided code.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Sure that's a way of convenience but that leads to neglect sharing the actual source as you said, hence SO introduced a warning which says to share a code if only fiddle link provided ... but if we don't emphasize on demos too much, users might share relevant codes...

Comment: I see one huge problem with a filter for this - if OP does not provide enough code to demonstrate their issue, it's perfectly reasonable to ask for a snippet reproducing the problem. You don't want to filter those comments.

Comment: @l4mpi asking for additional/relevant code is fine, asking for demos is wrong, that is where site is going bad these days.. people are asking for demos and they don't care about codes anymore thus making a question too much OP specific which won't be useful for future visitors anymore

Comment: I don't get the "lazy" accusation.  If the user was truly lazy then it would be much easier to just DV and not spend the time to provide the questioner with hints on how to make his question better.  Reading his comments, they go well beyond a demo demand in many cases.  Good Q+A that's useful to many more programmers doesn't fall from the sky, it takes work and that starts with the Q.

Answer (score 4):

### Demos = Problem?

Demos are not bad in and of themselves.  But they are not a substitute for a proper question.

Ideally, when someone asks a question they should put all the relevant code in the question.  However, my experience has shown me that most people do not.  Many posters do one of two things, either post far to little code (read: not enough to reproduce the problem) or way too much (posting their entire project).  Most of the time, the HTML/CSS/JS questions (which I believe this post is mostly referring to) fall on the side of too little.  I can't count the number of questions where someone asks about a CSS problem and then posts a tiny snippet of CSS with no HTML and expects us to divine what could possibly be causing a vaguely described problem.  Posting a demo at least forces them to give us a MCVE of the problem.

### Demos vs. Proper Question Writing

Providing a demo does not absolve someone from putting the code in the question.  We have a close reason that says (emphasis mine):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

When we find questions that only include demo links we can either edit the code into the question or downvote and vote to close.  If someone gets enough closed questions because they can't be bothered to do it right then they get a lovely question ban and can either shape up or get out.

### Asking for Demos

So what does asking for demos do?  It gives us a chance to get what we need to help and to make the question better.  Unfortunately, not everyone who gets the desired demo is going to fix the question.  Blocking their comment isn't going to fix their lack of desire to improve the site.  Removing their ability to tell the OP that they need to give us more is not going to help anyone.  And like most things, as soon as someone figures out that anything worded in a specific way gets blocked, they just learn to word it slightly differently.  Overall, I believe that asking for demos is helpful in the best case and neutral in the worst case.

Comment: Well, if the request links to [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's much better than simply asking for a demo. Even better if the point violated is explicitly mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator Completely agree.  I would be all for that if we could just get people to actually read the links we give them.  In this case "demo" seems to more universally convey the intent of "MCVE" without all that nasty, boring reading :P.